# Походовая игра в wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, разработка-игр

Мне нужно сделать маленькую походовую игрушку в WPF. Игровая доска будет иметь произвольный размер(пользователь сам указывает сколько на сколько клеток, но не больше чем 100**100). На самой доске случайным образом расставляются препятсвия которые не могут перейти игровые фигуры. Кажая фигура может ходить по опредлённым правилам(одна на искосок, другая во вертикали, третяя кренделем и т.д.).
   Во время хода пользователь выбирает фигуры, и указывает конечное поле куда она должна попасть, если указание не противоречит правилам, то фигура перемещается на выбранное поле, а путь подсвечивается красным. 
   Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше реализовать такую затею в WPF?

Я пока планирую изначально создать grid 100*100, в каждую его клетку положить по картинке соответствующей цвету фона,в каждую картинку положить по Canvas, и в нужных Canvas разместить фигуры, которые сделать катинками. Далее когда пользователь вводит размеры поля, я планирую удалять лишнии строки и столбцы, я только не знаю как это сделать в С#?(чисто в разметке XAML как я понимаю это не сделать.)

Вторая проблема это препядствия(стенки), которые размещаются в случайном порядке, между игровыми клетками(полями), думаю либо попробовать как то использовать обводку картинки(выделять её соответсвющим цветом), что бы показать наличие стены, хорошая ли это идея и как это можно сделать?(я не знаю как добраться до рамки картинки програмно на C#( в разметке xaml это наверное не сделать))....

Я знаю, что wpf возможно не лучшая технология для такой задачи, но мне хочется разобраться с wpf.

Comment: @Виталик: вы на 100% правы, поменяю в коде. (Отвечаю здесь, там лимит комментариев.)

Answer (score 16):

(Обновил код с позиций конца 2016 года.)

---

Значит так. Для начала, вам надо отделить логику игры от представления. Раз и навсегда.

Запомните: у вас должен быть в слое логики объект, представляющий собой поле, препятствия и всё такое, а его отображением пусть занимается слой представления. Смешивать логику и представление == говнокод.

Для начала, общий вспомогательный базовый класс, имплементирующий `INotifyPropertyChanged` (обычно он есть в вашем MVVM-фреймворке, или вы таскаете его из проекта в проект):

```
class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected bool Set<T>(ref T storage, T value,
                         [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Окей, поехали делать наброски.

```
class BoardVM : VM // это наша доска, понятно
{     
    #region property int NumberOfRows
    int numberOfRows;
    public int NumberOfRows
    {
        get { return numberOfRows; }
        set { Set(ref numberOfRows, value); }
    }
    #endregion

    #region property int NumberOfCols
    // аналогично
    #endregion
```

Хорошо, теперь нам нужны препятствия. Они находятся между клетками, и должны по идее принадлежать доске. Хорошо. Нам нужен отдельный тип, описывающий препятствие, пусть это будет `Obstacle`. Доска содержит список препятствий, который, разумеется, может меняться.

```
    public ObservableCollection<Obstacle> Obstacles { get; private set; }
}
```

Покамест больше ничего не нужно, но возможно, нам понадобится ещё список фигур.

Итак, препятствие. Препятствия, по идее, не «плавают», поэтому их позиция может быть обыкновенным property. Пусть препятствие будет вертикальным/горизонтальным, будем задавать начальную клетку и направление. У нас, возможно, будет много типов препятствий, поэтому мы должны предусмотреть возможность того, что у нас будут порождённые классы.

```
class Obstacle
{
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }
    public int Length { get; }
    public bool IsVertical { get; }
}
```

Окей, пришло время порисовать. Поскольку доска — нетривиальный объект, создадим для неё `UserControl`.

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="YourCoolGame.View.BoardPresentation"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <!-- здесь будут края вашей доски, возможно, вы хотите на них 
         что-то нарисовать -->
    <Grid>

        <!-- А это сама доска. Заполнять будем по рабоче-крестьянски,
             в code-behind  -->
        <Grid x:Name="CellsHost"/>

        <!-- тут ещё какие-нибудь контролы, если надо -->

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Теперь сам code-behind.

```
// там где-то выше namespace YourCoolGame.View

class BoardPresentation : UserControl
{
    public BoardPresentation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // окей, нам надо подписаться на изменение объекта из слоя логики
        // который, как вы уже обязаны знать, придёт к нам через DataContext
        DataContextChanged += (sender, args) =>
                OnBoardChanged((BoardVM)args.OldValue, (BoardVM)args.NewValue);
        OnBoardChanged(null, (BoardVM)DataContext);
    }

    void OnBoardChanged(BoardVM prev, BoardVM curr)
    {
        // окей, у нас новая доска. нам надо подписаться на изменение всего,
        // что нам интересно. но для начала отписаться от старой доски
        if (prev != null)
            prev.PropertyChanged -= OnBoardGeometryChanged;

        OnBoardGeometryChanged();

        if (curr != null) // ну и подписываемся
            curr.PropertyChanged -= OnBoardGeometryChanged;
    }
```

Вот, приготовления окончены, по идее. Теперь осталось только создать нужную доску.

```
    // аргументы игнорируются
    void OnBoardGeometryChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BoardMV board = (BoardMV)DataContext;
        if (board != null)
            SetBoardSize(board.NumberOfCols, board.NumberOfRows);
        else
            SetBoardSize(0, 0);
    }

    void SetBoardSize(int cols, int rows)
    {
        // Будем держать в Grid'е 1 + 2 * cols столбцов:
        // для клеток и для препятствий. То же со строками.
        var neededNumberOfCols = 2 * cols + 1;
        var actualNumberOfCols = CellsHost.ColumnDefinitions.Count;

        if (neededNumberOfCols > actualNumberOfCols)
        {
            // добавляем
            for (int i = actualNumberOfCols; i < neededNumberOfCols; i++)
            {
                bool isBorderCell = (i % 2 == 0);
                CellsHost.ColumnDefinitions.Add(
                    new ColumnDefinition()
                    {
                        Width = isBorderCell ? BorderThickness : CellSize
                    });
                // добавили столбец? теперь его надо заполнить
                // во все строки добавляем по клетке
                if (!isBorderCell)
                    for (int j = 1; j < CellsHost.RowDefinitions.Count; j += 2)
                        AddCellAt(i / 2, j / 2);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // убираем
            for (int i = actualNumberOfCols, i > neededNumberOfCols; i--)
            {
                bool isBorderCell = (i % 2 == 0);
                if (!isBorderCell)
                    for (int j = 1; j < CellsHost.RowDefinitions.Count; j += 2)
                        RemoveCellAt(i / 2, j / 2);
                CellsHost.ColumnDefinitions.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        // ну и то же самое для строк
    }
```

У нас есть клетки игрового поля. Они могут делать всякие интересные штуки, например, быть покрашенными в разные цвета, перехватывать события от мыши, и всё такое. Напишем функции для них.

```
    void AddCellAt(int i, int j)
    {
        var cell = new Cell(i, j, GetColorForCell(i, j))
        {
            DataContext = DataContext
        };
        int colInGrid = 2 * i + 1;
        int rowInGrid = 2 * j + 1;
        Grid.SetColumn(cell, colInGrid);
        Grid.SetRow(cell, rowInGrid);
        CellsHost.Children.Add(cell);
    }

    void RemoveCellAt(int i, int j)
    {
        var cell = CellsHost.Children.OfType<Cell>()
                                     .Where(c => c.Col = i && c.Row == j)
                                     .Single();
        CellsHost.Children.Remove(cell);
    }
}
```

Хорошо, там ещё надо было бы добавить `Obsacle`, но это вы уж сами разберитесь. А пока опишем `Cell`. `Cell`, понятно, тоже `UserControl`, простенький такой.

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="YourCoolGame.View.Cell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid Name="ContentElement" Click="OnClick"/>

</UserControl>
```

Ну и code-behind:

```
// там где-то выше снова namespace YourCoolGame.View

class Cell : UserControl
{
    int col, row;

    // конструктор по умолчанию нужен
    public Cell() : this(-1, -1, Colors.Transparent)
    {
    }

    public Cell(int col, int row, Color color)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.col = col;
        this.row = row;
        ContentElement.Background = new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }

    // это на самом деле не очень хороший момент, т. к. получается
    // сильная связность. развязаться можно при помощи команд, например.
    void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BoardVM board = (BoardVM)DataContext;
        board.ActivateCell(col, row);
    }
}
```

Вот вроде бы и всё. В препятствиями работайте так же, как и с клетками: подпишитесь на изменения `Obstacles`, заведите `UserControl`, представляющий препятствие, и добавляйте его в `Grid` на нужное место.

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt: Ну например, можно привязать эти editbox'ы к Board.NumberOfCols и Board.NumberOfRows.

Доску вставьте куда-нибудь в главное окно, только ради бога не пользуйтесь визуальным редактором, а через какой-нибудь подходящий контейнер.

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt: DataContext в первый раз всегда будет null, ведь когда конструируется BoardPresentation, свойство DataContext ещё не установлено. Оно будет установлено позже, для этого мы и подписываемся на его изменения.

Затем, у вас всё запускается из конструктора MainWindow. Это не вполне верно: отображение должно следовать за логикой, а не наоборот. Я бы убрал StartupUri из App.xaml, а создавал окно в коде, ответственном за логику.

По поводу порядка конструкторов, я думаю, конструктор BoardPresentation вызывается из InitializeComponent внутри конструктора MainWindow. Как-то так.

Comment: @VladD,  чисто моё замечание:  
Желательно логические свойства, поля (ваше Vertical свойство) называть как IsPropertyName, HasPropertyName, etc. => IsVertical  
Незнаю но это сугубо моё мнение

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt: тоже просто: `new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(5, GridUnitType.Star)`. Вот [документация](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridunittype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) с примерами.

Comment: Спасибо, всё у себя поправил. Всё работает. Но возникла проблемка. Мы ведь, как я понял, создавали визуальное предстваление BoardPresentation и логическое представление классом Board и связывали их через DataContext(записывали в него объект класса Board и сделали, что потом при каждом изменение DataContex доска будет перерисовываться.) И сейчас у меня возник вопрос, а как быть если я хочу добавить ещё одни контрол(назовём его NewPresentation) и логический класс для него(назовём New)?

Comment: Ведь по идее, если я попробую их так же связать их через DataContex, то потом при каждом изменение DataContext, будут вызываться обработчики как в BoardPresentation так и в новом контроле NewPresentation? Можно ли как-то их разграничить т.е. что бы при изменение объекта класса New вызывались бы обработчики только из NewPresentation, а при изменение Board соответственно вызывались бы только из BoardPresentation? Или я уже просто запутался?

Comment: Смотрите. Если у вас `New` — часть доски, значит, положите его как свойство (ни в коем случае не поле, с полями не работает `Binding`!) в `Board`. Затем, внутри `BoardPresentation` у вас возникает `NewPresentation`, и вы устанавливаете для него правильный `DataContext`:

    <controls:NewPresentation DataContext="{Binding New}"/>

(я исхожу из того, что свойство тоже называется `New`). Теперь `DataContext`'ом для `NewPresentation` будет ваш экземпляр `New`.

Если у вас несколько экземпляров `New`, которые будут подменять друг друга, вместо свойства `New` нужно как обычно `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: @Denis: Эээ... Моё форматирование было не ошибкой: отступы были потому, что код продолжал определение класса!

Comment: @VladD, упс... :) Я предположил, что так будет немного удобнее. Сделайте откат, я ни чуть не против.

Comment: @DenisBubnov: Ага, откатил. Если внимательно присмотреться, там один класс, разбитый текстовыми вставками.

Comment: @DenisBubnov: Хотя namespace наверное всё же стоит снести, да. А то слишком много места ест.

Comment: @VladD, да-да, заметил. Забавно разделили код текстом.

Comment: @DenisBubnov: Сейчас таки уберу один отступ :)

Comment: Связанный ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573196/10105