# Как поворачивать элементы в строке и столбце одновременно?

Tags: c#, wpf

Кнопки генерируются следующим образом:

```
private Button[,] CreateButtons(int quantity)
{
    Form.Rows = quantity;
    Form.Columns = quantity;
    Button[,] buttons = new Button[quantity, quantity];
    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < quantity; j++)
        {
            buttons[i, j] = new Button();
            buttons[i, j].Width = 100;
            buttons[i, j].Height = 20;
            buttons[i, j].Margin = new Thickness(5,80,0,0);
            buttons[i, j].Click += new RoutedEventHandler(new_button_click);
        }
    }
    return buttons;
}
```

И есть обработчик события клика по ним:

```
void new_button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    if (btn != null)
    {
        var transform = new RotateTransform(90);
        transform.CenterX = 50;
        transform.CenterY = 10;
        btn.RenderTransform = transform;
    }
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на одну кнопку поворачивались все кнопки в одной строке и в одном столбце.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы действуете неправильно. Воспользуйтесь MVVM. (Если не знаете, что это такое, то отвлекитесь и прочитайте, без этого никуда.)

Заведите VM, обслуживающую одна кнопку. Заведите в ней свойство `RotationAngle`. Заведите другую VM, которая будет обслуживать все VM кнопок, и содержать их (назовём её `BoardVM`). При активизации кнопки отправьте команду в её VM. Эта VM пусть вызывает в этой точке метод `BoardVM`, информирующий о клике, а та в свою очередь вызывает метод на каждой VM в том же столбце и строке, а этот метод пусть увеличивает `RotationAngle`.

Теперь View. Привяжите список кнопок к списку VM через `ItemsSource` какого-нибудь `ItemsControl`'а. Привяжите `Command` каждой кнопки к команде из её VM. Привяжите угол поворота к свойству `RotationAngle`. Всё.

И не пытайтесь программировать на WPF как на WinForms. Будет очень неудобно и неэффективно, поверьте.

Comment: Можно посмотреть пример MVVM, например, [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/270445/10105).

Comment: спасибо! Посмотрел про MVVM, действительно, так реализовать будет намного легче и правильнее. Не могли бы Вы мне помочь разобраться в некоторых моментах, пожалуйста? [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573050/%D0%98%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wpf-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-winforms-%D0%B2-mvvm)

Answer (score 4):

Помимо замечаний @VladD, к которым я советую прислушаться рано или поздно, по факту поворот можно делать так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
    buttons[ColumnNumber, i].RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(90) 
    {
        CenterX = 50,
        CenterY = 10
    };  
}

for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
    buttons[i, RowNumber].RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(90) 
    {
        CenterX = 50,
        CenterY = 10
    };
}
```

Где `ColumnNumber` и `RowNumber` соответствующие значения для строки или столбца.

Comment: Прошу прощения, а как добавить данный код в обработчик события "клик"? А точнее, как нам передать `buttons[ColumnNumber, i]` в него?

Comment: @Saint, извиняюсь, к сожалению у меня не всегда есть возможность вовремя отвечать. Рад, что Ваша проблема уже решилась в другом посте.