# Игра на WPF, переносим код WinForms в MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу реализовать:
Button расположены квадратом (как 2-мерный массив NxN). 
При клике на кнопку поворачиваются все кнопки в одной строке и в одном столбце. 
Число N настраиваемое.
Начал сначала всё делать в `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, посоветовали всё сделать нормально и использовать `MVVM`. Код `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Button[,] CreateButtons(int quantity)
    {
        Form.Rows = quantity;
        Form.Columns = quantity;
        Button[,] buttons = new Button[quantity, quantity];
        for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < quantity; j++)
            {
                buttons[i, j] = new Button();
                buttons[i, j].Width = 100;
                buttons[i, j].Height = 20;
                buttons[i, j].Margin = new Thickness(5,80,0,0);
                buttons[i, j].Click += new RoutedEventHandler(new_button_click);
            }
        }
        return buttons;
    }

    void new_button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        if (btn != null)
        {
            var rotateTransform = btn.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
            var transform = new RotateTransform(90 + (rotateTransform == null ? 0 : rotateTransform.Angle));
            transform.CenterX = 50;
            transform.CenterY = 10;
            btn.RenderTransform = transform;
        }
    }

    private void AddToWrapPanel(int quantity, Button[,] buttons)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < quantity; j++)
            {
                Form.Children.Add(buttons[i, j]);
            }
    }

    private int GetQuantityButtons()
    {
        ComboBoxItem item = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
        int count = int.Parse((string)item.Content);
        return count;
    }

    private void СreateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Form.Children.Count > 0)
            Form.Children.Clear();
        int count = GetQuantityButtons();
        Button[,] buttons = CreateButtons(count);
        AddToWrapPanel(count, buttons);
    }
}
```

Теперь начинаю всё переносить.

`XAML`:

```
<Window x:Class="Di.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:user="clr-namespace:Di"
    Title="Сейф" Height="715.6" Width="840" Left="250" Top="10" Background="Silver" ResizeMode="CanMinimize"
    TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" Icon="Resources/Icon1.ico">
<Window.DataContext>
    <user:MainWindowModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl Margin="0,30,0,0">
        <UniformGrid x:Name="Form"/>
        <WrapPanel Name="wrapPanel" Background="#FFF2F2F2" />
    </ItemsControl>
    <Button Content="Старт" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="457,12,0,0" Name="createButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="СreateButton_Click" Command="{Binding Seter}" />
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="368,12,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" SelectedIndex="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.739">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Three}" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Four}" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Five}" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Six}" />
    </ComboBox>
    <Label Content="{Binding Lvl}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="254,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

Код `VM`:

```
public class MainWindowModel
{
    public int Three { get; set; }
    public int Four { get; set; }
    public int Five { get; set; }
    public int Six { get; set; }
    public string Lvl { get; set; }

    public MainWindowModel()
    {
        Three = 3;
        Four = 4;
        Five = 5;
        Six = 6;
        Lvl = "Сложность (3 - 6):";
    }

    private ICommand _seter;

    public ICommand Seter
    {
        get
        {
            return _seter ?? (_seter = new RelayCommand(() =>
              {
                  // действие при вызове команды
              }));
        }

    }

}
```

Пока только так.. Помогите, пожалуйста, перенести и доделать задуманные мной моменты. Например: как в `VM`, обслуживающем кнопку, завести свойство `RotationAngle`? Как при клике по "создать" с генерировать массив из кнопок и потом работать с ними? Как обращаться к `UniformGrid` и связать кол-во строк и столбцов с выбранным `int` в `combobox`?

Comment: Сейчас напишу, если кто-то другой не успеет до меня.

Comment: @VladD А можно таким образом передать `int` в `UnirormGrid`?
`<UniformGrid x:Name="Form" Rows="{Binding ElementName=comboBox1, Path=Value}" Columns="{Binding ElementName=comboBox1, Path=Value}"/>`

Comment: По идее можно, но лучше привязывать к VM. (Сорри, пока не написал ответ, но я напишу.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Давайте пойдём сначала. Построим VM. Нам пригодится базовый класс для VM, в котором будет имплементация `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value,
                         [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;

        field = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

(Если вы пользуетесь каким-нибудь MVVM-фреймворком, то аналогичный базовый класс у вас уже может быть определён.)

Теперь VM для одной клетки. Что нам нужно знать? Угол поворота — сделаем из него свойство с INPC. Строку и столбец — эти свойства неизменяемые. И команда, которая будет вызываться при активации клетки. (Она тоже неизменяемая.)

Действие, которое будет выполняться при нажатии на клетку, сама клетка выполнить не может, так как поворот происходит у многих клеток. Поэтому реакцию на действие передадим «сверху» в качестве параметра. Получаем такой вот код:

```
class CellVM : VM
{
    public CellVM(int row, int column, Action<int, int> onActivate)
    {
        Row = row;
        Column = column;
        Activate = new RelayCommand(() => onActivate(row, column));
    }

    double rotationAngle = 0;
    public double RotationAngle
    {
        get { return rotationAngle; }
        set { Set(ref rotationAngle, value); }
    }

    public int Row { get; }
    public int Column { get; }

    public ICommand Activate { get; }
}
```

Следующая VM — вся доска. Ей придётся и принимать решение о вращении клеток. Какие нам тут нужны данные? Ширина и высота нужны, и при изменении нужно пересоздать массив клеток. Нужны сами клетки, и поскольку клетки у нас будут подменяться только как целое, берём не `ObservableCollection<CellVM>`, а просто `IEnumerable<CellVM>`. Наружу выставлять квадратный массив нельзя, никто не умеет к нему привязываться. Поэтому выставим все клетки, «слитые» в одну общую последовательность.

```
class BoardVM : VM
{
    int width;
    public int Width
    {
        get { return width; }
        set { if (Set(ref width, value)) { GenerateCells(); } }
    }

    int height;
    public int Height
    {
        get { return height; }
        set { if (Set(ref height, value)) { GenerateCells(); } }
    }

    CellVM[,] cells;

    public IEnumerable<CellVM> AllCells => cells.Cast<CellVM>();
```

Далее, при изменении количества строк или столбцов нам нужно перегенерировать клетки.

```
    void GenerateCells()
    {
        var cells = new CellVM[width, height];
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
            for (int column = 0; column < width; column++)
                cells[column, row] = new CellVM(row, column, OnCellActivate);
        ShuffleAngles(cells);
        // отбрасываем существующие клетки
        this.cells = cells;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(AllCells));
    }
```

... и установить им случайный начальный угол:

```
    static Random random = new Random();
    void ShuffleAngles(CellVM[,] cells)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                cells[x, y].RotationAngle = random.Next(4) * 90;
    }
```

Теперь функция, которая вызывается при активации клетки. Нам нужно повернуть все клетки в том же столбце и той же строке. Во втором цикле пропускем уже один раз повёрнутую клетку.

```
    void OnCellActivate(int row0, int column0)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
            Rotate(cells[column0, row]);

        for (int column = 0; column < width; column++)
            if (column != column0)
                Rotate(cells[column, row0]);
    }

    void Rotate(CellVM cellVM)
    {
        cellVM.RotationAngle = (cellVM.RotationAngle + 90) % 360;
    }
}
```

---

Окей, с VM более-менее ясно. Переходим к View.

Нам понадобится `ItemsControl`, т. к. мы хотим показать последовательность элементов. У нас последовательность элементов содержится в свойстве `AllCells`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllCells}">
```

Далее, нам нужно, чтобы клетки укладывались в `UniformGrid`. Выберем в качестве носителя `UniformGrid`, заодно привяжем количество строк и столбцов:

```
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True"
                         Rows="{Binding Width}" Columns="{Binding Height}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Дальше, как показывать отдельную клетку? Вы хотите `Button`, пускай. Пишем `DataTemplate`.

```
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CellVM}">
            <Button Command="{Binding Activate}"/>
```

Запустив программу, видим, что кнопка слишком прилегает к границам клетки, поэтому даём ей `Margin="10"`. Теперь, нам нужно как-то обозначить, где верх и где низ. Для этого нарисуем стрелочку вверх (но вам придётся сделать что-то покрасивее). Стрелочку будем поворачивать на угол из привязки:

```
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CellVM}">
            <Button Command="{Binding Activate}" Margin="10" Padding="10">
                <Path Data="M 0,1 L 1,0 L 2,1 M 1,2 L 1,0"
                      Stroke="Black" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RotationAngle}"/>
                    </Path.RenderTransform>
                </Path>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Вроде бы всё.

```
</ItemsControl>
```

Теперь нужно ещё задать размеры поля.

Для этого, по-хорошему, нужно завести другое окно (и показывать его только в самом начале игры), потому что изменять размер поля во время игры как-то неправильно. Но в нашем быстром прототипе мы закроем на это глаза. (А вам потом придётся таки переделать.)

Итак, нам нужна информация о том, сколько у нас возможно строк и столбцов. Возвращаемся в VM и заводим класс:

```
static class GameInfo
{
    static public IEnumerable<int> PossibleColumnNumber { get; } = new[] { 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    static public IEnumerable<int> PossibleRowNumber { get; } = new[] { 3, 4, 5, 6 };
}
```

Для красоты, нам нужно инициализировать значения в `BoardVM` валидным числом. Находим и меняем строки:

```
    int width = GameInfo.PossibleColumnNumber.Min();
```

и

```
    int height = GameInfo.PossibleRowNumber.Min();
```

Теперь View. Дописываем два комбобокса и метки к ним:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Label Target="{Binding ElementName=ColumnChooser}">Columns: </Label>
    <ComboBox Name="ColumnChooser" SelectedItem="{Binding Width}"
              ItemsSource="{x:Static vm:GameInfo.PossibleColumnNumber}"/>
    <Label Target="{Binding ElementName=RowChooser}">Rows:</Label>
    <ComboBox Name="RowChooser" SelectedItem="{Binding Height}"
              ItemsSource="{x:Static vm:GameInfo.PossibleRowNumber}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Весь `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ViewModels"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        Title="Test" Height="350" Width="350">
    <Grid d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:BoardVM, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllCells}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True"
                                 Rows="{Binding Width}" Columns="{Binding Height}"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CellVM}">
                    <Button Command="{Binding Activate}" Margin="10" Padding="10">
                        <Path Data="M 0,1 L 1,0 L 2,1 M 1,2 L 1,0"
                              Stroke="Black" Stretch="Uniform"
                              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Path.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RotationAngle}"/>
                            </Path.RenderTransform>
                        </Path>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Label Target="{Binding ElementName=ColumnChooser}">Columns: </Label>
            <ComboBox Name="ColumnChooser" SelectedItem="{Binding Width}"
                      ItemsSource="{x:Static vm:GameInfo.PossibleColumnNumber}"/>
            <Label Target="{Binding ElementName=RowChooser}">Rows:</Label>
            <ComboBox Name="RowChooser" SelectedItem="{Binding Height}"
                      ItemsSource="{x:Static vm:GameInfo.PossibleRowNumber}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Теперь нам нужно прикрепить VM к View. Лучше всего делать это не в XAML, а в `App.xaml.cs` (смотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/10105)). Пишем:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    BoardVM boardVM = new BoardVM();

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        new MainWindow() { DataContext = boardVM }.Show();
    }
}
```

и убираем из App.xaml `StartupUri`.

Компилируем, запускаем. Сразу видим пустое поле. Недоработка, мы ж не сгенерировали поле в конструкторе `BoardVM`! Исправляем:

```
    public BoardVM()
    {
        GenerateCells();
    }
```

Вот что у меня получилось:

[image: анимашка]

Comment: Только у меня компилятор ругается много на что :)
'Why.BoardVM.cells' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'
'Why.GameInfo' does not contain a definition for 'PossibleRowNumber'
'Why.VM.PropertyChanged' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: @Saint: Окей, давайте строку, на которую ругается.

Comment: @Saint: А у вас какая версия студии? У меня всё компилируется (VS2015).

Comment: у меня Visual Studio 2012

Comment: @Saint: Ыыыыы! Ну да, старая Студия, старая версия языка. Тогда переписываем так: http://pastebin.com/GFYrQsX5

Comment: И смотрим, где следующая ошибка.

Comment: @Saint: Заменить на линии легко: `Data="M 0,1 M 2,1 M 1,2 L 1,0"`. А с сменой положения немного больше работы, заходите в чат.

Comment: Кажется, на последней гифке строки и столбцы перепутаны :)

Comment: @tym32167: Точно! :)