# Создание двумерного массива кнопок WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button

Есть массив кнопок:

```
Button[,] buttons = new Button[n,n];
```

Как пробегая по всем кнопкам на форме(или сетке), добавлять их в этот массив? И вообще как будет происходить "пробегание" по всем кнопкам(то есть в какой последовательности эти кнопки будут выбираться)?

Comment: @Foggy Finder а если на форме есть не только кнопки?

Comment: @Foggy Finder  Да, если не трудно, я хотел бы получить массив кнопок 5х5 и снизу два лэйбла,каждый занимающий по 2 ячейки

Comment: А зачем вам это? Квадратный массив кнопок выглядит странно и очень в стиле WinForms. Опишите свою настоящую задачу.

Comment: @VladD Это сапер,причем размер поля можно выбрать,соответственно мне нужно уметь задавать сетку и размещать в каждой из ее ячеек кнопку

Comment: @Draktharon: Ага, понял. Где-то на сайте был пример, я найду. Только вам нужны не кнопки же, кнопки ведут себя совсем не так, как вам нужно.

Comment: @VladD а что же нужно?

Comment: @Draktharon: Нужен UserControl какой-нибудь, например.

Comment: @Draktharon: Вот вам пример того, как нужно привязывать к списку элементов, чтобы было квадратное поле: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573196/10105. Дубликат?

Comment: @VladD Спасибо,пока что сложно,но как-нибудь разберусь

Comment: @Foggy Finder можете пояснить, что значит "Создаете ItemsControl (можно взять обычный ListBox) и определить для него шаблон."?

Comment: @FoggyFinder пишите в ответы

Answer (score 1):

Я бы пошёл следующим путём:

1. Найти `List<Button> allButtons` — список всех элементов на форме.
2. Вложенными циклами перебрать высоту и ширину формы, и проверить, есть ли на этой точке кнопка (top/left position) (простым `allButtons.Where()` проверяешь).
3. Если кнопка есть на этой же строке — добавлять в двумерный массив в эту же строку.
4. Если на этой строке пикселей кнопки нет, но есть на следующей — это уже новая строка двумерного массива.

Может и кривовато, но работать будет точно. И точно ничего не пропустишь.