# WPF (C#) Splash экран прогресса загрузки в отдельном потоке

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

Имеется приложение. Первый запуск. Авторизация.

Основное окно понимает, что нет сохранённых данных и выдаёт окно авторизации.
Основное окно при этом ещё даже не отобразилось.

После ввода логина/пароля в форме авторизации, та отправляет запрос на сервер и получает токен.

Получив токен, второе окно закрывается и возвращает управление основному. Авторизация проходит за доли секунды.

Но после авторизации на сервер надо отправить повторный запрос для получения коллекции данных и в последствии занести их в БД. Всё это нужно сделать **до** отображения основной формы пользователю.

Этот запрос выполняется уже от 5 секунд и дольше, в зависимости от количества получаемых данных.

Необходимо после авторизации и передачи управления основному окну сразу же отобразить пользователю Splash-экран (красивенькое окно с информацией о прогрессе), а в отдельном потоке выполнить запрос.

По завершении выполнения запроса, закрыть Splash-экран и вернуть управление основному для уже непосредственно его отображения и работы с ним.

Основное окно нельзя отображать до получения данных, ибо вся им отображаемая информация будет браться из полученной по запросу информации. Без неё это голый шаблон, который пользователю видеть не нужно.

Проблема в том, что у меня нет опыта разработки многопоточных приложений, поэтому хотелось бы услышать советов от знающей аудитории.

**Как подобное правильно реализовать?**

**Дополнительная информация:** при втором и следующих запусках программы, она будет брать данные авторизации из сохранённых свойств (*Property.Settings.Default*), а данные для отображения в основном окне будет брать из локального файлы БД, в который будут кэшироваться результаты запроса данных.

В последствии программа будет через определённый интервал запускать в отдельном потоке запрос на обновление данных в локальной БД и обновлении отображаемой в окне информации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смысла делать многопоточный UI обычно нету. Типичное WPF-приложение работает так: UI бежит в одном, главном потоке, VM (это объекты для отображения и бизнес-логика) — в том же самом главном потоке, модели (базы данных, сеть, вычисления) — в главном и фоновых потоках.

Для начала, нужно сделать так, чтобы в начале работы не показывалось главное окно автоматически. Для этого из `App.xaml` удаляем `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"`.

Окей, что дальше? Дальше нам нужно показать окна в code-behind. Идём в `App.xaml.cs` и пишем следующее:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var mainVM = new MainVM();
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow() { DataContext = mainVM };
        mainWindow.Show();    
    }
}
```

Это равносильный вариант, который показывает главное окно. Теперь добавим логику авторизации.

```
protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    var mainVM = new MainVM();
    Window authorizationWindow = null;
    if (!mainVM.HasCredentials()) // нет авторизации?
    {
        // выдаём окно
        var authorizationVM = new AutorizationVM();
        authorizationWindow = new AutorizationWindow() { DataContext = authorizationVM };
        authorizationWindow.Show();
        await authorizationVM.RunAuthorization();
        // в этой точке у нас есть авторизация, скармливаем её в MainVM
        mainVM.SetCredentials(authorizationVM);
    }

    // теперь мы авторизованы, отправляем запрос данных
    // окно, которое отображает Splash
    var dataProgressWindow = new ProgressWindow() { DataContext = mainVM };
    dataProgressWindow.Show();
    // когда мы открыли новое окно, можно закрыть старое
    authorizationWindow?.Close(); // знак вопроса нужен, а то вдруг null
    // дожидаемся конца загрузки данных
    await mainVM.DownloadData();
    // тут мы готовы к работе, запускаем главное окно
    var mainWindow = new MainWindow() { DataContext = mainVM };
    mainWindow.Show();
    // а сплэш-скрин можно закрыть
    dataProgressWindow.Close();
    // я обычно для симметрии делаю ещё
    // await mainVM.Run(); mainWindow.Close();
    // но это не обязательно
}
```

Для этого вам придётся разделить логику и представление и немного подучить MVVM.

Comment: я правильно понял, что для начала я должен переместить все поля и свойства не имеющие отнощения к UI из MainWindow в новосозданный класс MainVM? И все методы, которые вы используете для VM это лишь абстрактные методы для примера, а не какие-то стандартные?

Comment: и ещё MainVM это простой класс или для связки с окном он должен наследоваться от чего-то? просто я до этого не работал с DataContext,  а тут вы этому полю присваивайте экземпляр класса mainVM

Comment: @Mr.Modest: Именно так. Это MVVM-подход, способствует отделению контента от представления.

Comment: @Mr.Modest: MainVM должен имплементировать `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Вот есть пример: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573196/10105

Comment: @Mr.Modest: В WPF `Binding` происходит к тому, что лежит в `DataContext`.

Comment: а как быть с подобным кодом? http://pastebin.com/G1he6mHF
у меня тут окно не пускает дальше, пока не будет совершён успешный вход, иначе выдаёт ошибку и просит логин/пароль по новой. Плюс, сохраняет данные авторизации, если стоит галочка.. как подобное реализовать в виде `await authorizationVM.RunAuthorization();` ?

Comment: ещё мне почему-то такую ошибку выдаёт, когда я пытаюсь в XAML прописать DataContext слудующей строкой `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:MainVM, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}`. Ошибка: Имя "MainVM" не существует в пространстве имен "clr-namespace:ShikiDeskVM". Хотя я вроде всё верно сделал.. добавил псевдоним.. VM в отдельном пространстве имён и назвал я его именно ShikiDeskVM =/

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54972/discussion-between-vladd-and-mr-modest).