# Wpf Взаимодействие данных в паттерне MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Изучая паттерн научился более менее связывать элементы окон со свойствами ViewModel, то есть классах, как я понимаю, посредниках между кодом/логикой и окном. Однако при поиске того как коду/логике взаимодействовать с ViewModel потерпел фиаско. При самостоятельных попытках связывания приходил к одному и тому-же - нет единого центра управления. Кажется весь смысл в том чтобы единого центра не было, но я совершенно не понимаю как реализовать подобную логику. Пытался искать примеры, но все они манипулируют какими-то запредельно сложными для новичка фичами C#. Объясните пожалуйста как мне например сделать окно авторизации и перехода в какой нибудь холл/домашнюю_страничку.

#### Такой будет код замла:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Login, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBox FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Pass, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Button Height="30" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

#### С# код окна:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ViewModel ViewModel = new ViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = ViewModel;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.Login = "1111";
        ViewModel.Pass = "2222";
    }
}
```

#### Код ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string login;
    private string pass;

    public string Login { get { return login; } set { login = value; OnPropertyChanged("Login"); } }
    public string Pass { get { return pass; } set { pass = value; OnPropertyChanged("Pass"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

### Надеюсь вы не ослепните

Как видно единственный способ для привязки ViewModel каким я владею - это указание его в коде с помощью DataContext. При этом создается объект который никак и нигде не контролируется. Не говоря уже о том чтобы организовать взаимодействие всех данных между собой. В данном примере логика помещена в метод клик, так как я представить не могу как логику написанную в отдельном файле и привязать сюда без костылей.

Comment: Посмотрите [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/573050/10105), тут вроде неплохой пример.

Comment: В частности, активация изменений в VM должна быть через команду.

Comment: Если у вас сделана привязка `{Binding Login, Mode=TwoWay}`, то вот это `ViewModel.Login = "1111";` в кодбихайнд делать не надо. Скачайте и посмотрите [пример](https://yadi.sk/d/ud7mV3Fbwqr6G).

Comment: @Bulson, ваш пример очень хорошо демонстрирует паттерн. Мне не хватает знаний в плане C# чтобы я мог использовать приемы из примера. Но механизм взаимодействия теперь мне понятен. Спасибо

Comment: Рекомендую вам скопировать из этого примера файл класса `RelayCommand` он вам пригодится в реализации команд в собственных проектах.

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите.

Вот что у вас неправильно — вы создаёте VM-классы в конструкторе окна. Это неправильно, потому что при этом вы не сможете легко связать VM-классы между собой.

Если вам нужно сделать несколько окон, нужно поместить программную логику в общее место. Например, в App.xaml.cs. В этом случае вы легко можете связать ваши окна. Пример:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    AuthorizationVM authVM = new AuthorizationVM();
    MainVM mainVM;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        var authWindow = new AuthorizationWindow() { DataContext = authVM };
        authWindow.Closed += OnAuthorizationFinished;
        authWindow.Show();
    }

    void OnAuthorizationFinished(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!authVM.IsAuthorizationSuccessful)
             Shutdown();

        mainVM = new MainVM(authoVM.Credentials);

        var mainWindow = new MainWindow() { DataContext = mainVM };
        mainWindow.Closed += OnMainWindowClosed;
        mainWindow.Show();
    }

    void OnMainWindowClosed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Shutdown();
    }
}
```

и так далее.

Не забудьте указать в `App.xaml` `ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"`.

Comment: **1.** В этом [примере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1546637/Почему-родительский-viewmodel-в-дочернем-становится-null) тоже можно запихнуть все взаимодействия между VM в App.cs?
**2.** Может есть возможность поделится примером?

Comment: @eusataf: 1. По идее можно, но можно и раскидать по классам. Главное, не делать этого в XAML’е, он для этого не предназначен. 2. А примером чего? Посмотрите [тут на сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a10105%20%5bwpf%5d&searchOn=3), у меня раньше было много ответов по тегу wpf.

Comment: Да.. Спасибо... Я постепенно изучаю по вашим ответам... Очень доходичво...
Но нехватает полноценных примеров... Например в [wpf-c-splash-экран-прогресса-загрузки-в-отдельном-потоке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/635879/313265) многое не понял... Фрагметы...
Целого примера нет...
Может у вас есть возможность дать ссылку на ваш Гитхаб... Я там может выберу себе чтонибудь интересное...
Спасибо...

Comment: @eusataf: У меня есть гитхаб, в основном для мелких примеров кода: https://github.com/vladd/. Не уверен, что вы найдёте там много полезной информации.