# Почему родительский ViewModel в дочернем становится null?

Tags: c#, wpf

Почему родительский ViewModel в дочернем становится null ?

Для взаимодействия между дочерней и родительской ViewModel, я передал ссылку на родительскую ViewModel в дочернюю ViewModel .

Когда вовремя отладки я открываю окно  `ManagerIndexesViewModel.IndexesViewModel`, то член `ManagerIndexesViewModel`, который находится в  `IndexesViewModel` не равен нулю.

Когда я вбираю строку в `IndexesView.DataGrid`, то в свойстве `SelectedIndexCalculation` я получаю `this.managerIndexesViewModel = null` (в строке `this.managerIndexesViewModel.SelectedIndexCalculation = SelectedIndexCalculation;`).

**IndexesViewModel**

```cs
public IndexCalculation SelectedIndexCalculation
{
    get { return selectedIndexCalculation; }
    set 
    { 
        selectedIndexCalculation = value;

        Debug.WriteLine($"--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---");
        Debug.WriteLine($"IndexesViewModel--selectedIndexCalculation -- {selectedIndexCalculation.Name}");
        this.managerIndexesViewModel.SelectedIndexCalculation = SelectedIndexCalculation;

        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedIndexCalculation));
    }
}
```

Проект:  https://github.com/jhon65496/WpfFrmApp1QPublic

---

**Минимальный код**

**ManagerIndexesViewModel**

```cs
public class ManagerIndexesViewModel : BaseVM
{  
    IndexesViewModel indexesViewModel;
    //. Code .... 

    public ManagerIndexesViewModel()
    {
        // ViewModel
        this.indexesViewModel = new IndexesViewModel(this);
        // Code
        // .....
        

        // View
        IndexesView = this.indexesViewModel;
        // Code
        // .....

        SelectedIndexCalculation = indexesViewModel.SelectedIndexCalculation;
    }
```

---

**IndexesViewModel**

```cs
public class IndexesViewModel : BaseVM
{
    
    public ManagerIndexesViewModel managerIndexesViewModel;
    public IndexesViewModel(ManagerIndexesViewModel managerIndexesViewModel)
    {
        this.managerIndexesViewModel = managerIndexesViewModel;

        LoadDataTest();
    }


    public IndexesViewModel()
    {   
        
        LoadDataTest();
    }

    


    private ObservableCollection<IndexCalculation> calculationIndexs;

    public ObservableCollection<IndexCalculation> СalculationIndexs
    {
        get { return calculationIndexs; }
        set 
        { 
            calculationIndexs = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(СalculationIndexs));
        }
    }

    private IndexCalculation selectedIndexCalculation;

    public IndexCalculation SelectedIndexCalculation
    {
        get { return selectedIndexCalculation; }
        set 
        { 
            selectedIndexCalculation = value;

            Debug.WriteLine($"--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---");
            Debug.WriteLine($"IndexesViewModel--selectedIndexCalculation -- {selectedIndexCalculation.Name}");
            

            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedIndexCalculation));
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[[image: введите сюда описание изображения][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifckw.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В вопросе нет проблемных мест, ибо они в XAML, который вы нам не показали. Вся ваша проблема в `<vvm:IndexesViewModel/>` - это тоже самое, если вы сделаете `DataContext = new IndexesViewModel()`, и вы будете постоянно при рендере данной страницы инициализировать новый контекст, и самое важное, будет инициализироваться класс с конструктором без параметров, ну а теперь найдите в своем коде `public IndexesViewModel() { .. }` и посмотрите, задаете вы там `managerIndexesViewModel` или нет. Вообще установка контекста в XAML [плохо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553).

Comment: Уберите конструктор `public IndexesViewModel()` и узнаете, почему.

Comment: @aepot Хочу в дизайнере XAML видеть данные, а для этого нуден конструктор без параметров. 
Если я правильно понял...
Нагородил такое: https://github.com/jhon65496/WpfFrmApp1QPublic/tree/apt01
Вроде работает...
Не сильно коряво? Или пойдёт?
У меня цель: просто подёргать различные приёмы.
Без глубоко погружения в биндинги, MVVM, архитектуры, DI.
Буду признателен за любые замечания, предложения.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ см. выше комментарий для `aepot`

Comment: Заставлять студию отображать данные в реальном времени - плохая затея. Хотите видеть в реальном времени - запустите проект и пишите с использованием Hot Reload все, что вам надо, многое будете видеть прям в реал тайме. Ну а дизайнер студии... Он очень корявый, прям очень, кучу всего до сих пор делает криво, из-за чего многие программисты попросту от него отказываются.  Ну а если прям очень надо видеть в студии что-то, то делайте фейковые данные (я вроде показывал как), а не отображайте в реал тайме, ибо в реал у вас вовсе может студия виснуть (если проект большой) и делать кучу лишнего.

Comment: _Не сильно коряво?_ - руками окно создавать надо не в конструкторе `App`, а `protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) { base.OnStartup(e); ...здесь... }`