# Отображение разного содержимого в одном окне WPF + MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Добрый вечер.
Собственно, вопрос заключается в том , как в одном окне отображать разное содержимое
К примеру то же приложение киви десктопное.
Вводишь пин и там уже совершенно другое отрисовывается

Вообще узнаю для того , чтобы понять: как сделать так , чтоб при запуске десктоп приложения проверялось авторизован ли пользователь, если нет - то будет отображена форма авторизации, иначе будет отображено основной интерфейс программы.
Я профан в это деле и только начал познавать Wpf + mvvm.
И желательно как можно подробнее описать всё это дело
Не кидайтесь тапками, пожалуйста :)

Приложение Киви:
[image: Приложение киви]

Comment: Сделать несколько UserControl и поместить их в корневой грид, в зависимости от ситуации отображать нужный контрол, остальные скрывать

Comment: не C#, но вот пример на F#: https://github.com/ReedCopsey/Gjallarhorn.Bindable/tree/master/samples/Collections

Comment: но есть также много вариантов страничной навигации и здесь на ruSO

Comment: а если вас интересует именно авторизация, то среди открытых хороших примеров не знаю (правда и не искал)

Comment: Смотри ContentControl.

Answer (score 16):

Очень просто. Возьмите `ContentPresenter` или `ContentControl`.

Положите контент окна, каким он должен быть в начале, в первый `UserControl` (пусть будет `AuthorizationPresentation`), а контент, который должен появиться потом — во второй `UserControl` (`MainPresentation`).

Заведите себе два VM-класса: `AuthorizationVM` (для авторизации) и `MainVM` (для основного контента), а также `RootVM`:

```
class RootVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    object currentContentVM;
    public object CurrentContentVM
    {
        get => currentContentVM;
        set => /* тут имплементация INotifyPropertyChanged */
    }
}
```

Ваш XAML будет выглядеть так:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AuthorizationVM}">
            <view:AuthorizationPresentation/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MainVM}">
            <view:MainPresentation/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentContentVM}"/>
</Window>
```

Установите `DataContext`'ом окна экземпляр `RootVM`.

Теперь вы можете регулировать, какой контент показывается в окне, устанавливая в `RootVM` свойство `CurrentContentVM`. Если записать туда экземпляр `AuthorizationVM`, будет показан `AuthorizationPresentation`, а если `MainVM` — то `MainPresentation`.

Всё!

---

Небольшое дополнение: а как связать между собой VM? Для этого разные VM должны создаваться не в XAML-коде своего View, а отдельно, в начале программы, которая занимается настройкой всего. Для этого имеет смысл [установить точку входа в `OnStartup`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/10105). Примеры того, как переключать VM, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/635879/10105) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/757541/10105). Логику приложения, по идее, имеет смысл вынести из `OnStartup` в корневую VM.

Comment: А как быть, если нужно при нажатии на кнопку в ``AuthorizationPresentation`` поменять ``CurrentContentVM`` у ``RootVM`` на ``MainVM``, если ``AuthorizationVM`` не имеет ссылки на ``RootVM``?

Comment: @alladuh: Ну это по сути вопрос для `MainVM`. Например, `AuthorizationVM` может определить событие `AuthorizationComplete`, на которое `MainVM` подписывается и меняет `RootVM`, когда оно происходит. Или (более модный метод) `AuthorizationVM` определяет метод `Task<bool> Run() { return tcs.Task; } TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(); void OnOK() { tcs.TrySetResult(true); void OnCancel() { tcs.TrySetResult(false); }` ну и т. д.

Comment: Все таки лучше бы дополнить ответ тем, как можно теперь на практике по нажатию на кнопку переключить отображение одной View на другую. Ведь в ресурсах прописаны въюмодели с конструктором по-умолчанию. И как тогда передавать ссылку на RootVM, чтоб из другой въюмодели поменять значение свойства `CurrentContentVM`? Из вашего ответа это остается неясным.

Comment: @Bulson: Я найду, где-то у меня был пример. В двух словах: view не должна никогда создавать себе самой VM.

Comment: @Bulson: Дописал ответ

Comment: @VladD спасибо.