# Навигация WPF/MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Как правильно реализовать навигацию в WPF приложении, не нарушая MVVM?

Есть несколько "блоков MVVM"(`MainView`-`MainModel`-`MainViewModel`, `DeviceView`-`DeviceModel`-`DeviceViewModel`,...). Как следует организовать переход с главного окна на другие? Открывать новые или использовать одно, главное окно и `UserControl'ы`? И правильно ли будет, что при использовании второго способа, `UserControl` станет представлением(`View`)?

Comment: Ну а вы как хотите-то? Внутри одного окна переходить или в разных открывать?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я думаю будет лучше открывать окна. Просмотрел несколько статей и в них либо используется UserControl, либо Page, но не уделяется внимание окнам, это меня и озадачило.

Comment: Открытие окон в рамках MVVM - очень скользкая тема. Менять контент одного окна - гораздо проще...

Comment: @АндрейNOP Тогда UserControl становится View для другой модели?

Comment: По сути - да. Вот пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/763691/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать Prism Framework, там все эти вопросы решены