# Новое окно в WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, окно

Есть два окна: MainWindow и Window1
В MainWindow есть кнопка:

```
<Button x:Name="MyFirstButton" Click="MyFirstButton" Content="MyFirstTextInButton" Margin="0 0 0 5" Padding="5" FontSize="15"/>
```

При нажатии на кнопку нужно вызвать окно Window1.
Нужно два варианта:

1. Чтобы оно открывалось как отдельное окно
2. Чтобы оно открывалось в этом же окне (как в обычных программах при открытии, скажем, папки в проводнике)

Comment: 1. Ну тут проблем, я думаю не возникнет, создаёте экземпляр класса Window1 и вызываете методом Show(). 2. Тут можно попробовать использовать UserControl, чтобы содержимое MainWindow подменялось при нажатии на кнопку на UserControl

Comment: С первым получилось. Можете, пожалуйста, показать, как использовать UserControl?

Comment: Сейчас, увы, сам написать не смогу, но вот то что вам нужно, правда там идёт реализация паттерна MVVM https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/285928

Comment: Если до утра никто не ответит, распишу сам

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отображение разного содержимого в одном окне WPF + MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763691/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b5-wpf-mvvm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите.

Для того, чтобы один и тот же контент можно было использовать в разных местах, проще всего использовать `UserControl`.

Таким образом, ваш код будет структурирован следующим образом:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourNamespace.Window1Content" ...>
    <!-- сюда помещаете то, что у вас внутри Window1 -->
</UserControl>
```

Заводите окно `Window1` так:

```
<Window x:Class="YourNamespace.Window1"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:YourNamespace" ...>
    <view:Window1Content/>
<Window/>
```

Теперь, если нужно показать окно, вы создаёте `new Window1()` и вызываете метод `Show()`. Если же нужно показать содержимое окна в другом окне, внутри некоторого элемента, пишете

```
mainWindow.Content = new Window1Content();
```

или там

```
mainGrid.Children.Clear();
mainGrid.Children.Add(new Windows1Content());
```

Если вы пользуетесь MVVM (а как же без него?), не забудьте установить правильный `DataContext`.