# Обращение из одного xaml к элементу другого xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть много view, которые похожи друг на друга, но есть и отличия.Но общий вид схож. Я написал образец view как база. У него есть элемент ContentControl = "AreaUser_1", в который хотелось бы вставлять свой вид. Есть способ обратиться к этому элементу из другого Xaml?
Пример:
База(образец)

```
    <UserControl x:Class="PCCD.View.TemlateSingleSettingsView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        xmlns:localVM="clr-namespace:PCCD.ViewModel"
        xmlns:localV="clr-namespace:PCCD.View"
        >

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localVM:LinkTable_RTUViewModel}">
                <localV:LinkTable_RTUView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localVM:LinkTable_COMViewModel}">
                <localV:LinkTable_COMView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="GridTest" x:FieldModifier="public" 
          >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                   Text="{Binding Name}" 
                   Margin="2"
                   />        
        <ContentControl x:Name="AreaUser_1"
                        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
                        Content="{Binding AreaUser1}"
                        />
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Content="{Binding LinkSettingsVM}"
                        />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Вот xaml, которому нужно обратиться к AreaUser_1

```
    <UserControl x:Class="PCCD.View.DeviceSettingsView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        xmlns:localVM="clr-namespace:PCCD.ViewModel"
        xmlns:localV="clr-namespace:PCCD.View"
        >

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localVM:TemlateSingleSettingsViewModel}">
            <localV:TemlateSingleSettingsView />
        </DataTemplate>

        <localV:TemlateSingleSettingsView x:Key="Templ">

        </localV:TemlateSingleSettingsView>

        <Grid x:Key="Area1" x:Name="AreaUser1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="DeviceAdd"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Margin="2"
            Width="16"
            Content="+"
            Command="{Binding Path=AddDevice}"
            />
            <Button x:Name="DeviceRemove"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="{Binding ElementName=DeviceAdd, Path=Margin}"
            Height="{Binding ElementName=DeviceAdd, Path=Height}"
            Width="{Binding ElementName=DeviceAdd, Path=Width}"
            Content="-"
            Command="{Binding Path=RemoveDevice}"
            />
        </Grid>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ContentControl x:Name="ContT" Content="{StaticResource Templ}">
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: Кажется, вам нужно вот это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/10105. Только `ContentPresenter` нужно будет вставлять не на уровень окна, а вместо `<ContentControl x:Name="AreaUser_1"`.

Comment: Не совсем то что нужно. По ссылке рассказывается подмена view. А мне нужно запихать в тот content к примеру кнопку для одного, для другого combobox, при этом обе view будут отображаться

Comment: Если вам нужно показывать несколько View, положите в XAML ItemsControl, и в VM добавляйте туда VM-элементы. Отображение каждого VM-элемента задавайте через DataTemplate.

Comment: @КонстантинМефодьев Удалось ли что-нибудь придумать? Тоже интересует решение данного вопроса, пока ничего не удалось найти..

Comment: Как именно обратиться из Xaml к Xaml не нашел. Сделал по другому: Скажем так что в "Базе" наша AreaUser1 байндиться AreaUser1ViewModel. В "Наследнике" с помощью DataTemplate ассоциируем AreaUser1ViewModel с необходимой View