# WPF Как сделать ListBox c фреймами

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу сделать Total Commander. Для большей гибкости хочу чтобы списки с файлами было любое количество. Для этого решил сделать список из фреймов.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Frames}">
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Frame DataContext="{Binding Path=Context}" 
                Source="/TotalCommander;component/View/FileBrowser.xaml"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Но ничего не вышло.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в качестве содержимого DataTemplate сделать содержимое фрейма

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                ... тело фрейма Grid и т.д.
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Получается рванье которое на которое можно только смотреть. Ничего нельзя нажимать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите как быть.

Comment: В WPF элемент `Frame` - весьма специфический и предназначен немного для других целей. Вам лучше вынести все, что нужно по своему `UserControl` и в последующем использовать их. Если хотите к примеру одному элементу сделать разный вид (другой `UserControl`), то задайте `DataTemplate`, а если хотите сделать что то по типу страниц, то сделайте свойство, которое будет содержать текущий VM и его привяжите к `ContentPresenter` ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553)). В общем, отказывайтесь от `Frame`, мой вам совет...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Сделал через UserControl, но элементы не реагируют на нажатия. Думаю это из-за того что они в ListBox. Может подскажете как решить эту проблему.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать просто `ItemsControl`, ListBox тут избыточен.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ С ItemsControl проблема осталась :(

Comment: Давайте тогда [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), будем разбираться. Так, я без понятия что и какие нажатия у вас там не работают...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Извините за потраченное время. Проблема была в TextBlock который имел те же координаты в Grid и из-за этого ничего не работало. Час убил на эту мелочь.