# Как получить доступ к MainWindow viewmodel из Page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

Пытаюсь разобраться с WPF. В моем примере мне нужно получить доступ к MainWindow viewmodel из Page в XAML.
У меня есть одно решение для реализации этого. Но я хочу узнать еще способы. Особенно как сделать это из XAML.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="FunAnkiWPF.MainWindow"
...omitted for brevity
Height="450" Width="800"
DataContext="{Binding ViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
Self}}">
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{        
    public MainWindowViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(this);
        InitializeComponent();            
    }     
}
```

**StartPage.xaml** (**обычная страница**)

**StartPage.xaml.cs** (**Решение которое работает**)

```
public partial class StartPage : Page
{
    public StartPage()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = App.Current.MainWindow.DataContext;
    } 
}
```

Как получить прямой доступ к MainWindow ViewModel (в XAML и в codebehind)?
Как получить доступ к MainWindow.DataContext в XAML (как в моем CodeBehind)?

Comment: Ну раз вы пишете по MVVM, то сразу говорю на вашу ошибку - Установка DataContect в View окна, это нарушение паттерна MVVM. Также я очень сильно советую вам отказаться от подхода установки страниц через Page (я на 90% уверен, что у вас там еще и Frame завалялся где то...).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Frame завалялся. А какой подход лучше?

Comment: [Этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553)