# Binding в C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, usercontrol

Есть в главном окне label

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{StaticResource h}" Content="{Binding Path=test}"/>
```

Binding - работает.

Есть в главном окне

```
<controls:uc x:Name="tttt" DataContext="{StaticResource h}" MyProperty="{Binding Path=test}"/>
```

Binding - НЕ работает.

Исходник uc

```
public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); lCaption.Content = value.ToString(); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(uc), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

Почему не работает? С label всё отлично но если нужно сделать Binding к label в UserControl начинаются танцы с бубном и всё равно не работает.

Comment: Почему вы всем ставите **статичный** `DataContext`?  Он во-первых должен быть не статичным, а во-вторых устанавливаться один раз окну. Далее, как в XAML контрола у вас привязано `MyProperty`?

Comment: Я с WPF на давно работаю и почему он не должен быть статичным? "Далее, как в XAML контрола у вас привязано MyProperty?" - никак, lCaption.Content = value.ToString(); - разве тут не должен content лейбла измениться?

Comment: Статика, в таком исполнении - зло! Запомните это раз и на всегда. Сам же контролл состоит из XAML и c# части, думаете это просто так? Задайте самому UC в начале имя (`<UserControl ... x:Name="uc" ...>`), далее привяжите свой элемент `<Lable Content="{Binding MyProperty, ElementName=uc}">`. Можете посмотреть любой ответ тут на SO по `UserControl`, например [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/940724/220553).

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло.

Comment: Подскажи  ещё плиз как прибиндить столбец из DataTable {Binding Path=test.Rows[0][0]} - так работает. А так {Binding Path=test.Rows[0]["x"]} - нет.

Comment: Ну начнем с того, что это другой вопрос, а тут принято их задавать отдельно. А по проблеме - читайте логи, вам студия должна говорить что ей не нравиться в окне вывода.