# ListBox в дизайнере не отображается в UserControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, usercontrol

Как отобразить **ListBox**  в режиме разработчика в  **MenuControl.xaml** ?

В  **MainWindow.xaml** отображается.

По материалам: [Обратиться из UserControl к MainWindow MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/940724/313265)
Проект: https://github.com/jhon65496/QDisplayListBoxInUC

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="MasterDetail0202Detail.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MasterDetail0202Detail"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainWindowViewModel , IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Margin="0,1,0,-1">                
        <GroupBox Header="Master" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">                           
                <local:MenuControl DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>            
        </GroupBox>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MenuControl.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="MasterDetail0202Detail.MenuControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MasterDetail0202Detail"             
             Background="White"
             mc:Ignorable="d"              
             x:Name="Control" 
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainWindowViewModel , IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <GroupBox Header="Меню" >
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=ItemsSource}"                   
                 SelectedIndex="1"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=SelectedItem}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <DockPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="3"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=State}" Margin="3"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ListBox>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MenuControl **

```cs
// <summary>
/// Логика взаимодействия для UserControl1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MenuControl : UserControl
{
    public MenuControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "ItemsSource", 
                typeof(IEnumerable), 
                typeof(MenuControl), 
                new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "SelectedItem", 
                typeof(object), 
                typeof(MenuControl), 
                new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get => GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
    }
}
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    

    public App()
    {
        MainWindowViewModel mainViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

        var mainWin = new MainWindow();
        mainWin.DataContext = mainViewModel;
        mainWin.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        mainWin.Show();
    }

}
```

**MainWindowViewModel**

```cs
internal class MainWindowViewModel : BaseVM
{

    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }

    public TestDataContext dataContext;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        dataContext = new TestDataContext();

        LoadMenuItems();
    }


    private BaseVM currentContent;
    public BaseVM CurrentContent
    {
        get => currentContent;
        set
        {
            currentContent = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    private MenuItem selectedMenuItem;

    public MenuItem SelectedMenuItem
    {
        get { return selectedMenuItem; }
        set
        {
            selectedMenuItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
            Debug.WriteLine("MainWindowViewModel--Prop--SelectedMenuItem");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Загрузка списка меню
    /// </summary>
    private async void LoadMenuItems()
    {
        //Загрузка списка меню
        var menuItems = await dataContext.GetMenuItemsAsync();
        this.MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>(menuItems);

    }
}
```

**BaseVM**

```cs
class BaseVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

```cs
internal class MenuItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Sort { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NameVm { get; set; }        
    public string State { get; set; }
    public BaseVM ViewModel { get; set; }

}
```

```cs
class TestDataContext
{
    // private readonly List<MenuItem> _people;

    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
    //ctor
    public TestDataContext()
    {
        MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>()
        {
            new MenuItem {Name = "Страница 1", NameVm = "FirstPageViewModel", State  = "Статус1"},
            new MenuItem {Name = "Страница 2", NameVm = "SecondPageViewModel", State = "Статус1"}
        };

    }
  

    public Task<IEnumerable<MenuItem>> GetMenuItemsAsync()
    {   
        return Task.FromResult(MenuItems.AsEnumerable());
    }
}
```

### Update-1

https://github.com/jhon65496/QDisplayListBoxInUC

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MasterDetail0202Detail.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MasterDetail0202Detail"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainWindow, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Margin="0,1,0,-1">                
        <GroupBox Header="Master" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">                           
                <local:MenuControl ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>            
        </GroupBox>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MenuControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MasterDetail0202Detail.MenuControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MasterDetail0202Detail"             
             Background="White"
             mc:Ignorable="d"              
             x:Name="Control" 
             
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <GroupBox Header="Меню" >
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=ItemsSource}"                   
                 SelectedIndex="1"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=SelectedItem}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <DockPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="3"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=State}" Margin="3"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ListBox>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148982/discussion-on-question-by-eusataf-listbox------usercont); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.