# WPF DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Как заставить Window и Page взаимодействовать с единственным на двоих ViewModel? У меня есть Окно:

```
<Window x:Class="SoftwareCost.MainWindow"
    .... Height="350" Width="600">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Frame Name="Main" Content="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
```

И ViewModel который реализует переход по страница (каждая кнопка ссылается на ICommand из ViewModel)
Одна из страниц это по сути меню программы с 5 кнопками на всё окно. 
Проблема в том, что если я укажу таким же образом DataContext для страницы с меню, это будет уже другой экземпляр ViewModel, а мне нужно чтобы действия (клики по кнопкам) на MenuPage производили изменения поля CurrentPage из DataContext который указан в MainWindows.
Надеюсь понятно объяснил. (Если очень коротко 2 XAML файла должны ссылаться на единственный объект ViewModel)
Я пробовал делать ViewModel синглтоном, но так и не понял как на него ссылаться из xaml. Просто из кода либо ничего не работало, либо приводило к исключению как название этого сайта. Возможно есть другие пути решения.

---

Сделал таким образом, теперь у меня в MainWindow.xaml так:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate
        DataType="{x:Type vm:MainMenuVM}">
        <v:MainMenu />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate
        DataType="{x:Type vm:DataBaseEditorVM}">
        <v:DataBaseEditor />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentContentVM}"/>
```

RootVM.cs:

```
 public class RootVM : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, BaseVM> mViewModels = new Dictionary<string, BaseVM>();
    private BaseVM mCurrentContentVM;
    public BaseVM CurrentContentVM
    {
        get => mCurrentContentVM;
        set
        {
            mCurrentContentVM = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentVM");
        }
    }

    public RootVM()
    {
        mViewModels.Add("MainMenu", new MainMenuVM(this));
        mViewModels.Add("DataBaseEditor", new DataBaseEditorVM(this));
        SetVM("MainMenu");
    }

    public void SetVM(string vmName)
    {
        if (mViewModels.ContainsKey(vmName))
        {
            CurrentContentVM = mViewModels[vmName];
        }
    }
}
```

Я удалил StartupUri и создаю MainWindows с контекстом RootVM в App.cs. У меня есть ViewModel для MainMenu, в которой есть команда

```
public Command OpenDataBaseEditorView
    {
        get => mOpenDataBaseEditorView ??
                   (mOpenDataBaseEditorView = new Command((o) =>
                   {
                       mParentVM.SetVM("DataBaseEditor");
                   }));
        private set { }
    }
```

Соответственно я ожидаю, что мне достаточно повесить её на Button

```
<Button Click="{Binding OpenDataBaseEditorView}">Open</Button>
```

а MainMenu.xaml, а контекст будет учтён во время выполнения, ведь указал DataTemplate в MainWindow.xaml. Но возникает ошибка компиляции с указанием на эту строчку с кнопкой. Как правильно назначать DataContext UserControl'ам в MVVM?

Comment: Подключайте вьюмодель не в XAML, а в коде.

Comment: 1. `DataContext` в XAML - это по сути нарушение MVVM и далеко вы с этим не уедите (чуть подробней почитать можно [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553)). 2. `Frame` - это тоже не очень хороший подход для WPF приложения с MVVM. С ним довольно трудно разделять логику на V/VM (лучше поступить [таким](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553) способом).

Comment: Спасибо большое