# Как лучше сделать ViewModel менюшки c#?

Tags: c#, mvvm

Требуется годная идея для реализации логической части менюшки приложения. Разрабатываю приложение в целях самообучения, и проектирую по правилам шаблона MVVM. В приложении имеется главная менюшка, по нажатии кнопок которой в приложении просто меняются страницы. На данные момент я создал `enum ModelViewContext` и в зависимости от того, какой контекст установлен в `DataContext` главного окна применяю нужную страницу. Проблема в том, что такой подход заставляет программиста следить сразу за двумя зайцами: какие-там контексты сейчас возможны, какие страницы сейчас нужны. Есть ли более лаконичное решение?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит