# Binding, создание listBox для Log записей

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Пытался сделать ListBox для Log записей в программе.

Делал через интерфейс INotifyCollectionChanged

```
 class LogItem
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

Далее

```
class Logs : ObservableCollection<LogItem>, INotifyCollectionChanged
    {
        public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
        protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action)
        {
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action));
        }
        public void AddMessage(string message)
        {
            Add(new LogItem()
            {

                Message = message
            });
            OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);

        }
    }
```

Как вызывать метод AddMessage не создавая нового экземпляра класса Logs?

Comment: Тут два пути. 1. Это сделать что то по типу синглтона, который будет отдавать уже созданный экземпляр, привязанного где то класса. 2. Передавать данный класс через конструктор в другой класс, где необходимо использовать запись в лог. Второй вариант более предпочтителен, ибо статик - зло и стоит от него избавляться, а синглтон это все же статик.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ 3) Event Aggregator

Comment: @tym32167 Тоже вариант, да

Comment: @EvgeniyZ С передачей через конструктор у меня есть. У меня приложение строится через Pages. И в каждой надо записывать что-то в лог. Получается в лог может записывать только та страница, которая создала экземпляр класса Log. Допустим в MainPage создался первый экземпляр, а в SettingsPage я никак не могу понять как передать этот экземпляр. Если только через наследование, но боюсь это не верный подход

Comment: Ну вот и ваш косяк. Pages очень плохо подходят для привязок и MVVM подхода в целом. Хотите нормальное "страничное" приложение, используйте [подобный подход](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553), а там уже вам достаточно будет сделать `Content = new CustomViewModel(MyLogger)`.