# Передаю команде Frame в WPF, но не работает

Tags: c#, wpf

Проблема в чем: мне нужно передать команде параметр в виде Frame. Frame определён в коде XAML. Frame в коде XAML:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
     <Frame x:Name="MainFrame"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Сама команда:

```
public RelayCommand OpenNewPage
    {
        get
        {
            return _openNewPage ??
                (_openNewPage = new RelayCommand(obj =>
               {
                   Frame frame = obj as Frame;
                   frame.Content = new TESTPAGE();
               }));
        }
    }
```

Команда вызывается нажатием на кнопку:

```
<Button Content="TEST IT!" Command="{Binding OpenNewPage}" CommandParameter="MainFrame"/>
```

Проблема вот в этом: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Команды находятся во ViewModel, а вьюмодель ничего не должна знать о контролах визуального интерфейса. Передачей `Frame` вы нарушаете смысл MVVM.

Comment: Понял. Принял. Спасибо)

Comment: `Frame`'у вообще не место в нормальном WPF приложение, особенно в том, которое строится по принципу MVVM (ИМХО). Если вам нужен разный контент, то используйте [ContentPresenter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553), который идеально подходит под MVVM подход.