# Навигация с помощью UserControl в WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm, шаблоны-проектирования

Задача состоит в том, как же менять местами ViewModel-и. Допустим у меня приложение состоит из нескольких UserControl-ов со связанными с ними ViewModel-ями.
Что у нас дано:

1. FirstUserControl и FirstViewModel
2. SecondUserControl и SecondViewModel
3. BaseView (Само окно, где "живут" UserControl-ы)
4. RootViewModel тут какм-то образом нужно организовать замены ViewModel-ей

XAML код BaseView:

```
 <Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:FirstVM}">
        <Views:FirstPage/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:SecondVM}">
        <Views:SecondPage/>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<ContentControl Content="{Binding GetVM}"/>
```

И файл связанный с BaseView:

```
public partial class BaseView : Window
{
    public BaseView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new RootViewModel();
    }
}
```

Как в RootViewModel-е организовать замену CurrentViewModel?
P.s. Это читал [ContentControl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763691/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B5-wpf-mvvm/765122#765122). Идею понял, а с реализацией возникли проблемы

Comment: А в чем трудности то? У вас в `RootViewModel` есть свойство `GetVM`, задавайте ему нужную VM и все (`GetVM = new SecondVM();`). Как вы дальше будете менять - это уже зависит от приложения, ибо тут можно и по событию и по кнопке и по чему то еще, хоть по таймеру, лишь замените значение у свойства. Если у вас вопрос в том, как с другой VM изменить контент в `Root`, то просто при инициализации передавайте ссылку через конструктор (что то вроде этого: `... = new SecondVM(this);`), тогда у вас нужной VM будет доступ через ссылку к главной VM.

Comment: Понял. Принял. Все работает)