# Как, соблюдая MVVM, управлять Frame?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Я нашел вариант в интернете, где Frame управляется созданием страниц из VM главного окна:

View:

```
<Frame Content="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
WriteNote = new Pages.WriteNote();
CurrentPage = WriteNote;
```

Но, если я не ошибаюсь, такой способ противоречит паттерну MVVM, так как ViewModel знает о View. Как же тогда управлять Frame?

Comment: Не как. С `Frame` очень трудно работать по правилам MVVM.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Что тогда можно взять на замену?

Comment: Ну вариантов много, если используете какой то фреймворк, то там есть свои решения, если стандартный WPF, то что то на подобие [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553). Я кстати вам советую также почитать [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553), вот на 90% уверен, что вы задаете `DataContext` не там, где надо...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, буду иметь ввиду