# Назначил кнопке обработчик событий, но ничего не происходит. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Хочу сделать свою программу многостраничной. Для этого я назначил кнопке событие по переключению страниц. Вот xaml:

```
   <Button Command="{Binding StartClick}"/>
```

вот сам `StartClick`:

```
       public ICommand StartClick
       {
           get
           {
               return new RelayCommand(() => SwitchPage(PrepareSI));
           }
       }


       public async void SwitchPage(Page page)
       {
           await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
           {
               CurrentPage = page;
           });
       }
```

Когда нажимаю на кнопку ничего не происходит.
Возможно есть другой способ переключений между страницами? Этот я взял с [ролика](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZSFY8YdSrA).
Там, правда, кнопки находится не на странице, а я хочу переключатся внутри страницы на другую.

Попутный вопрос: в этом же ролике свойства задавались через Binding вот так:

```
<Frame Content="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
```

У меня же работает только так:

```
<Frame Content="{Binding Path=CurrentPage}"/>
```

С чем это связано?

Реализация CurrentPage:

```
        //Возможные страницы
        public Page Main;
        public Page PrepareSI;
        public Page SI;
        public Page Settings;


        public Page CurrentPage;
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Main = new Pages.Main();
            PrepareSI = new Pages.PrepareSI();
            SI = new  Pages.SI();
            Settings = new Pages.Settings();


            CurrentPage = Main;//ПО умолчанию начальная страница - Main
        }
```

Comment: Зачем вы каждый раз при `get` инициализируете команду?  Бедный сборщик мусора... Зачем тут `async`?  Также вы не показали самих свойств (`CurrentPage` например). Ну а вообще, я настоятельно рекомендую вам отказаться от `Frame`, ибо он совершенно не пригоден для привязок и имеет ряд своих заморочек.

Comment: Я абсолютный новичок в wpf, поэтому следовал ролику. Посоветуйте альтернативу Frame.

Comment: [Альтернатива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122). На другие вопросы вы ответа так и не дали.

Comment: ```CurrentPage``` - объект класса ```Page```. Указывает текущую страницу приложения.

Comment: Я знаю что это, я не вижу как вы реализовали этот "объект". Добавьте все необходимое в вопрос (кнопка править под ним).

Comment: Это то, что Вы хотели?

Comment: Я вам рекомендую не брать за основу этот канал и найти более опытного "учителя", не играющего, не школьника, ибо смотря на тот код, что в видео можно сразу заявлять о том, что автор сам не знает что пишет, что советует и как он это реализует, совершая уйму ошибок. Теперь что касается самой проблемы: Запомните 2 вещи: 1. Привязка осуществляется ТОЛЬКО к публичному СВОЙСТВУ (оно имеет get и set). 2. Для оповещение интерфейса об изменении данных, свойство должно вызывать метод реализованного `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Смотрим ваш код: `public Page CurrentPage;` - это поле, не свойство! Оно не подходит для привязки (это ответ на ваш "попутный вопрос"). При обновление этого поля не вызывается `OnPropertyChenged()` (это ответ на "ничего не происходит").

Comment: Согласен с оратором выше. В видео по ссылке какая то ерунда.