# Как менять CurrentContentVM у RootVM?

Tags: c#, wpf

Я создал модели контента как сказано в ответе чувака этого [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763691/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B5-wpf-mvvm)

Вопрос: Как можно поменять свойство CurrentContentVM?

Нужно либо передавать в модели контента контекст Window, либо ставить обработчики события (когда нужно сменить контент) у Window и уже в них менять RootVM.CurrentContentVM.

---

Заранее, спасибо!

Comment: Вы знаете что такое MVVM, что такое привязки и как с этим всем работать? У вас должна быть одна главная ViewModel, в которой вы делаете свойство для текущего контента и кнопку изменения (`ICommand`), все это привязываете к нужным элементам окна и все, вот ваше приложение готово.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, объясните, пожалуйста, вашу идею. Я так понял вы имеете в виду, что нужно менять не контент окна, а контент того же `<Grid />`,  в котором будет отображаться другой контент при вызове команды смены контента. Эту команду я должен привязать к кнопкам каждой "секции". Так?

Comment: Это не моя идея, это шаблон проектирования, по которому принято программировать в WPF. MVVM означает разделение всего на 3 слоя (Model - ваши данные (база например), View - ваш интерфейс (кнопочки все, всякие цвета и т.д.), ну и ViewModel - некий связующий слой, который берет данные из Model и реализует публичные свойства для View слоя).  Вот вы создаете некий класс, называете его к примеру `MainViewModel`, в нем реализуете `public object CurrentContent {get; set;}` и например команду (`public ICommand ChangeCommand {get}`).

Comment: Далее задаете [DataContect](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/562578/220553), указав там `MainViewModel`. Все, теперь вы можете привязывать что угодно к созданным свойствам. Например кнопку: `<Button Command = "{Binding ChangeCommand}">`. И заметьте, в этом подходе нет обращения к контролам (напрпимер `mainWindow.myLable.Text ="Привет мир!"`), ибо это будет являться нарушением MVVM. View слой не должен знать о Model/ViewModel слое (а значит свойства по типу `Click` у кнопки использовать нельзя). ViewModel не должен знать об элементах View слоя (а значит обращение к контролам через их имена нельзя