# Как изменить Frame страницы из другой страницы в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как можно реализовать переключение Frame на странице MainWindow по нажатию на кнопку на странице Greeting? Я пытался сделать так, но такой вариант не работает

```
private void btnShowLicence_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow.ContentFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Licence.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

Main Page

```
    <DockPanel Width="auto" Height="auto"  >
        <Frame Name="ContentFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Focusable="false" Width="auto" Height="auto" Navigated="ContentFrame_Navigated"/>
    </DockPanel>
```

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать нормальное "страничное" приложение, то не используйте `Frame`. Ну а так, подумайте сами "переключение Frame на странице MainWindow по нажатию на кнопку на странице Greeting" - наверно ваша страница `Greeting` должна иметь ссылку на `MainWindow` и уже через эту ссылку взаимодействовать с контрогами окна.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Подскажите как эту ссылку получить, я не могу понять как это сделать

Comment: В вашем варианте - не как, ибо у вас простые xaml страницы. Смотрите, в WPF принято работать с привязками, то есть у вас есть некое публичное свойство и к нему вы привязываете в XAML нужный объект (например `Text="{Binding MyProperty}"`). Используя контролы из кода, вы многого себя лишаете и многое будете писать (я уверен) в виде костылей. Имея все это, люди придумали MVVM подход, где все делится на строгие слои, где UI - один слой, а код - другой слой и они не связаны друг с другом. Как только вы это все поймете, я вам советую [такой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122) вариант реализации.

Comment: `Frame` - это уже довольно давно устаревший и ограниченный контрол, который не позволит вам многого. Его задача лишь в отображение страницы, не более. По этой причине я вам и говорю - откажитесь от него! По поводу ссылки, я имел ввиду нечто, на подобие `var page = new SecondPage(this);`, где `this` - это `MainWindow`, переданный через конструктор в класс.