# Связанные окна WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, gui

Возник вопрос касательно возможности сделать связанные окна(не знаю,как это еще назвать),подразумевается,что изначально существует одно окно ,к примеру Window1,на котором расположена триггер формата On-Off или же кнопка.Необходимо ,чтобы по нажатию на триггер справа появлялось второе окно с независимой информацией(Window2),пусть там раз в 10 секунд выводит время,при этом при перемещении основного окна,второе двигалось вместе с ним.А по повторному нажатию триггера окно пропадало.Пробовал отслеживать позицию окна и менять его положение через и т.п.

```
Window1 window1Form = new Window1();
window1Form.Top=...;
window1Form.Left=...;
```

Возможно ли это как-то реализовать и в каком направлении стоит копать?Заранее спасибо за советы)
[image: Примерный вид]

Comment: А почему это не сделать в рамках одного окна? Ведь не удобно, когда открывается не пойми где отдельное окно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Из серии сделай кучу gridов и навешать свойств видимости?

Comment: Ну это уже зависит от ваших навыков. Я бы разделил окно одной сеткой на две части, в левой поместил эти переключатели, а справа `ContentPresenter`, который [менял бы свой вид](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553) под мои нужды, или если там несколько отображений, то `ItemsControl`. Привязал бы это дело по правилам MVVM и все, в одном окне у меня разное содержимое при выборе переключателей.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Благодарю,неплохой вариант.А так было чисто интересна реальность воплощения такой извращенной идеи))

Comment: Вы странно отзываетесь о вполне здравом совете. Я понимаю, что вы можете быть не знакомы с MVVM и не до конца понимать, что вам предложили, но заведомо утверждать, что основной для WPF подход к реализации подобных задач - извращение, это похоже на плевок в лицо практически каждому более-менее опытному в данном вопросе программисту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если два "окна" должны двигаться вместе, то проще всего их сделать не отдельными окнами, а элементами управления на одном физическом окне.

- Создаем полностью прозрачное родительское окно со свойствами `WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent"`
- В нем создаем window1 и window2 допустим как Grid-ы
- Воссоздаем в родительском окне нужный функционал обычного окна (перетаскивание за заголовок, изменение размера рамкой, кнопки сворачивания-разворачивания-закрытия)

В результате это выглядит как два окна, которые перемещаются вместе. Пример (у меня реализовано только перетаскивание за заголовок и кнопка закрытия):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent"
        Height="450" Width="600" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

    <Grid x:Name="grid">

        <Grid x:Name="window1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  
                  Background="AliceBlue">
            <Button x:Name="bClose" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" 
                    Margin="0,0,0,0" Click="Button_Click" />
            <Label x:Name="labelTitle" Content="Window 1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="36" Margin="0,0,36,0" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                <Label.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionColorKey}}"/>
                </Label.Background>
            </Label>
            <RadioButton Content="On" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="25,60,0,0" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="On_Click"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Off" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="70,60,0,0" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="True" Click="Off_Click"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="window2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="251,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" 
                  Background="AliceBlue" >
                <Label Content="Window 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>    
</Window>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);
                
        const uint HTCAPTION = 2;        
        const uint HTNOWHERE = 0;        

        const uint WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;

        const uint WS_OVERLAPPED = 0x00000000;
        const uint WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000;
        const uint WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000;
        const uint WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000;
        const uint WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000;
        const uint WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000;
        const uint WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU |
              WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;

        static int GET_X_LPARAM(IntPtr lp)
        {
            short loword = (short)((ulong)lp & 0xffff);
            return loword;
        }

        static int GET_Y_LPARAM(IntPtr lp)
        {
            short hiword = (short)((((ulong)lp) >> 16) & 0xffff);
            return hiword;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left, top, right, bottom;
        }

        //обработка координат мыши для неклиентской области
        IntPtr HitTestNCA(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            Point ptMouse = new Point(GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam));                        
            RECT rcWindow;
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, out rcWindow);
            
            if (ptMouse.Y >= rcWindow.top && ptMouse.Y < rcWindow.top + labelTitle.ActualHeight &&
                ptMouse.X>= rcWindow.left && ptMouse.X < rcWindow.left + labelTitle.ActualWidth)
            {
                return (IntPtr)HTCAPTION;
            }
            else
            {
                return (IntPtr)HTNOWHERE;
            }
        }

        //обработчик сообщений для окна
        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            IntPtr lRet = IntPtr.Zero;

            if (msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
            {
                //обработка нажатий мыши
                lRet = HitTestNCA(hwnd, wParam, lParam);

                if (lRet != (IntPtr)HTNOWHERE)
                {
                    handled = true;
                }
            }

            return lRet;
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WindowInteropHelper h = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
            HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(h.Handle);
            source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));//регистрируем обработчик сообщений
            window2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        private void Off_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            window2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        private void On_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            window2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]