# Динамическое добавление элементов. Не добавляются элементы на странице

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В общем, пытаюсь реализовать, что при переходе на страницу услуг, они должны выводится в StackPanel, каждой услуге свой StackPanel с определённой разметкой. Суть такая что при запуске программы и переходе на страницу, страница просто пустая, хотя метод запускается и всё проходит.

Вот метод, который призывается после инициализации.

```
private void GenerateList()
        {
            foreach (Service service in AvtoService.Service.ToList())
            {
                //Создание StackPanel которая будет являтся оболочкой для карточки услуги
                StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel()
                {
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                    Margin = new Thickness(10)
                };

                //Добавление созданного StackPanel на Grid
                MainServicesGrid.Children.Add(stackPanel);

                //Создание внутреннего Grid'а
                Grid gridIn = new Grid();

                //Объявление строк и столбцов для Grid'а
                ColumnDefinition gridCol1 = new ColumnDefinition()
                {
                    Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star),
                };
                ColumnDefinition gridCol2 = new ColumnDefinition()
                {
                    Width = new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Star),
                };
                ColumnDefinition gridCol3 = new ColumnDefinition()
                {
                    Width = new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Star),
                };

                RowDefinition gridRow1 = new RowDefinition();
                RowDefinition gridRow2 = new RowDefinition();
                RowDefinition gridRow3 = new RowDefinition();
                RowDefinition gridRow4 = new RowDefinition();

                //Добавление объявленных строк и столбцов во внутренний Grid
                gridIn.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol1);
                gridIn.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol2);
                gridIn.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol3);

                gridIn.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow1);
                gridIn.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow2);
                gridIn.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow3);
                gridIn.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow4);

                //Добавление внутреннего Grid'а в StackPanel
                stackPanel.Children.Add(gridIn);

                //Инициализация изображения для ImageSource
                BitmapImage BtmpImg = new BitmapImage();
                BtmpImg.UriSource = new Uri(service.MainImagePath,UriKind.Relative);

                //Создание элемента Image
                Image image = new Image()
                {
                    Source = BtmpImg,
                    Margin = new Thickness(5),
                };

                //Привязка изображения к Grid
                image.SetValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty, 4);
                image.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);

                stackPanel.Children.Add(image);
            }
```

MainServicesGrid это x:Name грида на форме в XAML.

Тут метод вызывается

```
public partial class ServicesPage : Page
    {
        AvtoServiceEntities AvtoService;

        public ServicesPage(bool IsUserAdmin)
        {
            AvtoService = new AvtoServiceEntities();

            InitializeComponent();

            GenerateList();       
        }
```

Нужно снова натыкать носом в ошибки, и подсказать почему не выводятся элементы. Пробовал по-всякому и на события инициализации и loaded назначать и ставить генерацию вне метода. Страницы вызываются во Frame который находится на главном окне.

Comment: Почему вдруг динамика = C# код? Вы знаете что такое привязки? Если да, то почему не используете? Если нет, то идите учите, ибо бессмысленно использовать WPF без них! Также `Frame`, забудьте про него! Если хотите делать изменяемый контент, то это делается совершенно иначе (и опять привет привязки).

Comment: Ну и в добавок [Отображение разного содержимого в одном окне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А что такого, люди приходят из форм и пытаются делать то, что они делали раньше. Не по собственной тупости, а потому что вы еще не успели подсказать, что дальше делать. Я тоже по-началу финформил, а xaml казался чем-то сложным и неповоротливым, несмотря на то что я изо всех сил в него пытался вникнуть. И у меня даже получалось писать что-то вменяемое, хоть и не большое. А потом узнал про MVVM и за неделю все переписал. Ни кто не пострадал. А вы ругаетесь, не надо ругаться, если с ходу непонятно, что у человека в голове. Вот когда с первого раза не понял, тогда уже другой разговор.

Comment: @aepot Не поверите, а я сразу зашел в WPF и понял, что за интерфейс отвечает XAML, а за код C#, да, я обращался к контролам и не особо использовал привязки (`textBox.Text="1"`), да и конструктор использовал, что у меня все было с `Margin = "900, 141, 515, 111"`, но я четко разграничивал UI и C#, это прям очивидные вещи. Я даже больше скажу, я тогда особо то и не знал что такое язык программирования. Да, может я такой "умный", но ведь если ввести в поисковике `wpf`, то увидим `Одной из важных особенностей является использование языка декларативной разметки интерфейса XAML`.

Comment: @aepot А если еще чуть углубиться, то увидим и привязки и все остальное, прям первыми запросами. Я уверен, что если сейчас напишу `Как динамически добавлять элементы`, то я также увижу уйму примеров, которые говорят "привязки". Ок, не хотим искать... Но ведь создание UI через C# это сложно! Не уж то это не может насторожить? Я лично до сих пор вряд-ли смогу сделать через C# нормальный UI, красивый. Так что я с вами не очень прям уж в этом плане согласен, ибо тут скорей очередное создание лабораторной работы, где студенты делают на тяп ляп все, без желания разбираться.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вы говорите совершенно правильные вещи, но при этом показываете всем, что это вас раздражает. Это я вижу, что вы практически каждый день разным людям рассказываете одно и то же, иногда слово в слово. Вижу, что люди идут сюда писать прежде чем гуглить и читать. Это на мой взгляд тоже плохо. Я про другое - про то, что эмоции должны быть в стороне, я во всяком случае всегда стараюсь писать максимально нейтрально, хоть и не всегда получается. Уж простите. :)

Comment: @aepot "ругаться" - почему вы всегда думаете, что я ругаюсь? Знак `!` (восклицания) не только ведь показывает, что это ругань, крик или еще что, а иногда и акцентирует внимание, что "так плохо!", "не делайте так!". Это не эмоции или что-либо еще, а лишь рассуждение и акцентирование внимания, ибо порой без этого знака контент не воспринимается, увы. Уж извините, если вам показалось это криком, руганью или еще чем. А по поводу людей, увы, но за 4 года, что я здесь, только единицы перешли на привязки, другим было лень, сложно, нет времени и так далее, хотя давал подробнейшие разборы их задач.

Comment: Автор, я никогда никому не советовал, но можно пробежаться по [моим ответам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A373567+isaccepted%3Ayes+%5Bwpf%5D) про WPF и по [ответам @EvgeniyZ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A220553+isaccepted%3Ayes+%5Bwpf%5D). Ссылки я сделал с фильтром WPF. Там много всяких разных, даже самых детальных примеров, которые не всегда можно найти через поиск. Даю гарантию, что поразбиравшись, вы решите свой вопрос, а так же научитесь делать новые крутые штуки. Ну и узнаете, что такое MVVM. Я бы может и на ваш вопрос написал ответ, но слишком мало данных.

Comment: Большое спасибо aepot и EvgeniyZ за ответы, наводки и критику. Буду разбираться.