# Сгладить углы формы

Tags: c#, wpf

Проблема в том что не получается правильно сгладить форму.
Вообщем, не получается что-то у меня... Или получается, но криво, отругайте, и поправьте меня, пожалуйста.

- Первая картинка, это когда приложение уже загрузилось, хотя бы края сглаживает, но, всё остальное недоступно...
- Вторая картинка, режим загрузки.
- Третья картинка, конечный результат, только в данный момент углы не косые, а прямые.
  **Решение:**

  ```
  <Border CornerRadius="10">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#131518"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ResIsLoaded, ElementName=home}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/wallGta5.jpg"
                                Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
  ```

[image: Картинка когда загрузилось приложение][image: Грузим приложение]

[image: Конечный результат]

Comment: Что значит "не получается" и что значит "криво"? Вот сколько раз я вам говорил, как можно больше информации в вопрос прикладывайте, скрины ваших попыток и так далее. Поставьте себя на наше место, вот вы видите код и описание "подскажите, что не так, криво отображает!", ну и как нам подобное понять?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Согласен, обновил своё обращение.

Comment: И что на скринах вас не устраивает?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Конечный результат запуска приложения. Третью картинку завтычил добавить...

Comment: Так, а зачем вам триггер? Не, я понимаю его цель, типа если `ResIsLoaded == true`, то мы делаем то-то, но смысл этого всего? Экран загрузки (splash screen), обычно делается либо отдельным окном, который выводит нужную информацию, либо это контент, который размещается поверх основного. Конечно, есть реализации, где заменяется основной контент, но тогда это лучше делать другими способами, например [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553). И тут мы с вами понимаем, что ваши видеоуроки заводят вас не совсем в ту степь, ибо у вас должны быть четко выраженные слои проекта, а не каша...

Comment: Далее, отсутствие контента: А почему он должен быть? Вы же при `ResIsLoaded == true` переписываете вид, который не имеет сам контент (`ContentPresenter`), ну вот и с чего ему там быть? Теперь про закругленные углы: А где вы переписываете вид окна, если `ResIsLoaded == false`? Вот у вас стиль, в котором вы меняете `Background`, потом идет триггер, привязанный на `ResIsLoaded`, в котором вы закругляете углы, ну а дальше? А и да, мне очень не нравиться, что вы вечно пишете с нового аккаунта! Один раз послали SO, получили бан, теперь скрываетесь или что? Мне лично подобное мерзко видеть...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Придумал самостоятельное решение.