# Как перейти из страницы UserControl на другую страницу?

Tags: c#, wpf

Недавно начал изучать WPF и столкнулся с такой вроде бы легкой проблемой.

**Необходимо по нажатию кнопки на странице (UserControl) переходить на другую страницу.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете несколько stackpanel и при нажатии на кнопку менять их расположение margin.
Например, появлениие yourpanel.Margin = new Thickness (0, 0, 0, 0);
Исчезание yourpanel.Margin = new Thickness (5000, 0, 0, 0);