# Как исправить ошибку System.InvalidOperationException: "Недопустимый для переходов корневой элемент "PlantsProject.PlantsPage"."?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Изображение с ошибкой
[image: Изображение с ошибкой]

Вызов нужного окна в C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainFrame.Content = new PlantsPage();
    }
}
```

Код в WPF

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Source="/Resources/logo.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Image>
    <TextBlock Text="Header" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    <Grid Background="White" ZIndex="-2"></Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="#76e383"></Grid>
    <Button Name="PlantsPage" Grid.Row="1" Content="Go" Background="White" 
            Height="60" Width="200" FontSize="30" 
            Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    <Frame Name="MainFrame" Grid.Row="1"></Frame>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Научитесь использовать основные элементы WPF, а именно XAML и привязки. Так вы поймете, что использование контролов в коде C# плохо. Потом вы поймете, что `Frame` не очень хорошее решение для отображения контента. И да, не давайте код в виде скринов, это очень плохая практика, ведь нам придется в случае чего переписывать все руками, а также поиск по вашему вопросу не будет работать, из-за чего другие люди не найдут ваш вопрос если столкнутся с аналогичной проблемой. Если разбирать саму ошибку, то какой тип у `PlantsPage`?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: EvgeniyZ, а где посмотреть, какой тип у PlantsPage?
И что можно использовать вместе Frame для отображения контента?

Comment: Не забывайте ставить `@` перед ником, ибо я так не вижу уведомлений. "Какой тип" - смотрите в коде, например вон у вас окно `public partial class MainWindow : Window` наследуется от `Window`, это и есть тип. Либо можете в XAML посмотреть, там в самом начале пишет `<Window ...`. В WPF бывают окна (`Window`), страницы (`Page`) и Пользовательские контролы (`UserControl`). `Frame` принимает именно страницы (`Page`), а судя по ошибки, у вас там явно не страница.

Comment: "Замена Frame" - у вас должно быть [нечто такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553), это самый основной и минимальный вариант отображения контента, который отлично подходит под привязки. Вот можете посмотреть [полноценный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/220553) приложения со страницами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что я делал обращение к окну, а не к странице.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]