# как привязать title у страницы к label из окна

Tags: c#, wpf

Необходимо привязать `label` из `MainWindow` и `title` из страницы. В `Content` у `label` написал `binding`. Указал, что `ElementName = MainFrame`, но я понимаю, что у MainFrame нет свойства `Title`, это свойство у страницы, но как мне сказать компилятору, что вот тебе страница и бери тайтл

MainWindow:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#6995C2"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="#6995C2"/>
        <Image x:Name="logo" Source="C:\Users\Radiance\Desktop\NBASHKA\Resources\logo.png" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5" Height="90" Width="90"/>
        <Label x:Name="header" Content="{Binding Title, ElementName=MainFrame}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="Rubik" FontSize="30" Foreground="Black"/>
        <TextBlock Text="FOOTER" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" FontFamily="Rubik" FontSize="15"/>
        <Button x:Name="back" Content="BACK" Width="130" Height="30" Background="White" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5" IsCancel="True" Click="back_Click">
            <Button.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                </Style>
            </Button.Resources>
        </Button>
        <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Страница MainScreen

```
Title="MainScreen">

<Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="visitor" Content="Visitor" Width="130" Height="30" Background="#6995C2" Click="visitor_Click">
                <Button.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Resources>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="admin" Content="Admin" Width="130" Height="30" Background="#6995C2" Margin="20,0,0,0" Click="admin_Click">
                <Button.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Resources>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: а что вы пробовали? Меня тоже интересует этот вопрос

Comment: `Frame` не очень подходящий элемент для привязок, там как бы можно, но не стоит. У вас должно быть что-то по типу [такого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553), где вы делаете классы, которые будут содержать в себе информацию о странице, ее заголовок, может описание, ну и др. Дальше создаете под каждую страницу свой вид в виде простого `UserControl`. Остается в XAML указать какой вид будет использован и под какую страницу, делается это через `DataTemplate`. Все, делаете свойство, привязываете к нему, готово. Отвыкайте от всех `x:Name="..."`, мой вам совет.

Comment: Ну а если нужно всеж через фрейм, то подумайте логически, вы титул чего хотите взять, контента, или самого фрейма? Наверно контента, так может `Content.Title`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, я понимаю, что я не так делаю, но мне именно это надо решить, на счет `title`, то мне нужен тайтл страницы(фрейма)

Comment: @DaLadno пока что я ничего не пробовал, но если найду ответ, то отвечу

Comment: @DaLadno наше ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<label Content="{Binding ElementName=MainFrame, Path=Content.Title}"/>
```

в окне MainWindow, где находится `label`, прописать данный бинд. Нужно учесть, что `Frame` находится там же где и `label`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]