# C# WPF Создание динамической таблицы обращение к ней и отрисовка заголовка в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

Коллеги, приветствую!

Стоит задача выводить в WPF DataGrid примерно сл. информацию (`xlm` см. ниже)

```
<table col="6" name="" row="3">
    <colnames>
        <uid>ID пользователя</uid>
        <name>Имя</name>
        <date_reg>Дата регистрации</date_reg>
        <mobilenumber>Моб.телефон</mobilenumber>
        <email_reg>Email регистрации</email_reg>
        <ip_reg>IP регистрации</ip_reg>
    </colnames>
    <colvalues>
        <uid>0000001</uid>
        <name>Григорьев Сергей Петрович</name>
        <date_reg>2017-04-11</date_reg>
        <mobilenumber>+79855555999</mobilenumber>
        <email_reg />
        <ip_reg>192.168.1.188</ip_reg>
    </colvalues>
    <colvalues>
        <uid>0000002</uid>
        <name>Сергеев Сергей Сергеевич</name>
        <date_reg>2017-04-11</date_reg>
        <mobilenumber>+79853335444</mobilenumber>
        <email_reg />
        <ip_reg>192.168.1.188</ip_reg>
    </colvalues>
    <colvalues>
        <uid>0000003</uid>
        <name>Иванов Иван Иванович</name>
        <date_reg>2017-04-11</date_reg>
        <mobilenumber>+79107774888</mobilenumber>
        <email_reg />
        <ip_reg>192.168.1.188</ip_reg>
    </colvalues>
</Table>
```

Отличаются таблицы количеством колонок. Таблицы выводить получилось, но не удается отрисовать заголовок (элемент `colnames` из `xml`). Проект был изначально на Delphi, так это всё делалось связкой DataSet через `DataSource` к DBGrid. Обращался к необходимому полю примерно `FDataSet.FieldByName('name').AsString` и получал всё, что необходимо. А тут даже и не знаю как решить свой вопрос. **Прошу, выручите рабочим примером динамического создания таблицы и обращения к ней.**

*(P.S. уже неделю копаю в этом направлении, пересмотрел множество кусков кода с динамическим созданием коллекций `ObservableCollection` и `Binding`, но опытные хаЦкеры то ли чего-то не договаривают в своих статьях, то ли я ещё очень молод в WPF, к сожалению не смог въехать)*

Comment: Если это xml попробуйте использовать XmlDataProvider - http://dotnet-experience.blogspot.ru/2011/11/wpf-working-with-xml-and.html

Comment: @Ev_Hyper: Думаю, `XmlDataProvider` не ожидает имена столбцов в отдельном теге.

Comment: Набросал 2 примитивных примера того что хочу получить (с компонентом ListView получилось задуманное, но хочу использовать DataGrid, а вот в проекте с датагридом не удается сбиндить колонки) Может так мне кто-нибудь сможет помочь. https://yadi.sk/d/lHCVf7L83HUqro

Comment: @АндрейКулаков: Вы бы выложили лучше код сюда, потому что заглядывать в файлообменники и искать там нужную часть всем как бы лень.

Comment: @VladD да нет, это как раз настроить должно быть можно, а вот то, что столбцов может быть разное количесвто, это да, недосмотрел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня работает вот такой код:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="DG" AutoGenerateColumns="False" />
```

Code-behind:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(тут путь или откуда у вас там должен взяться XML);
var columnNames =
    xdoc.Descendants("colnames")
        .Single()
        .Elements()
        .Select(cn =>
            new
            {
                Name = cn.Name.LocalName,
                DisplayName = ((XText)(cn.Nodes().Single())).Value
            })
        .ToList();
foreach (var cn in columnNames)
    DG.Columns.Add(
        new DataGridTextColumn()
        {
            Binding = new Binding()
            {
                Path = new PropertyPath("Element[(0)].FirstNode.Value", cn.Name)
            },
            Header = cn.DisplayName
        });
DG.ItemsSource = xdoc.Descendants("colvalues").ToList();
```

Результат:

[image: таблица как бы]

Обратите внимание, что у нас `ItemsSource` отделён от XML, и значит, нужно будет его оттуда вытаскивать вручную, если нужно сохранить изменения.

---

Код, который приведён сверху, разумеется, прототип. Чтобы правильно с ним работать, давайте-ка улучшим его в сторону поддержки MVVM: выгрузим операции с данными из представления. (Имейте в виду, сейчас код работает с данными в VM, но нужно по идее вытеснить его в модель.)

Итак, наша VM. Базовый класс для VM с реализацией `INotifyPropertyChanged` берём, например, [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573196/10105).

Что нам нужно в нашем VM-классе? Нам нужны описатели столбцов (имя для отображения и имя для привязки), для них используем список пар (в C# 7 как раз появилась поддержка кортежей, ура!). Нам нужен список строк, который за неимением лучшего положим в виде последовательности `XElement`'ов. И нам нужен текущий выделенный элемент, его типом, понятно, является `XElement`.

Поехали!

```
class MainVM : VM
{
    public IEnumerable<(string Name, string DisplayName)> ColumnDescriptors { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<XElement> Values { get; }

    XElement selectedItem;
    public XElement SelectedItem
    {
        get { return selectedItem; } // при изменениях вызовется OnSelectedItemChanged
        set { if (Set(ref selectedItem, value)) OnSelectedItemChanged(); }
    }

    public MainVM()
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(тут путь или что там надо);
        ColumnDescriptors =
            xdoc.Descendants("colnames") // выбрали colnames
                .Single()                // он должен быть один
                .Elements()              // дочерние элементы
                .Select(cn => (Name: cn.Name.LocalName, // извлекаем нужные данные
                               DisplayName: ((XText)(cn.Nodes().Single())).Value))
                .ToList()                // материализуем
                .AsReadOnly();           // и защищаем от изменения
        // этот список может по идее менять, так что ObservableCollection
        Values = new ObservableCollection<XElement>(xdoc.Descendants("colvalues"));
    }

    void OnSelectedItemChanged()
    {
        // это вызовется, когда текущий элемент поменялся
        var item = SelectedItem;
        var uid = ((XText)item.Element("uid").FirstNode).Value;
        // например, 0000001
    }
}
```

Теперь XAML. Он довольно простой, большая часть работы у нас в VM.

```
<DataGrid Name="DG" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
```

Что мы забыли? Да, мы ведь забыли создать колонки. Это, кажется, невозможно сделать через `Binding`, поэтому создадим колонки вручную. Не забудем подписаться на изменение `DataContext`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
}

void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = (MainVM)DataContext;
    DG.Columns.Clear();
    if (vm == null)
        return;
    foreach (var cn in vm.ColumnDescriptors)
        DG.Columns.Add(
            new DataGridTextColumn()
            {
                Binding = new Binding()
                {
                    Path = new PropertyPath("Element[(0)].FirstNode.Value", cn.Name)
                },
                Header = cn.DisplayName
            });
}
```

Вот и всё. Не забудьте где-нибудь установить `DataContext` вашему окну. Например, [в `OnStartup`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/10105).

Answer (score 0):

@VladID Конечно, конечно: рабочий код с компонентом ListView

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
        string source = File.ReadAllText("Source.txt", Encoding.Default);
        StringReader string_reader = new StringReader(source);
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializebleResponse), "response");
        SerializebleResponse response = (SerializebleResponse)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(string_reader);
        XElement[] tables = response.Tables;
        XElement xml = tables[0];
        MyViewModel mvm = new MyViewModel();

        int i = 0;
        foreach (XElement el in xml.Element("colnames").Elements())
        {
            string binding = ".[" + i + "]";
            mvm.ArrayGridViewColumns.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn()
            {
                Header = el.Value, DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(binding)
            });
            i++;
        }

        foreach (XElement xRow in xml.Elements("colvalues"))
        {
            List<string> lst = new List<string>();
            foreach (XElement el in xRow.Elements())
            {                    
                lst.Add(el.Value);
            }
            mvm.ArrayCollection.Add(lst);
        }

        lvNew.ItemsSource = mvm.ArrayCollection;
        lvNew.View = mvm.ArrayGridViewColumns; 
    }

    private void lvNew_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView vrow = (DataRowView)lvNew.SelectedItem;
        DataRow row = vrow.Row;

        MessageBox.Show(row["123"].ToString());
    }
}


public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<List<string>> ArrayCollection { get; set; }
    public GridView ArrayGridViewColumns { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        ArrayCollection = new List<List<string>>();
        ArrayGridViewColumns = new GridView();
    }
}
```

и НЕ рабочий код с компонентом DataGrid (вот что-то не то с биндингом делаю)

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string source = File.ReadAllText("Source.txt", Encoding.Default);
        StringReader string_reader = new StringReader(source);
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializebleResponse), "response");
        SerializebleResponse response = (SerializebleResponse)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(string_reader);
        XElement[] tables = response.Tables;
        XElement xml = tables[0];
        MyViewModel mvm = new MyViewModel();

        int i = 0;
        foreach (XElement el in xml.Element("colnames").Elements())
        {
            string binding = ".[" + i + "]";

            DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn()
            {
                Header = el.Value,
                Binding = new Binding(binding)
            };

            dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
            i++;
        }

        dataGrid.ItemsSource = mvm.ArrayCollection;
    }

    private void dataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        /*
        State path = dataGrid.SelectedItem as State;
        MessageBox.Show($" Название: {path.Name}\n Столица: {path.Capital}\n Город: {path.Cities}\n Часовой пояс: {path.TimeZone}");
        */
    }
}


public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<List<string>> ArrayCollection { get; set; }
    public GridView ArrayGridViewColumns { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        ArrayCollection = new List<List<string>>();
        ArrayGridViewColumns = new GridView();
    }
}
```

Comment: А чем код не рабочий?

Comment: Прикрутить динамические коллекции не удается к колонкам.

Comment: @VladD, Сори, не сразу увидел код выше. Сейчас встроил в проект, и всё завелось, спасибо огромное, вроде ТО ЧТО НАДО!!! (прошу подсказать как через linq получить значение той или иной колонки выделенной строки)

Comment: Обновил ответ, смотрите.