# Как сделать динамическую привязку данных к элементам разметки в коде?

Tags: c#, xaml

Есть коллекция объектов, которые представляют собой данные. Есть класс, который представляет собой совокупность элементов разметки xaml. В зависимости от количества объектов в коллекции данных, создается соответствующего размера массив объектов разметки. Нужно сделать между ними двунаправленную связь.
Например.
Данные:

```
public class SampleData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
```

Разметка:

```
class CountBlock : StackPanel
    {
        TextBlock tbName;
        TextBlock tbCount;
        Button btn;
    }
```

Comment: Пользуете `MVVM`?

Comment: Эээ... Вы дали весь код класса `CountBlock`? Так работать не будет. А почему вы хотите связать элементы в code-behind? Я надеюсь, не потому, что не знаете как по-другому?

Comment: Нет, это не весь код, там еще конструктор. Просто не хотел загромождать лишними деталями, мне нужно понять основную суть, как можно связать поля данных с TextBlock-ами. Связать хочу в code-behind, потому что заранее количество элементов неизвестно, оно будет определяться динамически в ходе выполнения. Если это можно как-то сделать прямо в xaml, то я действительно не знаю как.

Comment: @denny7794: А что в конструкторе? Приведите весь класс `CountBlock`, без него непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, вам нужно не изобретать велосипед, а воспользоваться существующими средствами.

Для привязки к динамической коллекции (это у вас `ObservableCollection<SampleData>`, правильно?) лучше всего использовать `ItemsControl`. А для установки того, как выглядит каждый элемент, используется `ItemTemplate`. Получается что-то такое:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Тут-ваша-коллекция}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Count}"/>
                <Button Command="{Binding Тут-команда-вызываемая-по-нажатию}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Заодно и отпадает необходимость в классе `CountBlock`.

Comment: CountBlock мне нужен, т.к. разметка генерится динамически в зависимости от количества элементов данных, и эти блоки раскидываются еще по разным Column и Row на странице, количество которых тоже вычисляется динамически, чтобы все выглядело пропорционально.

Comment: @denny7794: Если нужно расположение по строкам/колонкам, то установите в качестве `ItemsPanel` например `UniformGrid`, как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573196/10105).