# Как сделать привязку к классу

Tags: c#, wpf

Помогите сделать привязку данных к свойствам класса. 2 день не могу разобраться. Вроде теорию понимаю а код получается с кучей ошибок. Для теста создал новый проект wpf в нем папки - `pages` и - `mv` для страниц wpf и вью моделей. Нужно загнать в `Label Content="{}"` `текст  = Text` из класса `MainVM` Вот разметка `xaml` страницы `page1` :

```
<Page x:Class="wpf_test.Pages.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" 
  Title="Page1" Background="Aqua">
<Grid>
    <Label />
</Grid>
```

и сам класс `MainVM`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace wpf_test.mv
{
public class MainVM 
{
   public string Text { get; set; }
   MainVM() { Text = "String test"; }
 }
}
```

Теперь как я понимаю нужно сделать привязку данных что то вроде

```
 <Page.DataContext>
    <....>
  </Page.DataContext>
```

Что писать вместо точек и как закончить привязку? Правильно ли вообще я действую 
  и правильно ли использую паттерн MVVM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну почти.

Для начала, вам нужно

```
<Label Content="{Binding Text}"/>
```

чтобы привязка проходила к полю `Test`.

Затем, вам нужно, чтобы в `DataContext` вашей страницы попал экземпляр `MainVM`.

Это можно сделать разными путями. Например, так, как вы написали, в XAML:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MainVM/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

Чтобы железяка понимала, что означает `vm`, вам нужно определить `xmlns:vm` как-то так:

```
<Page x:Class="wpf_test.Pages.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:wpf_test.mv"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
```

Другой способ — установить в code-behind:

```
public Page()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new mv.MainVM();
}
```

Способ, которым я обычно пользуюсь — не присваивать `DataContext` самостоятельно, а присвоить его в том коде, который показывает страницу (но это может быть невозможно для навигационных команд, я не проверял).

---

Ну, раз вы собираетесь пользоваться MVVM, то вы, вероятно, захотите обновлять данные в VM так, чтобы обновлённые данные автоматически отображались в UI. Для этого вашему VM-классу нужно будет имплементировать `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Спасибо! С `INotifyPropertyChanged` я пока не разбирался, но обязательно займусь. Скажите, wpf и mvvm --- насколько современен этот подход? Я имею в виду - нет ли более новой технологии, которая опережает `MVVM` так же как `MVVM` опережает `code-bechind` ? Насколько знаю в `Xamarin` &  `Silverlight` тоже применяется этот паттерн, но могу ошибаться.

Comment: @Сергей: MVVM не исключает code-behind. Смысл MVVM в разделении контента и представления, а то, устанавливаются ли привязки в XAML'е или в code-behind, не так уж важно. Главное, чтобы логики программы не было в OnClick и тому подобных штуках (ну и вообще в UI-классах). А то у некоторых разработчиков есть привычка в OnClick лазить в базу данных, читать статус из сети и показывать messagebox в одном методе. Вот это то, с чем борется MVVM.

Comment: блин, а у меня как раз на одной кнопке висит `Onclick` ( Его тоже нужно во вьюмодель перенести?

Comment: @Сергей: Это смотря что он делает. Если он выполняет UI-логику, то нет, его место в UI. А если он запускает программную логику, то тогда ему надо превратиться в команду и переехать в VM. Посмотрите пример вот здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573196/10105

Comment: Кнопка меняет пароль в БД для текущей учетной записи. Видимо перевести во вью надо.Спасибо посмотрю!

Comment: @Сергей: Да, операции с базой — это чисто модельная работа. Переносите!

Comment: Хорошо. Как только разберусь как это сделать.