# Как отследить событие со всех CheckBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

Имеется вот такая панель кнопок, в `ScrollViewer1` вложен `StackPanel` с сотней кнопок, на каждой кнопке `SteckPanel` с `Image`, `CheckBox` и `TextBlock`, `CheckBox` управляет видимостью своей кнопки, сейчас сделано так: в каждом `CheckBox_Unchecked` 
делаю невидимым соответствующую кнопку

```
but1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

и так сто раз ,  а как сделать по компактней?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто используйте привязки и шаблоны, ваша задача превратится в простейшую манипуляцию с коллекцией, которая займет пару строк Linq

Comment: Подскажите как ?

Comment: Рекомендую досконально изучить этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/616413/218063 Многое станет на свои места

Comment: Спасибо, начал изучать.

Comment: Вот еще, попроще должно быть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573196/218063

Comment: еще раз большое спасибо