# C# WPF как сделать биндинг видимость кнопки от состояния чекБокса в коде?

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать привязку не декларативно а в коде, 
нашел только вот такое про текстБокс

```
    CollapsedWrap disabledLine numbers off
    static void BindText(TextBox textBox, string property)
    {
    DependencyProperty textProp = TextBox.TextProperty;
    if (!BindingOperations.IsDataBound(textBox, textProp))
    {
  Binding b = new Binding(property);
  BindingOperations.SetBinding(textBox, textProp, b);
}
}
```

по аналогии пытаюсь переделать под себя

```
    CollapsedWrap disabledLine numbers off
    DependencyProperty visStPan = stpans[i].Visibility  ; 
    if (!BindingOperations.IsDataBound(stpans[i], visStPan))
    {
     Binding b = new Binding("{ Binding IsChecked, Converter = { 
     StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter }, ElementName = 
     chBox001 }");
     BindingOperations.SetBinding(stpans[i], visStPan, b);
     }
```

но показывает ошибку типов

```
........
ОшибкаCS0029Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Windows.Visibility" в "System.Windows.DependencyProperty".
```

показывает на первую строку

подскажите как динамически при создании кнопки в коде создавать и привязки

когда мы декларативно объявляем биндинг в XAML , то делаем так

```
<Window.Resources>
 <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Button  x:Name="but001" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, Converter=
 {StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}, ElementName=chBox1}" / 
 >

<CheckBox x:Name="chBox1"    IsChecked="True"   />
```

т.е. используется конвертор

а как теперь через код объявить и применить конверотор в

```
  DependencyProperty видКн = кнопки[i].Visibility  ;
```

Comment: А какой смысл вы в этом видите?

Comment: кнопки и чекБоксы создаються  динамически, как их связать чтобы видимость каждой кнопки зависила от своего чекБокса

Comment: @vova-forum из ошибки разве не видно? Нужно указывать свойство зависимости, а не свойство. Пишите "DependencyProperty visStPan = UIElement.VisibilityProperty".

Comment: Вам же в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/846045/220553) вопросе дали наводку на то, как надо правильно делать, вы пробовали? Суть банально проста, из кода вы **не должны** знать о контролах во view, каждый объект должен соответствовать своей ViewModel (в которой вы делаете все необходимые свойства для привязки). Вот вам почти [идентичная задача](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/833104/220553) (динамически создаваемые объекты, привязка и все по правилам), только еще конвертор прицепить.

Comment: John -  что там ?

Comment: попробывал по вашему совету  "DependencyProperty visStPan = UIElement.VisibilityProperty"        ошибка     не удается преобразовать из "System.Windows.Visibility" в "System.Windows.DependencyProperty".

Comment: EvgeniyZ  -   Вы  про что ?????  там вопрос вооще о другом ,  насчет идентичной задачи там тоже мимо,  мне не надо MVVM,    и насчет конвертора  как раз я и спрашиваю

Comment: Ну как говорится, хотите делать костыли - удачи, дело ваше. Мое лишь показать как правильно, а WPF без MVVM, привязок и всего его функционала лучше вовсе не использовать (ибо это как в феррари засунуть мотор от жигули, вроде работает, а не то...), работали бы лучше в WinForm в таком случае...

Comment: ребят ну что же Вы так выводы делаете как то не правильно , я не команда разработчиков а любитель одиночка , а в писании сказано что  MVVM  это технология для  командного использования и только в средних и больших проектах ,  и с какого мне это счастье пихать в свой код который умещается на ладошке ,  это MVVM уже пихают куда не попадя

Comment: не знаете ответа начинаете развозить халивары , тут Вам уже к стате не раз уже указывали на это, не знаете промолчите , не понятно уточните вопрос

Comment: @vova-forum значит где-то ещё вы пытаетесь DependencyProperty приравнять Visibility. Вам же пишут, что невозможно преобразовать один тип в другой. В тексте ошибки написано строка, где ошибка: найдите и справьте по аналогии. MVVM - это паттерн проектирования приложения, специально созданная для WPF. Вы учите язык? Тогда пишите консольное приложение и не парьтесь. Вы хотите писать интерфейс в WPF? Тогда сразу учитесь правильному подходу. Сейчас у тебя маленькая прога с двумя кнопками и всё кажется простым, а когда захочешь написать, что-то покрупнее, то всё, что ты знал окажется ненужным.

Comment: John  спасибо за ответ ,  вот я и не могу DependencyProperty приравнять Visibility ,  а везде только упоминание про ТекстБоксы, вот я и ищу

Comment: Создание привязки в коде: https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/binding_and_styles_WPF/level8/8_3.php

Comment: Чтобы использовался конвертер, добавьте: `bind.Converter = new MyConverter();`