# Автопрокрутка DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, прокрутка

Мне необходимо контролировать прокрутку `DataGrid`, т.е. решать какой элемент должен быть верхним отображаемым. Для этого я хочу использовать либо свойство `CurrentItem` либо метод `ScrollIntoView()`. Но все упирается в то, что я не могу получить индекс верхней строки. Есть ли какой-то вариант получить этот индекс?

Comment: А если перематывать в два этапа: сначала перематываем на самый первый, потом на нужный. Он не будет верхним в таком случае? (перематывать с помощью ScrollIntoView, да)

Comment: @АндрейNOP Идея в принципе интересная, но не будет ли прыжков? И все равно, самым интересным является именно определение "нужного" элемента. Мне ведь надо понять на каком элементе сейчас пользователь. Вот крутит он колесом или скролбаром и текущий верхний отображаемый элемент мне и нужен.

Comment: а можно развить вашу мысль по поводу того зачем вам нужен верхний элемент, возможно вам подскажут, как по другому это сделать? А вообще пока, я бы начал двигаться в сторону того что высчитал часть прокрученного и разбивку по страницам, и математикой подтянул бы номер строки которая верхняя, но это в теории на практике я бы поискал иной путь.

Comment: у меня есть таблица, в которую подтягиваются сообщения из БД в режиме реального времени. Иногда пользователю потребуется посмотреть сообщения, которые приходили ранее, так вот чтобы при приходе нового сообщения пользователя не дергало вверх мне и нужно знать номер верхнего отображаемого сообщения. При приходе нового я просто перемотаю грид до нужного мне( верхнего отображаемого) индекса и пользователь ничего не заметит

Comment: @Monomax, а как вообще можно высчитать прокрученное? Я не могу найти события прокрутки в `DataGrid`.

Comment: Эмм, а зачем вы вообще перематываете при приходе нового элемента? Подозреваю, что вы полностью ItemsSource меняете у DataGrid? Не нужно этого делать, просто догружайте в уже привязанную коллекцию

Comment: @АндрейNOP, по умолчанию, `DataGrid` сдвигает строку на 1 вниз при приходе нового элемента. У меня же при приходе элемента, с помощью `ScrollIntoView` весь грид отматывается наверх. Это необходимо по ТЗ. Типа видишь новые события. Весь вопрос во втором режиме. Когда пользователь просматривает то, что было раньше.

Comment: Ну дык не отматывайте во втором режиме, пока не понятно

Comment: @АндрейNOP, во втором режиме и не мотаю. Новые элементы добавляются сверху таблицы. при добавлении элемента происходит смещение всех элементов на 1 вниз. Вот это не есть правильно. Правильно, чтобы все стояло на месте

Comment: @АндрейNOP, а каким образом обновить отображение в гриде кроме обновления ItemSource?

Comment: *а каким образом обновить отображение в гриде кроме обновления ItemSource?* — например, с помощью ObservableCollection // Ок, теперь понятно, попробую что-то сочинить

Comment: @АндрейNOP, `ObservableCollection` не перестраивает грид. Кроме явного изменения `ItemSource` я не могу придумать вариантов

Comment: Значит вы что-то неправильно делаете, т.к. именно для этих целей `ObservableCollection` и сделан (реализация `INotifyCollectionChanged`)

Comment: Задание источника данных для грида:`ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(local:Messages.MessagesCollection), UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` и само свойство: `public static ObservableCollection<Message> MessagesCollection
        {
            get { return messages; }
            set { messages = value; }
        }`

Comment: Ну а добавляете элементы вы в `ObservableCollection` как?

Comment: С добавлением новых элементов проблем нет. Проблема с обновлением уже имеющихся элементов. У меня в гриде шаблон ячейки завязан на ее значение. По умолчанию в ячейке кнопка, а при нажатии вместо кнопки отображается `TextBlock` со временем нажатия. Вот без обновления `ItemSource` шаблон не меняется

Comment: А, ну дык ваши `Message` должны реализовывать `INotifyPropertyChanged`. "Классический" пример на этом сайте: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573196/218063 Обратите внимание, стрелочки поворачиваются *без переназначения `ItemsSource`*

Comment: @АндрейNOP, Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получите `ScrollViewer` вашего `DataGrid`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += (o, e) => scrollViewer = GetVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(MyDataGrid);
}

ScrollViewer scrollViewer;

private static T GetVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : Visual
{
    T child = null;
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        child = v as T;
        if (child == null) child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
        if (child != null) break;
    }
    return child;
}
```

Что интересно, `ScrollViewer` внутри `DataGrid` отсчитывает вертикальное смещение в элементах, а не в координатах (как он обычно это делает).

Перед добавлением новых элементов запомните текущее смещение:

```
int verticalOffset;

verticalOffset = (int)scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
```

А после добавления скорректируйте его (здесь `x` — количество добавленных элементов):

```
scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(verticalOffset + x);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]