# Как управлять отображением в окне из разных контролов

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation, controls

Нужно реализовать изменение отображаемого контента в окне. Все переходы происходят по нажатию кнопок в разных контролах. MainWindow открывается после успешной регистрации.

***Схема переходов***
[image: Схема переходов]

Пытался сделать по этим примерам([пример1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573050/%D0%98%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wpf-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-winforms-%D0%B2-mvvm), [пример2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1266044/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-view)), они похожи, но мне нужно что бы была возможность изменять содержимое из каждого контрола, получилось сделать только переходы между "AuthorizationControl" и "RegistrationFirstStageControl". Вот код который у меня есть на данный момент:

***Основная ViewModel***

```
namespace Frontend.ViewModel.AuthorizationRegistrationWindow
{
    public class RootViewModel : ObservableObjcet
    {
        private object _currentContentVM;
        public object CurrentContentVM
        {
            get => _currentContentVM;
            set
            {
                _currentContentVM = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentContentVM");
            }
        }

        public RootViewModel()
        {
            //Здесь я передаю Action, что бы изменить содержимое из другого контрола.
            CurrentContentVM = new AuthorizationViewModel((param) => CurrentContentVM = param);
        }
    }
}
```

***ViewModel авторизации***

```
namespace Frontend.ViewModel.AuthorizationRegistrationWindow
{
    public class AuthorizationViewModel : ObservableObjcet
    {
        private AuthorizationModel _authorizationModel;
        public AuthorizationViewModel(Action<object> onActivate)
        {
            //Здесь в команду помещаю тот самый отправленный Action, который вызывается по нажатию 
            //кнопки и открывается контрол регистрации.
            OpenFirstStageReg = new DelegateCommand((o) => onActivate(new FirstStageRegViewModel()));

            _authorizationModel = new AuthorizationModel();
        }

        #region Property
        private string _login;
        public string Login
        {
            get { return _login; }
            set 
            { 
                _login = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _password;
        public string Password
        {
            get { return _password; }
            set
            {
                _password = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private bool _isAuth;
        public bool IsAuth
        {
            get { return _authorizationModel.IsAuth; }
            set 
            {
                _isAuth = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        #endregion

        /*COMMAND*/
        public DelegateCommand OpenFirstStageReg { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

***Код окна авторизации и регистрации***

```
<Window x:Class="Frontend.View.AllWindows.AuthorizationRegistrationWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Frontend.View.Controls.AuthorizationRegistration"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Frontend.ViewModel.AuthorizationRegistrationWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="xProject" Height="450" Width="800" MinHeight="400" MinWidth="400">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AuthorizationViewModel}">
            <view:AuthorizationControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FirstStageRegViewModel}">
            <view:RegistrationFirstStageControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SecondStageRegViewModel}">
            <view:RegistrationSecondStageControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentContentVM}"/>
</Window>
```

***Файл App.xaml.сs***

```
namespace Frontend
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            var mainWindow = new AuthorizationRegistrationWindow();
            mainWindow.DataContext = new RootViewModel();
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Можете внедрить какой-нибудь сервис, добавить его в DI контейнер и уже его изменять в ваших ViewModel's. В нужной VM(где нужно показывать изменения) подпишитесь на событие об изменение свойств.

Если не хотите использовать DI-контейнер, то простой и топорный вариант - Singleton/Static класс. В нем также реализовываете нужные вам свойства и события об их изменении, но смотреться все это будет гораздо хуже.

Я лично открыл для себя новый мир в WPF, когда познакомился с Prism, ReactiveUI фреймворками. Оба вам рекомендую.

Comment: Вместо того чтобы разобраться в вопросе используя прилинкованный ответ, вы создаете дубликат вопроса только изменив заголовок. Не надо так.

Comment: Передаете главную вьюмодель в конструктор вм логина, по кнопке в команде меняете вм на основную в главной вм, получаете ожидаемый результат. Но не разобравшись, как это работает, ничего не получится.

Comment: @aepot, я пытался разобраться в вопросе используя прилинкованный ответ, но видимо мой опыт не позволяет мне адаптировать прилинкованный ответ к своей ситуации. Поэтому я и пытаюсь задать вопрос.

Comment: Вы сначала запустите пример отдельно и разберитесь в том как он сам по себе работает, а уже потом внедряйте. Сходу конечно сложно может показаться.

Comment: Dependency Injection/Inversion of Control контейнер необязательно сразу прикручивать, можно по-старинке. В прилинкованном ответе и так и сяк показано.

Comment: Добавил еще ссылку - как делать команды.

Comment: @aepot, если я правильно вас понял, нужно передавать основнуюVM(RootViewModel) в конструктор VM которую нужно открыть(AuthorizationViewModel), и далее из этой VM открывать другие VM используя VM которую передали.

Comment: Да, можно так..