# Как обратиться к ячейкам элемента Grid и их содержимому

Tags: c#, wpf

Имею сетку, построенную с помощью `Grid` 10*10.
В ячейках этой сетки лежат элементы `Button`, созданные и помещенные туда динамически.

Вопрос, как мне обратится к этим ячейкам, чтоб можно было взаимодействовать с помещенными в них элементами (к примеру поменять им цвет, или свойство content).
Не могу понять как это в WPF делается..

Метод создающий кнопку.

```
private void CreateItemField(int i, int j, Brush color)
{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Margin = new Thickness(0.5d);
    button.Background = color;
    button.Name = "btn" + i + j;

    MainGrid.Children.Add(button);
    Grid.SetColumn(button, i);
    Grid.SetRow(button, j);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Простым путём — никак.

Если вы почему-то решили создавать контент в code-behind (почему не через `ItemsControl`, с MVVM?), проще всего при создании запомнить отображение номера клетки в кнопку.

Если вы этого не делаете, `Grid` сам по себе не имеет понятия о ячейках. Вы можете опросить у него `Children`, получить список всех дочерних элементов, и искать среди них в цикле (или через LINQ) нужные, пользуясь функциями `Grid.GetRow` и `Grid.GetColumn` для получения нужных индексов.

---

Вот вам код:

```
Button[,] buttons = new Button[10, 10];
```

```
private void CreateItemField(int i, int j, Brush color)
{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Margin = new Thickness(0.5d);
    button.Background = color;
    button.Name = "btn" + i + j;

    MainGrid.Children.Add(button);
    Grid.SetColumn(button, i);
    Grid.SetRow(button, j);
    buttons[i, j] = button;
}
```

Comment: Я новичек в WPF поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Я кстати при создании так и сделал - записал в название кнопки маркировку ячейки. Как теперь по ней ее достать? Обновил вопрос с примером создания кнопки.

Comment: @РоманТимохов: Снова-таки никак, только перебором. `Grid` не выдаёт элементы по имени. Ну или завести словарь на стороне code-behind.

Comment: @РоманТимохов: Посмотрите [сюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/270439/10105), это ваш случай?

Comment: Спсибо, буду разбираться.

Comment: @РоманТимохов: Вот [ещё](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573196/10105) может пригодиться.