# Создание игры Pacman на WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Задумал написать игру (простой PacMan).
Сделал Grid сетку 30x30
присвоил нажатию клавиш (стрелочек) методы для перемещения картинки Pacman по гриду:
как пример движение вверх и влево :

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);

    if (e.Key == Key.Down)
    {
        PacmanDuwn();
    }
    else
    if (e.Key == Key.Left)
    {
        PacmanLeft();
    }
}
```

Сами методы :

```
public int Column;
public int Rou;

private void PacmanDuwn()
{
    if (Rou == 29)
    {
        Rou = 0;
        Grid.SetRow(Pacman, Rou);
    }
    else
    {
        Rou += 1;
        Grid.SetRow(Pacman, Rou);
    }
}
private void PacmanLeft()
{
    if (Column == 0)
    {
        Column = 29;
        Grid.SetColumn(Pacman, Column);
    }
    else
    {
        Column -= 1;
        Grid.SetColumn(Pacman, Column);
    }
}
```

Если просто - то, при нажатии на стрелочки, я переназначаю позицию картинки по гриду вызывая - Grid.SetColumn, или  Grid.SetRow ("+ -"колонка, или там "+- "строка)
картинка перемещается, по ячейкам, все хорошо.

Далее мне нужно от рисовать лабиринт, и корм который будет "съедать" Pacman. Думаю просто по вставлять картинки в  xaml разметке так как мне нужно, создавая лабиринт.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, что бы Pacman не проходил под стеной лабиринта, а упирался в нее :)  Ну и так же чтобы "съедал" корм, при попадании в 
ячейку с кормом.
Понимаю, что это должна быть какая то проверка, по типу "есть ли компонент в данной ячейке", и если компонент такой (стена) - то не пройдешь, 
а если компонент "корм" - то проходи, и затри его.

Может конечно я не в ту сторону двигаюсь, и есть более верные решения передвижения контролов по гриду, и взаимодействия контролов, но пока только к этому пришел :) 
Заранее  благодарен!

Comment: Зачем **пукмен**, зачем???

Comment: Да вот, захотелось именно его родимого :)

Comment: А чем пакман не угодил?

Comment: @vp_arth, так права же нямко!

Comment: Наличие стенок и еды придётся таки проверять перед ходом

Comment: да, проверять нужно, а потом нужно что - то с ними делать. Думал что есть какой - то способ узнать, что содержится в определенной ячейке грида

Comment: А вы не держите бизнес-логику в UI. У вас должна быть таблица с содержимым клеток отдельно, не зависящая от Grid'а.

Comment: Да пукмена можно и не писать, можно супчика горохового покушать и готов результат...

Comment: @VladD нет. такую таблицу не делал, я фактически только начал знакомиться с WPF. Вы имели в введу, инициализацию каждого компонента не в XAML а в MainWindow?

Comment: Вы бы для начала язык на котором говорите выучили а потом уж и за программирование взялись?

Comment: переименую в PacMan, спасибо за замечание.

Comment: @SergeyD: Нет, конечно. Вы должны разделить программу на части: контент и представление. Всё, что относится к смыслу, должно быть отдельно от UI. Вот вам [пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/270445/10105), покурите его.

Comment: @VladD я Вас понял, спасибо!