# С помощью чего писать игру на c#?

Tags: c#, разработка-игр

Всем привет.

Я в программировании новичок и хочу сделать какую-нибудь примитивную 2d игру не на unity, а с нуля, просто для себя (хочу изобрести велосипед).

Так вот, на WinForms нашла такой способ: по таймеру постоянно повторяется перерисование карты, карта рисуется в picturebox. Ну и сама карта - массив ячеек 300 на 300, в picturebox легко можно в квадрате любого размера и в любом месте добавить картинку или залить цветом. Так вот, оно то работает, карта рисуется и видно, как персонаж ходит, но я понятия не имею, на сколько это рационально. Ну и есть WPF, где говорят, что окошки рисуются с помощью видеокарты и все вроде бы круто и можно было бы там все сделать, вот только picturebox там нету. А то, что есть, не подходит.

Мне нужно, чтобы можно было создать цикл и внутри цикла высчитывать координаты и размер квадрата, и в данном квадрате залить цветом или нарисовать определенную картинку. Есть ли в WPF что нибудь, где можно так сделать? И рационально ли использовать WPF для такого? Если нет, то где можно писать мелкие 2d игры (с нуля, не на готовом движке)?

Comment: Ну вот вам пара примеров: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/573050/10105, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/270439/10105

Comment: если хотите сделать игру, начните с того графического движка, который лучше знаете. Хотя бы для того, чтобы больше времени потратить на саму игру. Оптимизации и прочие красивости можно оставить на потом. Самое главное не запихивайте логику игры в контролы, ни в WinForms, ни в WPF. А 2d игры на основе поля с ячейками, можно хоть в консоли писать - один символ = одна ячейка, только графика будет на любителя =).

Comment: Предлагаю попробовать monogame framework, который является продолжением развития XNA и предоставляет возможность создавать игры с использование GPU (OpenGL или DirectX). Написан на C#, хорошая документация, дает опыт для перехода на тот же Unity, свободный и кроссплатформенный, на нем написаны довольно хорошие игры инди (Bastion, Stardew Valley, Wizorb, Fez). Сайт [Monogame](http://www.monogame.net/). В WPF хорошо использовать Canvas, но там оптимизация разделяется между CPU и GPU, поэтому не все рендерится видеокартой.

Answer (score 2):

XNA - платформа для создания игр. Как и в предыдущих платформах для описания действий игры используется язык программирования (C# или VB). Отличий WinForms и WPF от XNA много. В вышеописанных платформах используется принцип реакции на событие, произошло событие - пишем действия, нет событий нет действия. В XNA же описывается игровой экран в конкретный момент исходя из неких переменных, которые меняются в зависимости от действий пользователя. Кроме того XNA в отличии от платформ для бизнес приложения можно запускать как на PC так и на приставке Xbox или телефоне с OC Windows. Максимально возможная поддержка 3D среди высокоуровневых API. Трехмерную игру писать лучше на этой технологии.

//Я не могу не чего порекомендовать кроме C# XNA, ведь я знаком только с ним

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/4423aa62-8be0-4f56-b9eb-738c10ecd680/-3d-c?forum=msdnfeedbackru