# Игра Змейка - задержка между регистрацией нажатий WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Делаю змейку на WPF, но уже столкнулся с несколькими проблемами.
Например, для управления змейкой пользователь может пользоваться **WASD** или стрелочками, но не предусмотрено, что при повороте позиция меняется не сразу, что и порождает следующий баг.

Допустим, змейка движется вниз, пользователь с минимальной задержкой "поворачивает" её влева, потом вверх, переменная направления меняется слишком быстро, поэтому получается, что змея поменяла направление на противоположное. Игра заканчивается поражением.

И ещё один серьёзный баг. Вот структура странички с игрой:

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <Label Name="ScoreLabel" Content="Your current score: 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#118ab2"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="GameField" MinHeight="400" Margin="5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Сама змейка, еда, а также разметка прописываются в `Canvas`. Но я почему-то не могу настроить, чтобы разметка была ровной. Всегда на пол клетки "выезжает". Выглядит это как: есть концы разметки, нет границ, при утыкании в эту неполную клетку игра резонно считает, что пользователь проиграл.

Движение пытался исправлять добавлением `Thread.Sleep()` в конце функции `Window_KeyDown()`, а `Canvas` пытался исправить добавлением

```cs
int rows = (int)GameField.ActualHeight / elementSize;
GameField.Height = rows * elementSize;
```

Однако, везде испытал неудачу.

Как можно исправить управление и внешний вид игрового поля?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` — это [не лучшая идея](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615113/10105).

Comment: Возможно, эти ответы [(1)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/270439/10105), [(2)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/573050/10105) вам помогут тоже. (Там вряд ли получится много скопипастить, но идеи можно подсмотреть.)

Comment: Знаю, поэтому я его и не использовал, уже столько времени сижу над этими примерами, не нашёл там такого, чего хочу :(

Comment: Ну вы смотрели в примеры? Там вроде доска ровно получается

Comment: Конечно, смотрел. Я проверил сейчас, у меня тоже почему-то ровно начало получаться способом, который пробовал. Может, тогда что-то перепутал. И await я попытался запихнуть в функцию KeyDown_Window(), однако, никакого эффекта, змею всё равно можно развернуть в обратную сторону до смены её позиций... Тут пока бессилен(

Comment: В обработчик Keydown не нужно ничего засовывать, наоборот, он должен отработать максимально быстро. А вы попробуйте залогировать приход Keydown и Keyup, может быть сюрприз.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> но не предусмотрено, что при повороте позиция меняется не сразу

А надо, чтоб сразу. Игрок, нажимая на клавишу должен видеть реакцию игры немедленно, иначе он будет считать, что кнопки плохо нажимаются, или игра тупит, и вообще сломает клавиатуру об монитор.

> Сама змейка, еда, а также разметка прописываются в `Canvas`

Вам не нужен здесь `Canvas`. Холст нужен тогда, когда вам надо работать с координатами для рисования. В данной игре вам достаточно отобразить игровое поле-матрицу, где клетки просто идут друг за другом, никакой работы с координатам не требуется. А далее просто менять состояние каждой клетки.

> есть концы разметки, нет границ, при утыкании в эту неполную клетку игра резонно считает, что пользователь проиграл

Перемешивание состояния графики и игровой логики вообще ни к чему хорошему не приведет. Игровая логика должна быть игровой логикой, интерфейс игры - интерфейсом игры. Логика говорит интерфейсу, что в ней поменялось, интерфейс отображает. Юзер нажал кнопку, интерфейс сказал логике, что что-то надо при этом сделать или поменять.

> Движение пытался исправлять добавлением `Thread.Sleep()`

`Thread.Sleep()`, выполняемый в UI потоке намертво вешает приложение, пока действует. Вам нужно немного асинхронного программирования здесь. Но! Никогда не синхронизируйте логику разных частей приложения с помощью ожидания по времени - это плохая практика. Другими словами - костыль. Есть события, есть колбэки, есть асинхронное ожидание, куча инструментов, чтобы не делать `Sleep(t)`.

> Однако, везде испытал неудачу.

У вас графика управляет игрой. Или как говорят "хвост виляет собакой". Вы пытаетесь сделать очень сложное дело, заставить пиксели влиять на игровую логику, когда должно быть все в точности наоборот.

Давайте попробуем переписать игру так, чтобы "собака виляла хвостом". Ну и познакомимся с WPF.

## Как написать игру "Змейка" в WPF и выжить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предполагаю, что вы еще только начали осваивать WPF, решил написать вам змейку с использованием популярных практик, используемых именно в WPF.

Дело в том, что в WPF в общем понимании код не сваливается в кучу в класс окна, да и даже в Winforms это делают только новички. Я объясню кратко, что и как, не углубляясь в мелкие детали, но если интересно, в сети очень много написано про то, что я сейчас расскажу.

*Приготовьтесь, сейчас будет много информации, но я выбрал только самые основы. Чтобы попробовать игру, показанную ниже, создайте новый .NET Core 3.1 или .NET 5 WPF проект.*

### Структура приложения

Код логически разделяется на 3 слоя:

- внутренняя логика приложения (**Model**)
- интерфейс (**View**)
- логика для взаимодействия с интерфейсом (**ViewModel**).

Все вместе это выглядит как **Model-View-ViewModel**, или сокращенно **MVVM** - самый удобный и популярный шаблон проектирования приложения, используемый в **WPF**. Грубо говоря, это точка опоры для того, чтобы всё в приложении не смешалось в кучу, чтобы не застрять в состоянии *"не знаю, что теперь делать, придётся все переписывать"*.

### Базовые технологии

#### Привязка данных

Самая основная технология, без которой в WPF написать что-то вменяемое очень сложно - **привязка данных**. А конкретно привязка данных к интерфейсу. Она по сути **переворачивает работу связки интерфейс-код с ног на голову**.

Новички же как делают - дают контролам имена `x:Name`, и обновляют контролы, присваивая свойствам данные. Это называется прямая ручная работа с интерфейсом. Но разработчики Microsoft не для этого делали WPF, и не сильно старались сделать этот способ работы с интерфейсом удобным. Как следствие, он очень неудобен, намного хуже, чем **Winforms**.

"С ног на голову" переворачивает это все привязка именно потому, что вы грубо говоря сообщаете контролу, где брать данные, и он сам обновляется, когда обновляются данные. То есть не вы даете контролам данные, а они сами в себя их затягивают, вы только в XAML указываете `Binding` - **откуда тянуть**, а в коде с помощью `OnPropertyChanged()` - **когда тянуть**.

Имена контролам за ненадобностью давать больше не нужно. Отвечает за эту магию класс `Binding`. Механически, чтобы `Binding` узнал, что данные поменялись, он подписывается на событие `PropertyChanged` в классе, который вы установили в `DataContext` контрола. Сам же `DataContext` наследуется между контролами, поэтому его можно назначить окну, и все заработает.

Чтобы использовать `PropertyChanged` вызовы к коде, нужно реализовать специально предназначенный для этого интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Реалзиция выглядит вот так:

**NotifyPropertyChanged.cs**

```cs
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

*Каждый класс создается в отдельном файле проекта. Классы можно добавить в Visual Studio кликнув правой кнопкой по решению в проводнике решения и выбрать `Добавить -> Класс`, и вставить туда код.*

Теперь можно наследоваться от этого класса, и вызывать `OnPropertyChanged()` там, где нужно сообщить интерфейсу, что свойство **ViewModel** обновилось.

#### Команды

Так как код в классе окна больше писать не нужно, обработчики событий использовать в MVVM неудобно, что же делать, если нажал кнопку? - вызвать команду. А команду можно привязать как и любые данные к кнопке через `Binding`, да и не только к кнопке, ниже вы в этом убедитесь. Чтобы удобно использовать команды, есть вот такой вспомогательный класс:

**RelayCommand.cs**

```cs
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

Так же, добавьте этот класс в проект.

*Не забывайте подключать пространства имён в тех местах, где студия подсвечивает вам ошибки. Чтобы сделать это легко и быстро, поставьте курсор на подчеркнутое и нажмите* <kbd>Ctrl+.</kbd>*, из появившегося меню, выберите вариант с `using`, и студия сама добавит вам нужное пространство имен в начале кода.*

### Игра "Змейка"

*Я начну с самых глубин игровой логики, и постепенно поднимусь к интерфейсу по слоям MVVM.*

Как можно представить игровое поле? Самый очевидный ответ - с помощью двумерного массива. А что может быть в ячейке этого массива? Змейка, пусто, еда или например стена. Описать в коде такое просто - энумератором.

Второй энумератор, который потребуется - это направление движения змейки. И еще структура "коодинаты" для удобной работы с координатами ячеек на игровом поле.

**Data.cs**

```cs
public enum CellState
{
    Empty,
    Snake,
    Food
}

public enum Direction
{
    Right,
    Down,
    Left,
    Up
}

public struct Coords
{
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }

    public Coords(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

Для удобства самые мелкие кусочки кода с энумераторами, я помещаю в файл **Data.cs**, но профессиональные разработчики на полном серьёзе каждую структурную единицу кода кладут в отдельный файл. В больших проектах так делать реально удобнее.

Кстати, я не буду делать двумерный массив для игрового поля, а буду делать массив массивов, или список списков, что в данном контексте - одно и то же. Игровое поле будет выглядеть так:

```cs
public List<List<Cell>> Arena { get; }
```

А ячейка игрового поля - так:

**Data.cs**

```cs
public class Cell : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private CellState _state;

    public CellState State
    {
        get => _state;
        set
        {
            _state = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот класс, который создает новое игровое поле и содержит основную логику игры:

**Game.cs**

```cs
public class Game
{
    private const int _delay = 300;

    private readonly MainViewModel _viewModel; // ссылка на вью-модель
    private readonly Snake _snake; // Змейка
    private readonly Food _food; // Еда
    private Direction _direction; // Куда змейка ползет
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts = null; // Щтука, чтобы останавливать игру (ставить на паузу)
    private bool _addDelay; // добавить паузу после смены напраления

    public List<List<Cell>> Arena { get; } // игровое поле

    public Direction Direction
    {
        get => _direction;
        set
        {
            // Вот это не дает змейке ползти назад.
            if (value != _direction && (int)value % 2 != (int)_direction % 2)
            {
                _direction = value;
                _addDelay = true;
                Update(); // немедленная реакция на нажатие
            }
        }
    }

    // создание новой игры
    public Game(MainViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
        int width = 40;
        int height = 30;
        Arena = new List<List<Cell>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            List<Cell> row = new List<Cell>();
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                row.Add(new Cell());
            }
            Arena.Add(row);
        }
        _food = new Food(Arena, 10, 2);
        _snake = new Snake(this, _food, new Coords(Arena[0].Count / 2, Arena.Count / 2), 1, Direction.Right);
    }

    // запустить игру
    public void Start()
    {
        if (_cts == null)
            Run();
    }

    // остановить игру
    public void Stop()
    {
        _cts?.Cancel();
    }

    // а здесь змейка в цикле ползает, обратите внимание на то что метод "async" - асинхронный
    private async void Run()
    {
        using (_cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            try
            {
                while (true) // повторять, пока не надоест
                {
                    if (_snake.Died) // если змейка умерла
                    {
                        _viewModel.EndGame(); // Game Over
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        Update(); // Обновить игровое состояние

                    await Task.Delay(_delay, _cts.Token); // а вот единственная асинхронная операция
                    if (_addDelay)
                    {
                        _addDelay = false;
                        await Task.Delay(_delay / 2, _cts.Token);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { } // была остановка?
            catch (Exception ex) // была другая ошибка?
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        _cts = null;

    }

    // начисляет 10 очков за каждую найденную еду
    public void GiveScore()
    {
        _viewModel.Score += 10;
    }

    // обновляет игровое состояние
    public void Update()
    {
        _snake.Move(Direction); // двинуть змейку
        _food.Update(); // попросить еду добавиться на поле
    }
}
```

Сама змейка - это как отдельная боевая единица, вы можете при таком построении приложения даже 2 змейки на поле выпустить, одной например может управлять игрок, другой компьютер. Здесь - на что фантазии хватит.

**Snake.cs**

```cs
public class Snake
{
    private readonly Queue<Coords> _tail; // хвост змейки
    private readonly Food _food; // змейка взаимодействует с едой
    private readonly Game _game; // там есть игровое поле

    private Coords _head; // голова змейки
    public int _length; // длина змейки без учета головы
    public bool Died { get; private set; } // показывает, жива ли змейка

    public Coords Head // голова
    {
        get => _head;
        private set
        {
            _head = value;
            // отобразить голову на арене
            _game.Arena[value.Y][value.X].State = CellState.Snake;
        }
    }

    // создать новую змейку
    public Snake(Game game, Food food, Coords head, int length, Direction direction)
    {
        _game = game;
        _food = food;
        _tail = new Queue<Coords>();
        Head = head;
        _length = length;
        while (_tail.Count < _length)
            Move(direction); // проползти немного, чтобы змейка была во всю длину на поле
    }

    // ползти на одну клетку в направлении direction
    public void Move(Direction direction)
    {
        Coords coords = Head;
        switch (direction)
        {
            case Direction.Right:
                coords = new Coords(coords.X + 1, coords.Y);                   
                break;
            case Direction.Down:
                coords = new Coords(coords.X, coords.Y + 1);
                break;
            case Direction.Left:
                coords = new Coords(coords.X - 1, coords.Y);
                break;
            case Direction.Up:
                coords = new Coords(coords.X, coords.Y - 1);
                break;
        }
        if (!CheckMove(coords)) // а можно ли туда ползти?
            return;
        _tail.Enqueue(Head); // старая голова стала началом хвоста
        Head = coords; // новая голова

        while (_tail.Count > _length) // если хвост длиннее, чем нужно
        {
            Coords tail = _tail.Dequeue(); // отрезать клетку от хваоста
            _game.Arena[tail.Y][tail.X].State = CellState.Empty; // и отобразить это на игровом поле
        }
    }

    // проверка следующего хода
    private bool CheckMove(Coords coords)
    {
        // если выползем за пределы или врежемся в себя
        if (coords.X >= _game.Arena[0].Count || coords.X < 0 || coords.Y >= _game.Arena.Count || coords.Y < 0 || _game.Arena[coords.Y][coords.X].State == CellState.Snake)
            Died = true; // то умрём
        else
        if (_game.Arena[coords.Y][coords.X].State == CellState.Food) // иначе может попасться еда
        {
            _food.FoodCount--; // сказать еде, что ее стало меньше
            _length++; // вырастить хвост
            _game.GiveScore(); // дать игроку очки
        }
        return !Died;
    }
}
```

Еда отвечает за количество себя на поле, частоту появления ну и рисует себя, когда надо в случайной клетке поля.

**Food.cs**

```cs
public class Food
{
    private readonly int _foodDelay; // задержка между появлением еды в игровых ходах
    private readonly int _maxFood; // максимальное количество еды на поле
    private readonly Random _rnd; // генератор случайных чисел
    public readonly List<List<Cell>> _arena; // ссылка на игровое поле

    private int tick; // сколько ходов прошло с момента последнего появления еды

    public int FoodCount { get; set; } // сколько сейчас еды на поле

    public Food(List<List<Cell>> arena, int foodDelay, int maxFood)
    {
        _rnd = new Random();
        _arena = arena;
        _foodDelay = foodDelay;
        _maxFood = maxFood;
    }

    // добавить еду
    public void Update()
    {
        if (tick >= _foodDelay && FoodCount < _maxFood)
        {
            tick = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                Coords coords = new Coords(_rnd.Next(_arena[0].Count), _rnd.Next(_arena.Count)); // выбрать случайную клетку
                if (_arena[coords.Y][coords.X].State == CellState.Empty) // если там пусто
                {
                    _arena[coords.Y][coords.X].State = CellState.Food; // нарисовать еду
                    FoodCount++; // учесть, еды стало больше
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            tick++; // +1 ход не было еды
    }
}
```

**ViewModel** содержит в себе логику приложения, не отвечающую за игру, но отвечающую за взаимодействие с интерфейсом. Точнее наоборот, за взаимодействие интерфейса с вью-моделью, то есть предоставляет ему все необходимое, чтобы игра работала.

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _score;
    private int _highScore;
    private List<List<Cell>> _arena;
    private Game _game;
    private bool _gameRunning;
    private bool _gameOver;
    private ICommand _moveCommand;
    private ICommand _startCommand;

    public int Score // Очки
    {
        get => _score;
        set
        {
            _score = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int HighScore // Лучший результат
    {
        get => _highScore;
        set
        {
            _highScore = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public List<List<Cell>> Arena // Ссылка на игровое поле для интерфейса
    {
        get => _arena;
        set
        {
            _arena = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool GameRunning // Сейчас игра играет?
    {
        get => _gameRunning;
        set
        {
            _gameRunning = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool GameOver // Игра проиграна?
    {
        get => _gameOver;
        set
        {
            _gameOver = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // Начать игру, сюда привязана кнопка "Start/Pause" в интерфейсе и клавиша Пробел
    public ICommand StartCommand => _startCommand ??= new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (!GameRunning)
        {
            if (GameOver)
                NewGame();
            else
            {
                GameRunning = true;
                _game.Start();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            GameRunning = false;
            _game.Stop();
        }
    });

    // Сюда привязаны стрелки и WASD
    public ICommand MoveCommand => _moveCommand ??= new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (GameRunning && Enum.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out Direction direction))
        {
            _game.Direction = direction;
        }
    });

    // Змейка умерла, закончить игру
    public void EndGame()
    {
        GameRunning = false;
        GameOver = true;
        if (HighScore < Score)
            HighScore = Score;
    }

    // Создать новую игру
    private void NewGame()
    {
        if (GameRunning)
            _game.Stop();
        GameOver = false;
        Score = 0;
        _game = new Game(this);
        Arena = _game.Arena;
    }

    // Здесь всё начинается
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        NewGame();
    }
}
```

Чтобы подключить **ViewModel** к окну, надо как я выше писал, задать `DataContext`, вот кстати, весь код окна:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

Интерфеейс змейки содержит много для вас нового, но я уверен, вы разберетесь. Вообще XAML не такой страшный, как кажется, и в нем просто удобнее создавать интерфейсы, чем в коде C#. Не зря же Microsoft решили сделать именно так.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" 
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Right" Command="{Binding MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="Right"/>
        <KeyBinding Key="Down" Command="{Binding MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="Down"/>
        <KeyBinding Key="Left" Command="{Binding MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="Left"/>
        <KeyBinding Key="Up" Command="{Binding MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="Up"/>
        <KeyBinding Key="D" Command="{Binding MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="Right"/>
        <KeyBinding Key="S" Command="{Binding MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="Down"/>
        <KeyBinding Key="A" Command="{Binding MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="Left"/>
        <KeyBinding Key="W" Command="{Binding MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="Up"/>
        <KeyBinding Key="Space" Command="{Binding StartCommand}"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Score:" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Score}" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="High Score:" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding HighScore}" FontSize="20"  FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Margin="5" Padding="15,0" Command="{Binding StartCommand}">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Start"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding GameRunning}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Pause"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding GameOver}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="New game"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Background="AliceBlue" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Arena}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border Width="18" Height="18" Margin="1" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <Border.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightBlue"/>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Snake">
                                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DodgerBlue"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Food">
                                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="9"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Border.Style>
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="White" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1">
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding GameOver}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Margin="20,10" Text="GAME OVER" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="20,10" Text="{Binding Score, StringFormat=Score: {0}}" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Вот они, все привязки данных здесь. Я показываю контролам - где брать данные, а в C# коде вообще не думаю о контролах. Это и называется разделение приложения на слои, с которых я начал этот рассказ.

#### Вот и всё, змейка готова.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Из меня, кстати, не очень хороший игрок. Приятного кодинга!**

---

#### Обновлено

Немного сделал комфортнее управление, теперь реже проигрываю. А так же если игра закончена, написал на кнопке "New game".

Архив с решением - https://yadi.sk/d/M97soEdRyU3gMA

Comment: Хм, а правильно-ли это с точки зрения полноценного MVVM? `public Game(MainViewModel viewModel)`. Ведь `Game`, это модель, а значит он должен быть самостоятельным, а не зависеть от его обертки. Исходя из этого выскакивают, как по мне, костыли по типу `_viewModel.Score += 10;`, ибо почему вдруг некий класс VM стал отвечать за кол-во очков, если очки - это часть игры? Это как допустим игрок, где его имя находится в классе игрока, а здоровье игрока вдруг ушло в класс "оружие", также и тут, данные, что отвечают за игру, перешли в другой класс. Ну а так молодцы, хорошее решение (хоть и не ответ)!

Comment: Такие кстати нарушения ответственностей у вас почти во всем коде, например, класс змеи вдруг отвечает за выдачу очков игроку (`_game.GiveScore();`). Тут стоило бы не инжектить зависимости, а наоборот, отдавать наружу данные, например события, что счет игрока изменился, на которое будет подписываться VM и обновлять результат.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я попробовал переделать зависимости грамотно, у меня появилась `GameViewModel`, 3 события и еще много всякого мусора из-за SRP, и вот прямо напрашивается теперь IoC. Приложение стало сложнее по своему устройству. Лучшее - враг хорошего. Наверное, я оставлю как сейчас есть. Решение все-таки не претендует на финальное, а просто показывает технологии.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ теперь похоже на ответ? :)

Comment: Да, IoC хорошая штука, которая сильно облегчает нам жизнь) Ну а так, главное, чтоб вы сами понимали, что здесь нарушение как MVVM, так и SOLID, это конечно лишь набор рекомендаций, но пренебрегать ими не стоит. А ответ да, хотя бы теперь не просто некий проект, который косвенно относится к поставленной задачи автора вопроса, а отвечает на поставленный вопрос. P.S. Минус не мой, а то будете думать, что опять я злой критик, которому все не нравиться.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я точно знаю, что не ваш, это было бы не логично. Просто странно, что если человек посчитал этот ответ бесполезным, то почему мне не объяснил, в чем именно причина, хотя-бы чтобы я смог уведомить, что устранил замечание. Вы то как раз напротив, четко и совершенно верно изложили замечания, которые все по делу. В общем, человек-загадка побывал здесь. Скорее всего кто-то из модераторов за "это не ответ". :( Игра кстати прикольная получилась. :) Сижу играю.

Comment: Спасибо за огромную проделанную работу, сижу, изучаю код! Думаю, на несколько дней зависну с построением, казалось бы, простой змейки)

Comment: Я тоже раньше выкладывал свой код на Яндекс.Диск, но спустя некоторое время понял, что лучше создать репозиторий ответов на гитхабе и все подобные проекты размещать там. Поверьте это и вам удобнее (если надо быстро сделать изменения/исправления) и другим, если им нужно просто просмотреть общую структуру/архитектуру проекта. А в целом, спасибо, было интересно.

Comment: @Bulson я допишу (когда-нибудь) это до проекта, который достоин моего портфолио, то есть с применением всех навыков, что у меня есть, включая IoC и без нарушений, которые озвучил выше EvgeniyZ, тогда и выложу на гитхаб. Да, это здравая мысль, которую я и сам уже думаю.

Comment: Лучшее - враг хорошего. Репозиторий ответов на вопросы из SO не требует идеального кода, все же понимают их предназначение. Зато объем такого репозитория (кол-во ответов и их разнообразие) кое-чего и говорят. Так что полировка готового ответа под каждое замечание грозит тем, что ваш ответ так и не окажется на гитхабе.

Comment: @Bulson верно, подумаю еще над этим.

Comment: Да, сама идея, перемещать сразу после нажатия клавиши, хороша, однако.. это немного ломает логику игры, ведь по факту это ускоряет змейку, т.к. можно быстро вести её наискосок. Нельзя ли как-то ограничить реакцию на клики или что-то такое, чтобы это не было так ощутимо?

Comment: Сам код я во многом списал с видео из этого плейлиста: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLtFURTtAiZImKbj2xUvfoy3qxLX-ncNF6 . Разумеется, немного подогнал под себя. С гитом я ещё не научился пользоваться, прошу простить, вот мой архив с кодом: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jCDdGYFecaa2mGqnQmFR7LW89jExiYWa/view?usp=sharing . Только начал учить WPF, поэтому всё так криво.

Comment: @KoryJaxx ускоряет, а проблема ли это? Игрок никогда не хочет ждать. Когда вы в классическую змейку играли, вы не замечали, что там точно так же это работает? А еще замечали ли вы, что сильнее жмете на кнопки, если (любая) игра реагирует с задержкой? Что вы выберите, вот такое "ускорение", или раздражение игрока? Видео посмотрел краем глаза, насколько же там все сложно, и удивлен, что автор работает с WPF через боль и страдания, по сути я написал то же самое, только у меня кода в 5 раз меньше. А все потому, что я использовал WPF так, как это было задумано разработчиками WPF.

Comment: Это да, у Вас в разы проще, лучше и доступнее.. В змейку играл довольно много, не замечал, что там также, тогда всё хорошо, я неправ)

Comment: @KoryJaxx 5 видео общей длиной более 2 часов. Я наверное весь код с нуля около 1,5 часов писал. Накрутить на все что я написал уровни, масштаб сетки и т.д. - это еще минут 15 от силы. Но дело не в том, чтоябыстропишукод, а в том, что с привязкой данных это делается сильно проще.

Comment: @KoryJaxx вспомнил еще одну фишку, добавьте в разметку окна `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"`, я выше в ответе в XAML разметке показал, куда. Тогда линии отрисовки на экране станут более четкими. Покрасивее будет. Раньше почему-то не обратил на это внимание.

Comment: А чего бы код на github не положить и там релиз сделать, в релиз бинарники?

Comment: @tym32167 Справедливое замечание, но так как я не разработчик, гитхаб у меня пустой, и пользоваться всякими фичами гита мне еще надо учиться, знаю только коммит, пуш и пулл. :) Пока то лень, то некогда. Прижмёт - конечно освою. Если желаете - можете себе сбэкапить в коллекцию, я только за, и с удовольствием заменю ссылку для скачивания на ваш репозиторий. Или сразу можете отредактировать пост в любое время.

Comment: `но так как я не разработчик` wat? так, это мне надо переварить или свою жизнь переосмыслить после таких заявлений :)