# Полю "MainWindow.propertyToAnimate" нигде не присваивается значение, поэтому оно всегда будет иметь значение по умолчанию null

Tags: c#, wpf

При запуске программы , запускается а после того как нажимаешь на кнопку старта, выдаёт данную ошибку:
Полю "MainWindow.propertyToAnimate" нигде не присваивается значение, поэтому оно всегда будет иметь значение по умолчанию null.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq;
using System.Text; using System.Threading.Tasks; using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls; using System.Windows.Data; using
System.Windows.Documents; using System.Windows.Input; using
System.Windows.Media; using System.Windows.Media.Imaging; using
System.Windows.Navigation; using System.Windows.Shapes; using
System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace WpfApp1 {
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window {
        Random random = new Random();
        private PropertyPath propertyToAnimate;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Duration Duration { get; private set; }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddEnemy();
        }

        private void AddEnemy()
        {
             ContentControl enemy = new ContentControl();
             enemy.Template = Resources["EnemyTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
             AnimateEnemy(enemy, 0 , playArea.ActualWidth - 100, "(Canvas.Left)");
             AnimateEnemy(enemy, random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100),
                  random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100), "(Canvas.Top)");
             playArea.Children.Add(enemy);
        }

        private void AnimateEnemy(ContentControl enemy, double from, double to, string properetyToAnimate)
        {
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard() { AutoReverse = true, RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
            {
                double From = from;
                double To = to;
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(4, 6)));
            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, enemy);
            PropertyPath propertyToAnimate = this.propertyToAnimate;
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, propertyToAnimate);
            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
            storyboard.Begin();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Почему вы не используете XAML?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Answer (score 1):

[Метод](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/cc672995(v=vs.95)) не должен принимать null параметры, а полю *propertyToAnimate* у вас, судя по всему нигде не присваивается значение, о чем и говорит ошибка.

Comment: Скажи пожалуйста, какое значение я могу ему присвоить и как, что бы всё заработало?
Заранее благодарю тебя.

Comment: @Алексей Путь к тому свойсту элемента, которое хотите анимировать, если я правильно понимаю. Учите WPF и XAML, посмотрите пример из ссылки на документацию.

Comment: @Алексей У вас в метод `AnimateEnemy` передается как раз этот путь в виде строки `properetyToAnimate`. Соответственно в метод `SetTargetProperty` передаете `new PropertyPath(properetyToAnimate)`

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы!
Починил
а насчёт WPF и XAML, я как раз и занимаюсь  их изучением на данный момент.
Ещё раз всем спасибо!

Comment: @Алексей [пример очень простой игры в WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567), без анимаций, но показан именно тот способ, который является самым удобным для WPF. Разберите его, лишним не будет.