# Генерация Canvas через код в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, wpf-canvas

Создаю игру Альтернативные Крестики-нолики (81 игровая ячейка) на WPF, столкнулся с проблемой генерации ячеек через Canvas на игровом поле, генерирую их через код.
Чтобы разместить ячейки внутри мини-Canvas наследовал свой класс SmallGameArea от Canvas, и добавил поле Cells, но их заполнить не удалось, т.к. возникает исключение Null Reference при создании ячеек внутри поля

Просьба подсказать решение данной проблемы, потому что вариант у меня только костыльный, т.к. мне нужно отталкиваться от размерности мини-поля, придется добавить еще одну ссылку на SmallGameArea со значениями Width и Height вот так:

```
this._smallGameArea =
                        new SmallGameArea
                        {                            
                            Width = (this._bigAreaCanvas.Width / 3) - 3.0,
                            Height = (this._bigAreaCanvas.Height / 3) - 3.0                            
                            
                        };
                    this._smallGameArea =
                        new SmallGameArea
                        {
                            Name = "smallField_" + smallArea._coordinateX.ToString() + "_" + smallArea._coordinateY.ToString(),
                            Width = (this._bigAreaCanvas.Width / 3) - 3.0,
                            Height = (this._bigAreaCanvas.Height / 3) - 3.0,
                            Background = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#a4ba8f"),
                            Cells = FillPlayingCells(this._smallGameArea)
                        };
```

Код MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Width="800" Height="800" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Canvas x:Name="_bigAreaCanvas" Width="800" Height="800" Margin="5">
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

Код MainWindow.cs

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FillPlayingArea();
        }

        private void FillPlayingArea()
        {
            // Задаем размерность игрового поля
            var size = 3;
            // Очищаем игровое поле от элементов
            this._bigAreaCanvas.Children.Clear();
            // Заполняем Backend данными
            BigArea bigArea = new BigArea();

            var bc = new BrushConverter();

            double bigAreaWidth = (this._bigAreaCanvas.Width / 3) - 3.0;
            double bigAreaHeight = (this._bigAreaCanvas.Height / 3) - 3.0;

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    var smallArea = ((SmallArea)bigArea.playField[i, j]);                   


                    this._smallGameArea =
                        new SmallGameArea
                        {
                            Name = "smallField_" + smallArea._coordinateX.ToString() + "_" + smallArea._coordinateY.ToString(),
                            Width = (this._bigAreaCanvas.Width / 3) - 3.0,
                            Height = (this._bigAreaCanvas.Height / 3) - 3.0,
                            Background = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#a4ba8f"),
                            Cells = FillPlayingCells(this._smallGameArea)
                        };
                    
                    this._bigAreaCanvas.Children.Add(this._smallGameArea);
                    
                    // Размещаем элементы внутри основного Canvas
                    Canvas.SetLeft(this._smallGameArea, i * this._bigAreaCanvas.Width / size - 2.0);
                    Canvas.SetTop(this._smallGameArea, j * this._bigAreaCanvas.Height / size - 2.0);
                }
            }
        }
        
        private List<GameCell> FillPlayingCells (SmallGameArea smallGameArea) // object[,] playCells, double smallCanvasWidth, double smallCanvasHeight
        {
            List<GameCell> gameCells = new List<GameCell>();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    var bc = new BrushConverter();
                    
                    gameCells.Add(
                        new GameCell
                        {
                            Name = "cell_" + i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString(),
                            Width = smallGameArea.Width / 3 - 2.0,
                            Height = smallGameArea.Height / 3 - 2.0,
                            Background = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#73a9ff"),
                            coordX = i,
                            coordY = j
                        }
                    );
                }
            }

                    return gameCells;
        }
```

Код класса SmallGameArea.cs

```
 public class SmallGameArea : Canvas
    {
        private List<GameCell> _cells;
        public List<GameCell> Cells 
        { 
            get { return _cells; } 
            set 
            {                
                _cells = value;                
               
                foreach (var cell in _cells)
                {
                    this.Children.Add(cell);
                    // Размещаем игровые ячейки внутри каждого мини-поля Canvas
                    Canvas.SetLeft(cell, cell.coordX * this.Height / 3 - 5.0);
                    Canvas.SetTop(cell, cell.coordY * this.Width / 3 - 5.0);                
                }

            }
        }
```

Просьба подсказать по дополнительной проблеме с оповещением ViewModel через форму, реализовал отправку активного объекта ячейки в VM, но только по статичным координатам(BigGameArea.MiniAreasList[1].SmallAreaCellsList[1].Coordinates), как можно отслеживать координаты. которые выбрал пользователь на форме и динамически подставлять в код Xaml чтобы передать в VM? Или подход неправильный?

Код XAML

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding BigGameArea.MiniAreasList}" HorizontalAlignment ="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SmallAreaCellsList}">
                        <ItemsControl.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightBlue"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="IndianRed"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                        <!--<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>-->
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ItemsControl.Style>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button CommandParameter="{Binding Path=BigGameArea.MiniAreasList[1].SmallAreaCellsList[1]}" Command="{Binding DoTurnCommandVm}" Cursor="Pen">
                                    <Button.DataContext>
                                        <vm:MainViewModel/>
                                    </Button.DataContext>
                                    <Button.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightBlue"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CellState}" Value="Empty">
                                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value=""/>
                                                </DataTrigger>-->
                                                <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding CellState}" Value="Cross">
                                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource CrossImg}"/>                                                    
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding CellState}" Value="Zero">
                                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource ZeroImg}"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>                                        
                                    </Button.Style>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3" Margin="8"></UniformGrid>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></WrapPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Код MainViewModel.cs

```
 public class MainViewModel
    {

        public BigGameAreaModel BigGameArea { get; set; }       

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            // Создаем игровое поле размерностью 3 х 3
            BigGameArea = new BigGameAreaModel(3);
        }
       
        private ICommand _doTurnVm;
        public ICommand DoTurnCommandVm => _doTurnVm ??= new RelayCommand(parameter =>
        {
            var activeCell = (CellModel)parameter;            
        });        
    }
```

Выкладываю ссылку на рабочий проект:
https://github.com/Gosha94/TicTacToeGame/tree/master/TicTacToeGame.WPF

Comment: Вам здесь не нужен канвас. [Вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567) можно создать игровое поле любого размера. Там по нему змейка бегает, но можно в ячейке что угодно нарисовать. Разберите пример, он очень похож на то что вы пишете. Возможно там для вас много нового, но вы хотя-бы попятайтесь. Это вам точно поможет.

Comment: Самая основная разница у вас в том, что там игровое поле не взаимодействует с мышью, а у вас наверное взаимодействует. Собственно вместо бордера можно засунуть в ячейку кнопку и привязать ее к команде, расположеной во вьюмодели. А контент кнопки привязать к состоянию ячейки игрового поля, например 0 - пусто, 1 - крестик, 2 - нолик. В игровой логике же вообще забыть про интерфейс и работать с игровым полем, например вы напишите `area[10,15].State = 1`, и на экране появится крестик, сам. В этом и есть смысл привязки данных - писать простой код. Если смогу, попробую написать простой пример.

Comment: Примерный принцип понял, завяз на визуализции поля, после генерации поля также планировал использовать принцип MVVM, а генерацию поля и проверку побед вынести в отдельную dll

Comment: Так здесь как раз MVVM - для всего. Привязки данных - везде. А поле - это просто вложенные массивы `[][]`, можно обертку с двумерным индексатором прикрутить `[,]` для удобства.

Comment: Еще один вопрос, подскажите пожалуйста, пытаюсь оповестить ViewModel о координатах нажатой кнопки, <Button CommandParameter="{Binding Path=BigGameArea.MiniAreasList[2].SmallAreaCellsList[1].Coordinates}" Command="{Binding DoTurnCommandVm}" Cursor="Pen"> Пока сделал привязку данных напрямую к конкретному полю, но как динамически определить, ячейка с какими координатами была нажата на форме?

Comment: Дополните вопрос про привязку кнопки, добавьте актуальный код. Задача простая, но пока непонятно, чего вы хотите добиться и каким образом. Покажите вьюмодель и разметку в вопросе. К собеседнику в комментах обращаться вот так @Georgy, тегать не нужно если обращение к автору поста.

Comment: @aepot, понял, обновил, спасибо за инфо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не так давно я писал [Змейку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567), покажу простой пример реализации игрового поля с кнопками на базе того ответа.

Если нужны детали реализации, что как и почему и что такое MVVM и привязки - почитайте в Змейке, здесь же я приведу только код.

#### INotifyPropertyChanged и ICommand

Вспомогательные классы. Первый для привязок, второй для команд.

```cs
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

#### Данные

Ячейка игрового поля может быть в 3 состояниях - пустая, крестик и нолик, опишу ее вот так.

**Data.cs**

```cs
public class Cell : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private CellState _state;

    public CellState State
    {
        get => _state;
        set
        {
            _state = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public enum CellState
{
    Empty,
    Cross,
    Zero
}
```

#### Основная логика приложения

Далее, реализую `MainViewModel`.

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<List<Cell>> _arena;
    private ICommand _areaCommand;
    private ICommand _newGameCommand;

    private CellState _turn; // чей ход

    public List<List<Cell>> Arena // игровое поле
    {
        get => _arena;
        set
        {
            _arena = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand NewGameCommand => _newGameCommand ??= new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        NewGame();
    });

    public ICommand AreaCommand => _areaCommand ??= new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (parameter is Cell cell)
        {
            cell.State = _turn;
            _turn = _turn == CellState.Cross ? CellState.Zero : CellState.Cross;
        }
    }, parameter => parameter is Cell cell && cell.State == CellState.Empty);

    private void NewGame()
    {
        _turn = CellState.Cross;
        int width = 8;
        int height = 8;
        List<List<Cell>> arena = new List<List<Cell>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            List<Cell> row = new List<Cell>();
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                row.Add(new Cell());
            }
            arena.Add(row);
        }
        Arena = arena;
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        NewGame();
    }
}
```

Гвоздь программы здесь - я вообще не работаю с координатами на поле, мне это не за чем. А работает это так - вы жмете на кнопку, а кнопка привязана к данным типа `Cell`, собственно это и есть экземпляр нужной ячейки, где совершен код. Зачем нам искать ее по коодинатам, если ее уже нашел юзер мышкой и прямо буквально ткнул меня носом в эту `Cell`. Я просто передаю ее в команду как `CommandParameter`, и готово. :)

Теперь прикручу вьюмодель к окну.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

#### Интерфейс

Много общего со змейкой. Обратите внимание, я не использую картинки, а вместо этого использую векторную графику, то есть рисую Крестик или Нолик простыми контолами в шаблонах, а шаблоны переключаю с помощью триггеров, которые реагируют на `CellState`.

```xml
<Window x:Class="TicTacToeWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TicTacToeWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" 
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Margin="5" Padding="15,0" Command="{Binding NewGameCommand}" Content="New Game"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Arena}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Focusable="False">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" Focusable="False">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Width="38" Height="38" BorderThickness="1" Focusable="False" Command="{Binding DataContext.AreaCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                    <Button.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="CadetBlue"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Cross">
                                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                                        <Setter.Value>
                                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                                    <Path Data="M5,5 L31,31 M5,31 L31,5" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3"/>
                                                                </Border>
                                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                                        </Setter.Value>
                                                    </Setter>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Zero">
                                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                                        <Setter.Value>
                                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                                    <Ellipse Width="30" Height="30" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="Black"/>
                                                                </Border>
                                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                                        </Setter.Value>
                                                    </Setter>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Button.Style>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Суть решения в том, что дано пустое поле 8 на 8, юзер тыкает мышкой в пустую ячейку, и если там ничего нет, появляется крестик, следующий тык в другую ячейку делает нолик, потом снова крестик и т.д. Пока не заполнятся все ячейки. Кнопка **New Game** просто пересоздает игру.

Готово.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дам подсказку, если вам нужно например "перечеркнуть" линию визуально, чтобы показать причину окончания игры, не перечеркивайте, вы можете в `Cell` добавить еще одно свойство, например `public bool Winner {...}`, а в разметке на этот `Winner` привязать цвет кисти для крестика и нолика, через триггер, например если `true`, то красный, если нет - черный.

Игровую логику, думаю, теперь вам не составит труда к этому прикрутить.