# Как изменить отрисовку виджетов в WinUi 3?

Tags: c#, winui3

Я изучаю возможности графической библиотеки `WinUi 3`. И меня в частности интересует возможность изменять отображение виджетов (контролов, вьюх иными словами). Но бегло просмотрев документацию я удивился что не смог быстро найти поддержку кастомной отрисовки виждетов. Даже смотрел дизассемблированные библиотеки (реализацию `Control`, `FrameworkElement`, `Button` и тд) - методов отрисовки нигде не увидел. Модель рендеринга не понятна, как библиотека отрисовывает контролы и как мне можно было переопределить отрисовку самому?

Comment: Windows App SDK? Я бы посоветовл дождаться релиза, слишком много изменений будет в версии 1.0, а вообще там XAML. Система очень похожая на WPF должна быть, типа переопределить Style, но я сам пока руками не трогал эту библиотеку, наверняка не скажу. Хотя, [вот пример](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/tree/main/Samples/Windowing/cs-winui/SampleApp). Ничего переопределять не нужно, просто задайте Style как в WPF.

Comment: @aepot меня именно интересует возможность создания кастомных контролов с кастомной отрисовкой (или даже польностью переопределения внешнего вида кнопок). где отрисовка может быть довольно нестандартная с возможностями сложных безье курв и тд(я про то что боюсь переопределение стилей и xaml тут не помогут).

Comment: Кастомный контрол можно  собрать из чего угодно. Рисованием в Winui3 занимается DirectX. Некоторые API DX доступны для использования в C#. Если вам нужны мощные кривые, есть `Path` в XAML разметке, любые закорючки можно в векторе рисовать, можно хоть SVG файл подключить. Вот [шахматные фигуры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1255542/373567), нарисованные XAML разметкой, чистый вектор. Данные выдернуты из SVG. В общем, подход Winforms, где рисовали с помощью GDI+ в коде, здесь неэффективен. Изучайте XAML. Хотя и в C# создать `new Path { Data = ... };` не проблема.

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/17.3.php

Comment: @aepot в WPF можно более эффективно отрисовать тысячи линий напрямую в Visual обьект (это сериализация инструкций для отрисовки). в WinUi для этого придется использовать класс Line (наследник Shape). Эта абстракция стоит дорого (каждый обьект аллоцирует память в хипе) (особенно если у меня будет большая коллекция таких обьектов)

Comment: Если вам нужен супербыстрый рендер - используйте DirectX напрямую. WinUI 3 здесь вообще не при чем тогда. Но все же рассмотрите возможность использовать Path, не думаю, что это медленнее, чем GDI+ в Winforms. DX API - штука не простая. В любом случае никаких событий или методов отрисовки в контролах WPF/Winui3 нет и никогда не было. Контролы строятся на основе графических примитивов, которые рисуются глубоко на низком уровне внутри нативных библиотек, интегрированных с DirectX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В плане кастомной отрисовки виджетов WinUI3 радикально отличается от WPF, методов типа OnRender, которые позволяли менять отрисовку в WinUI3 нет и вряд ли в версии 1.0 они появятся.

В принципе, сейчас единственный путь - использовать DirectWrite и его реализацию под WinUI3 DWriteCore

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/dwritecore

Но это сильно низкоуровневый путь, не очень удобный.

P.S. небольшое дополнение от разработчиков WinUi (https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6050)

> WinUI has largely focused on the user interface of an application rather than being a renderer for application content, and complex custom rendering is less common for the user interface. More capabilities have been added in recent years, but even those focus on shapes and paths. Note that there are both XAML elements for Shape and Path as well as Composition primitives via CompositionSpriteShape, which moves the shape handling/rendering down to the composition layer. If the rendering capabilities you're looking for here are shapes/paths, then perhaps Win2D is a better fit?

Comment: Да, вы полностью правы. немного дополню ваш ответ если вы не против (я задавал этот вопрос в winui communit call)

Comment: Win2d или SkiaSharp тоже для определенных случаев варианты. Win2d хорош для UWP, но для Winui3 пока сырой какой-то