# Реверс массива не отображается в ListBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, reverse

У меня есть задача - при нажатии на белый квадратик на вьюшке должна перевернуться доска и координаты слева и снизу.
Итак, координаты слева находятся в листбоксе и хранятся в листе Ranks. При нажатии на квадратик происходит реверс массива (сравните значения в 1 пункте на картинке и во втором во время отладки), но во вьюшке этот реверс не отображается (числа попросту не меняются). Я решил провести эксперимент (пункт 3 на картинке) и просто создать новый лист с перевернутыми значениями координат, при нажатии на квадратик они действительно отобразились так, как должны, в обратном порядке. Также пробовал с ObservableCollection, проблема сохраняется.

Полный код для координат слева:

```
    private List<int> ranks;
    public List<int> Ranks {
        get { return ranks; }
        set { ranks = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
```

в конструкторе:

```
Ranks = new List<int> { 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
```

в команде:

```
get {
    return changeColorCommand ??
          (changeColorCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
           {
              Ranks.Reverse();
              Files.Reverse();
              //Board.Cells.Reverse();
              CurrentColorBoard = CurrentColorBoard == CellColor.White ? CellColor.Black : CellColor.White;
           }));
}
```

Вьюшка:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxRanks"
         Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
         Style="{StaticResource ListBoxCoordinatesRanks}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Ranks}"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
 </ListBox>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В случае с `List<>`, коллекция не оповещает о том, что в ней были какие-либо изменения, из-за чего View не обновляет. В случае с `ObservableCollection<>`, у него попросту нету метода `.Reverse()`, он есть у `LINQ`, а тот в свою очередь возвращает вам новую коллекцию, а не меняет исходную. В любом случае, вам надо либо пересоздавать коллекцию с перевернутыми данными (например `Ranks = new (Ranks.Reverse<int>());`), либо явно вызывать `OnPropertyChanged("Ranks")` после реверса, что оповестит UI.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, странно, пробовал `Ranks = new ObservableCollection<int>(Ranks.Reverse());` до этого, не работало (сейчас все ок), а вот OnPropertyChanged("Ranks") вообще не сработало. Однако почему при создании нового объекта листа в команде (на картинке 3 пункт) данные меняются, если коллекция не оповещает об изменениях (или это касается только изменения в уже созданном объекте?)

Comment: Смотрите, вот у вас есть свойство `public Type Name {get; set;}`, вы его привязали и вдруг в коде решили написать `Name = ...;`, но изменений вдруг не видите, почему? Правильно, свойство не реализует `INPC`, как только свойство начнет вызывать метод обновления, UI сразу начнет получать свежие данные. У вас, свойство `Ranks` вызывает `OnPropertyChanged()`, то есть, при `Ranks = new();`, UI подхватит **новую** коллекцию. НО, если вы сделаете `Ranks.Add(...);`, то изменений не будет, почему? Верно, у данной коллекции нету `INotifyCollectionChanged`, которое оповещает об изменениях **внутри**.

Comment: В c# `INotifyCollectionChanged`, по умолчанию, реализуют всего 2 коллекции `ObservableCollection<>` и `BindingList<>`, вот если используете их, то все добавления и удаления объектов будут отображаться в UI. Если же меняется конкретно значение свойства, то это `INotifyCollectionChanged`, вызов его методов. `OnPropertyChanged("Ranks") вообще не сработало` - скорей всего не там вызвали, без кода не скажу. `данные меняются` - пояснил выше, у вас свойство `Ranks` вызывает INPC.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ все сделал и все работает как надо, правда пришлось реализовывать INPC в моделях, но это не страшно, MVVM пока неизведанный лес, так что спасибо за помощь и объяснения :)

Comment: В тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1255542/373567, у меня бы вопрос решился простой реализацией INPC на Numbers и Letters. Либо вообще одно INPC свойство типа bool, а магию всю в XAML на тригерах творить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно проще. Строка - это тоже коллекция.

```
private string ranks;
public string Ranks
{
    get => ranks;
    set
    {
        ranks = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Дальше просто

```
// туда
Ranks = "12345678";

// сюда
Ranks = "87654321";
```

А в UI то же самое

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Ranks}"/>
```

С буквами то же самое. И не потребуется никакой возни со списками.

`ListBox` вам не нужен, если вы не собираетесь делать эти цифры кликабельными. `ItemsControl` практически без стилей будет выглядеть как вам надо. Переопределите `<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>`, положите туда `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>` и получится горизонтально, а если надо масштабироваться, то `<UniformGrid>` сойдет. Чтобы задать размеры ячейкам, можно использовать простой стиль `<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>`.

- [C# WPF Шахматы, отрисовка доски](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1255183/373567)

Comment: спасибо, да, листбокс использовал потому что не знал как по-другому можно сделать)