# WPF - StackPanel рисует не убираемый Border

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я заметил, что используя DockPanel и пихая в один из его элементов StackPanel (как на скрине), я вижу обводку этого самого StackPanel, однако у которого нет Border и BorderThickness. Теперь я хз как ее убрать, очень сильно режет глаза.
Если что-то не так понял, простите

Вот метод класса Window, в котором устанавливается весь UI (скрин 2):

```
public void SetLayout()
        {
            Content = mainDock;

            leftStackPanel.Background = Styles.SuperDark.Color;
            mainDock.Children.Add(leftStackPanel);
            DockPanel.SetDock(leftStackPanel, Dock.Left);

            addObjectButton.Click += delegate { HubModel.CreateObject(); };
            leftStackPanel.Children.Add(addObjectButton);

            mainDock.Children.Add(rightDock);
            DockPanel.SetDock(rightDock, Dock.Right);

            rightDock.Children.Add(rightTopTextBlock);
            DockPanel.SetDock(rightTopTextBlock, Dock.Top);

            objectsStack.Background = Styles.Dark.Color;
            rightDock.Children.Add(objectsStack);
            DockPanel.SetDock(objectsStack, Dock.Top);
        }
```

Comment: Если вы говорите про XAML, то наверно воспроизводящий пример надо добавлять в вопрос, верно? Как вот допустим мне воспроизвести эту проблему?

Comment: Сейчас обновлю, однако view делаю в C#, а не XAML

Comment: Ну тогда ерундой страдаете, говорю вам сразу, ибо WPF это не про создание дизайна в C# коде. У вас вообще не должно быть в коде работы с контролами, дизайном и так далее. Дизайн это XAML, а данные это C#, вывод всего через привязки.

Comment: Я недавно занимаюсь программированием, но уже сейчас знаю, что какой интерфейс можно создать в XAML, такой можно создать и в C#. Какая разница, если свойства StackPanel оба языка видят одинаково? Мне лишь интересно почему StackPanel рисует обводки, я не собираюсь с вами спорить, какой язык вам больше нравится для написания интерфейсов. Если не знаете что ответить, зачем вообще пишете

Comment: ну можно было посоветовать изменить шаблон, но видимо не в твоем случае...

Comment: @piscopancer к сожалению, вынужден сказать вам, что вы не правы. Xaml и код c# должны быть разделы. Для этого есть специальный Паттерн - mvvm.

Comment: @piscopancer Если считаете [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbJxF.png) минимальным, самодостаточным примером, который мы просто берем и вставляем, то ошибаетесь, я вот чет не очень хочу идти и все контролы там создавать, с нужными именами. `Какая разница, если свойства StackPanel оба языка видят одинаково?` - 1. Удобство. 2. Производительность. Вот допустим вы захотите сделать список сотрудников, который должен автоматически обновляться в UI, ваши действия? Предположу, что будете создавать циклом контролы под каждого человека. Ну а я, просто добавлю объект человека в коллекцию, не затрагивая UI

Comment: Используйте XAML, он проще и эффективнее. И опытные разрабы более вероятно помогут здесь именно с XAML, потому что опыт имеется. На шарпе UI никто не пилит, поэтому вряд-ли кто что-либо подскажет. Но если вы насильно выбрали свой путь через шарп, никто не против, но идти по нему придется самому.

Comment: @aepot может я не понимаю, но когда в XAML есть "биндинги" ужасные. Если я в C# просто назвал свои поля и пишу это как:

string randomText = "he";
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Text = randomText;

Если я поменяю или забуду название полей в C# - ничего страшного, компилятор подскажет, но в XAML он просто не работает. Сколько не смотрел обзоров по XAML, все вручную по памяти пишут string названия поля. Неудобно

Comment: В XAML тоже работает IntelliSense, подсказывает названия свойств. Просто дизайнеру надо подсказать тип вьюмодели `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MyViewModel}"`, гайдов полно. Короч, пока вы не назвали ни одного реального недостатка. А биндинги ужасные только до момента узнавания как они работают, потом сразу прекрасные становятся. Они даже в Winforms прекрасные (да, они там есть!), даже если в C# их писать в WPF. Идёте по пути наименьшего сопротивления, а в результате сидите в сильно ограниченных рамках и пишете раз в 5 больше кода, чем нужно.

Comment: Сейчас напишу ответ, но конечно не совсем тот, который вы ожидаете, но проблему обозначу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не бортик, это не точное попадание в пиксель. То есть вы задаете координаты, но контрол на полпикселя может не точно отрисоваться там где нужно. Для того чтобы разметить статическую сетку интерфейса приложения, надо использовать `Grid`. При этом сами контролы позиционировать от ячеек этого грида, а не от левого верхнего угла окна. Тогда этих линий просвечивающих не будет. Другими словами, это не бортик, это просвечивает белый фон окна через нечеткие границы. Решение - отказаться от пиксельного позиционирования блоков в окне.

Давайте погадаю по фотографии, то есть напишу тоже самое что у вас на скриншотах.

Будет 2 окна - `MainWindow` и `EditWindow`, второе буду использовать как диалог.

#### Разметка и код основного окна

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfAppDemoBindings.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppDemoBindings"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Style="{StaticResource DarkWindowStyle}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="PlusButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource FlatButtonStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Margin="3" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="2 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                                <ContentPresenter Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="#23192b">
            <Button Content="+" Style="{StaticResource PlusButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EditWindow window = new EditWindow();
        window.Owner = this;
        if (window.ShowDialog() ?? false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(window.Data.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

В разметке можно увидеть, что я использую какие-то стили, которые не описаны прямо в этом окне. Я сделал их общими для всего приложения, чтобы в каждом окне их не повторять.

Они расположены в **App.xaml**.

```xml
<Application x:Class="WpfAppDemoBindings.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppDemoBindings"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}" x:Key="DarkWindowStyle">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2e2035"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="FlatButtonStyle">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#564a6a"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseDirectlyOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#665a7a"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Данные

Здесь есть работа с данными, поэтому я создам класс для данных и чтобы управлять данными из кода через биндинги в окне, я реализую `INotifyPropertyChanged` с помощью вот такого простого класса, его просто надо добавить впроект:

**NotifyPropertyChanged.cs**

```
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Теперь я от него отнаследуюсь и реализую свойства для класса с данными

**FormData.cs**

```
public class FormData : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    private string features;

    public string Name
    {
        get => name; 
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string Features
    {
        get => features;
        set
        {
            features = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        Name = "";
        Features = "";
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Name = {Name}, Features = {Features}";
    }
}
```

#### Окно редактирвоания

**EditWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfAppDemoBindings.EditWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppDemoBindings"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Create object" SizeToContent="Height" Width="500" Style="{StaticResource DarkWindowStyle}" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" Background="#23192b" ResizeMode="NoResize"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:FormData}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#adb5bd"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2e2035"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource FlatButtonStyle}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Fill the information" Margin="0" Padding="20" TextAlignment="Center" Background="#23192b"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Name"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Features" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Features}"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="#2e2035">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Content="Reset" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Create" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Я здесь не стал использовать вертикалюную `StackPanel` только потому что мне захотелось, чтобы текстбоксы были одинаковой ширины. Использовать для этого `Grid` - проще всего.

**EditWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class EditWindow : Window
{
    public FormData Data { get; }

    public EditWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Data = new FormData();
        DataContext = Data; // указываю, где Binding в XAML будет брать данные
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Data.Reset();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = true;
        Close();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нажать **Reset**, текстбоксы очистятся. Если нажать **Create**, то диалог закроется и появится вот такой `MessageBox`:

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, собственно и всё. Никаких фантомных бортиков у меня нет. И оно при этом не только хорошо выглядит, но и работает. Если вы начнете знакомиться с биндингами, обратите внимание на `ItemsControl` и `ObservableCollection`. Примеров решения разноплановых задач с их использованием даже среди [моих ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A373567+%5Bwpf%5D) здесь очень много.

[Ссылка на проект на Яндекс.Диске](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/r7nQOqgAHjMIzA)

Comment: (⊙_⊙) ... У меня слов нет наверное

Comment: Мне так в универе не объясняют, как вы

Comment: @piscopancer чтобы принять ответ, вы можете поставить зеленую галочку слева от него. А если почитаете хотя-бы вскользь все остальные мои ответы, то сами сможете препода учить писать код под WPF :) WPF - это про XAML, биндинги и MVVM. Потому что это самые мощные средства писать вменяемый софт именно под WPF.

Comment: Тут столько XAML и всего непонятного, я не поленюсь это все прочитать, хочу верить, вам за этот ответ заплатили, а если не платили, то пусть снизойдет на вас небесное счастье

Comment: @piscopancer мне не жалко полчаса, чтобы написать такой простой проект, вот смотрите еще большие примеры - [змейка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567), [шахматы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1255542/373567), [многостраничный интерфейс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567), [привязки данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1115342/373567)