# Возможно ли добавить обработчик Click += OnClick/*или аналог*/ в объявление new Button

Tags: c#, wpf

Интересует, возможно ли заменить `((window.Content as Grid).Children[0] as Button).Click += OnClick;` на что то, непосредственно в коде объявления кнопки

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SimpleGame
{
    public class MainFrame : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            Window window = new Window()
            {
                Title = "SimpleGame",
                Width = 1024,
                Height = 768,
                Content = new Grid()
                {
                    Tag = "grid",
                    Children =
                    {
                        new Button()
                        {
                            Tag = "StarGame",
                            Content = "Start Game",
                            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
                            //например сюда что то вроде
                            // Click += OnClick не работает
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            ((window.Content as Grid).Children[0] as Button).Click += OnClick;
            window.Show();
        }
        
        void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас вообще не должно быть этого кода в WPF проекте. Где привязки? Где XAML?

Comment: XAML не является обязательным для WPF - [Пруф](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.window?view=net-5.0), хотя если подскажете, как сделать динамически поле 25*25(625) кнопок с паттерном MVVM, буду благодарен, так как с биндингами не очень дружу

Comment: @Jlekcop `XAML не является обязательным для WPF` - по рельсам тоже не обязательно ездить на поезде, можно пешком. Хотите поле игровое в MVVM - [пожалуйста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1239671/373567), [вот еще](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1255542/373567), и [на закуску](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567). Я думаю, нет смысла пилить пример, разберетесь же с тем что есть?

Comment: @Jlekcop И что показывает ваш "пруф"? То, что можно? Да, можно. Но задайте тогда себе вопрос: а зачем вообще вы сидите на WPF? Идите вон WinForms используйте, там контролы в коде лепить в порядке вещей (и то, от этого уже давно люди отошли). WPF вам дает мощнейший инструментарий в виде XAML разметки, а вы его просто игнорируете. Хорошо это? Ну, решать вам, если для вас это норма - дерзайте. Только потом не жалуйтесь на потери производительности, на кашу в коде и так далее. Примеры вам дали выше, могу еще добавить [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820820/220553). Все зависит от ваших задач.

Comment: @Jlekcop Касательно вашего вопроса, в C#, подписка на события не задается при инициализации, она задается уже для готового объекта. Вынесите `Button` отдельно, как `var button = new Button(){...};` и подпишитесь на что вам надо `button.Click += OnClick;`, ну а в `Children` заносите ссылку на ранее созданный объект (`Children = { button }`). Но повторюсь - этому не место в WPF!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Спасибо за ответ, его и искал, а по поводу "WPF вам дает мощнейший инструментарий в виде XAML разметки" я же не спорю, но вы тоже его на седьмой день освоили?

Comment: @Jlekcop Знаете, я когда только начал изучать C#, сразу полез в декстоп программирование, выбрав сразу себе WPF. И не поверите, я не обходил стороной XAML, я писал там нужные мне контролы и обращался к ним через код (по именам), да, я не знал тогда что такое привязки, но четко понимал для чего нужен XAML и где создавать все кнопочки. Так что для меня до сих пор является большой загадкой: почему люди, используя WPF, всячески обходят стороной очевидную вещь по типу XAML. Да я даже больше скажу, создавать контролы через код - сложнее. Короче, учитесь сразу правильным вещам, а не ищите "пруфы".

Comment: XAML - ужасен и чудовищен. Обратите внимание: это критика замла, а не WPF! Но есть альтернативы. Например, [AMMY](http://www.ammyui.com/). Обсуждение можно почитать [здесь](https://www.rsdn.org/forum/nemerle/6671124.all)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov AMMY сделано умныии фронтендерами, кто всю жизнь пилил вьюхи под JS фреймворки. А XAML норм, он богаче и удобнее JSON'а. Но на вкус и цвет...