# C# WPF Пишу тетрис для учебной цели. Как связать Grid с матрицей?

Tags: c#, wpf

Максимально упрощаю условия для более-понятного изречения.

Есть двумерная булевская матрица, определяющая игровое поле. Единица – ячейка занята, ноль – свободна.

```
bool[,] gameField = new bool[20, 10];
```

Как я представление будет выглядеть представление:

1. Будет контейнер Grid с 20-ю RowDefinition и 10-ю ColumnDefinition;
2. Внутри каждой ячейки будет находиться Rectangle (Fill="Black" - если соответствующий элемент в матрице = 1 и "White", если = 0);
3. Для получения и задания цвета отдельного Rectangle, я могу использовать свойство Tag=Point(x, y).

Проблема в следующем: как с помощью INotifyPropertyChanged могу я могу организовать привязку булевой матрицы и ячеек Grid'а? Или мне стоит как-то по другому архитектурно построить представление?

Comment: Вам нужен не INotifyPropertyChanged, а INotifyCollectionChanged, т. е. ObservableCollection, т. к измерения два, берите ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<bool>>. Можно и INotifyPropertyChanged обойтись (массивом), но получится очень неэффективно — вам придется на каждое изменение целиком массив заменять на новый, иначе wpf не увидит изменений

Comment: Ну и вместо bool используйте сразу класс, все что нужно для определения ячейки — складывайте в него, цвет и все что ещё может понадобиться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ранее я показывал всякие приемы по реализации игр в WPF ([1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1255542/373567), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1239671/373567)), покажу еще раз.

Для реализации буду использовать шаблон проектирования MVVM, но рассказывать про него не буду. Если интересно, можно по ссылкам выше посмотреть. Здесь будет только код и краткие объяснения по нему.

#### Вспомогательные классы

Просто добавьте их в проект.

```cs
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        => (_execute, _canExecute) = (execute, canExecute);

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter)
        => _execute(parameter);
}
```

#### Данные

В качестве данных буду использовать тот же `bool`, но чтобы интерфейс мог автоматически обновлять себя при изменении состояния ячейки игрового поля, нужна реализация `INotifyPropertyChanged`, собственно она уже есть в одном из классов выше. Просто использую ее.

```cs
public class Cell : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _state;

    public bool State
    {
        get => _state;
        set
        {
            _state = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); // сообщает интерфейсу что надо обновить эту ячейку
        }
    }
}
```

Игровое поле - это своего рода мутант, который смотрит одним концом в интерфейс, другим к вам для удобного использования в коде.

```cs
public class GameField : IEnumerable
{
    private readonly int _rows;
    private readonly int _cols;

    private readonly Cell[] _data;

    public int Rows => _rows;
    public int Cols => _cols;


    public bool this[int row, int col]
    {
        get => _data[row * Cols + col].State;
        set => _data[row * Cols + col].State = value;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _data.Length; i++)
            _data[i].State = false;
    }

    public GameField(int rows, int cols)
    {
        _rows = rows;
        _cols = cols;
        _data = new Cell[rows * cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < _data.Length; i++)
            _data[i] = new Cell();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() 
        => _data.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Тот самый `GetEnumerator()` как раз и нужен интерфейсу, чтобы отрисоваться, в то же время с этим игровым полем можно работать как с двухмерным массивом в коде. Класс простой, никакой игровой логики здесь не будет, он просто мост между игрой и интерфейсом.

Игровую логику я не стал реализовывать, это придется сделать вам. Здесь есть только демонстрация технологий, за которой вы наверное сюда и пришли.

#### Игровая логика

Комментарии в коде

```cs
// состояние игры
public enum GameState
{
    Over,
    Running,
    Paused
}

public class Game
{
    // мне показалось, события здесь хорошо подходят
    public event Action<int> ScoreChanged; //возникает при изменении очков
    public event Action<GameState> StateChanged; // возникает при изменении состояния игры

    private int _score;
    private GameState _state;
    private readonly GameField _field;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public int Score
    {
        get => _score;
        private set
        {
            _score = value;
            ScoreChanged?.Invoke(value);
        }
    }

    public GameState State
    {
        get => _state;
        private set
        {
            _state = value;
            StateChanged?.Invoke(value);
        }
    }

    public Game(GameField field)
    {
        _field = field;
    }

    public async void Start()
    {
        // если игра уже запущена, повторно не запускать
        if (State == GameState.Running)
            return;

        // пример работы с полем
        _field[3, 1] = true;
        _field[4, 1] = true;
        _field[5, 1] = true;
        _field[5, 2] = true;

        _field[3, 4] = true;
        _field[4, 4] = true;
        _field[5, 4] = true;
        _field[4, 5] = true;

        _field[4, 7] = true;
        _field[5, 7] = true;
        _field[4, 8] = true;
        _field[5, 8] = true;

        // собственно, сам запуск игры
        State = GameState.Running;
        using (_cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            await RunGameLoop(_cts.Token);
        }
        _cts = null;
    }

    private async Task RunGameLoop(CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            // асинхронный цикл, чтобы не блокировать интерфейс во время выполнения
            while (true)
            {
                Score += 10;
                await Task.Delay(1000, token); // подождать секунду
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { } // при отмене токена выбрасывается исключение в Task.Delay, ловим здесь, это нормально
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        if (State != GameState.Running)
            return;
        _cts?.Cancel(); // остановить игру
        _field.Clear(); // очистить поле

        State = GameState.Paused;
    }
}
```

Вот и вся логика.

#### View Model

Этот класс занимается обеспечением интерфейса данными для отображения. Показан пример использования команды, остальное должно выглядеть просто.

```cs
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private const int rows = 20;
    private const int cols = 10;

    private int _score;
    private GameField _field;
    private GameState _state;
    private Game _game;
    private ICommand _startCommand;

    public GameField Field
    {
        get => _field;
        set
        {
            _field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public GameState State
    {
        get => _state;
        set
        {
            _state = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Score
    {
        get => _score;
        set
        {
            _score = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand StartCommand => _startCommand ??= new RelayCommand(parameter => 
    {
        if (State == GameState.Running)
            _game.Pause();
        else
            _game.Start();
    });

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Field = new GameField(rows, cols);
        _game = new Game(Field);
        _game.ScoreChanged += (s) => Score = s;
        _game.StateChanged += (s) => State = s;
    }
}
```

#### View

Сам интерфейс.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfTetris.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTetris"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainViewModel}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Space" Command="{Binding StartCommand}"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Command="{Binding StartCommand}" Margin="5">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Start"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Running">
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Pause"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Field}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" Width="20" Height="20">
                            <Border Background="Gray" Margin="1" Visibility="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding Field.Rows}" Columns="{Binding Field.Cols}"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock Text="Score: "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Score}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Сделал по-простому, 3 колонки, слева кнопка, посередине стакан, справа очки.

Для примера привязал пробел к команде `StartCommand`, той же что у кнопки. Точно таким же образом вы можете привязать стрелочки к другим командам.

И самое главное, как подключить вьюмодель к окну - самая сложная часть этого приложения.

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начните с простого, пусть фигура - это будет один квадратик, падающий с нужной вам скоростью и останавливающийся на дне стакана или над уже лежащим там квадратиком. После того как он упал, пусть начисляются очки. Когда стакан заполнен - игра должна закончиться. Как только это сделаете полностью - принимайтесь за фигуры и их поворот.