# Как скрыть элемент Rectangle?

Tags: c#, wpf, разработка-игр, морской-бой

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть вот такая `ViewModel`:

```
internal class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    protected void Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propName = "") {
        if (!field.Equals(value)) {
            field = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }

    protected void Set<T>(ref T field, T value, params string[] propNames) {
        if (!field.Equals(value)) {
            field = value;
            foreach (var name in propNames)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    
    internal void Notify (params string[] names) {
        foreach (var name in names) {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

В ней есть метод `Notify`, который стреляет по корабликам (я реализую игру морской бой). И я хочу после каждого попадания в кораблик сделать так, чтобы он появлялся.

Comment: Это просто реализация `INotifyPropertyChanged`, которая не имеет никакого отношения к вашей игре и приутствует практически в любом проекте WPF. Другими словами, показанный код никак не относится к проблеме. Метод `Notify` сообщает UI, что значение свойства изменилось и UI должен обновиться. Имя свойства передается в метод строкой. Больше этот метод не умеет ничего.

Comment: Вот пример работы с привязками данных https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567, ещё пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1255542/373567, и ещё пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1239671/373567