# Реализация меню WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, консоль, menu, menuitem

Делаю первые шаги в C#. Начал с консольного приложения, где реализуется квест: текст и меню. Выбираешь стрелками клавиатуры вариант, нажимаешь enter, переходишь к следующей менюшке с выбором, сопровождающийся комментарием. Возник вопрос можно ли перенести такую историю на WPF? Или это крайне трудоемко - постоянно работать с элементами меню?
[image: Прикрепляю пример]

Comment: Перезалейте скрин с замазанной нецензурщиной.

Comment: `Возник вопрос можно ли перенести такую историю на WPF?` Да. `Или это крайне трудоемко` Мне например легче лёгкого, а как вам - не знаю. Начните учить матчасть, ключевые слова: "привязка данных", "MVVM в WPF", "ООП", "SOLID". Разработка приложений с графическим интерфейсом сильно отличается от консоли, но то что принципы используются другие в разработке - совершенно не значит, что одно сложнее или проще другого. Если вам скучно читать, и нужно сразу в бой, [вот, разберитесь как это работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну например так.

Будем писать сразу на MVVM. Поскольку ваша игра — походовая стратегия, то естественно моделировать состояние игры как стейт-машину. Стейты и таблица переходов у нас, разумеется, не меняются в течение игры (то есть immutable). Это даст такую структуру.

```cs
class GameStepVM
{
    public GameStepVM(string description, IReadOnlyList<GameStepOptionVM> options)
    {
        Description = description;
        Options = options;
    }

    public string Description { get; }
    public IReadOnlyList<GameStepOptionVM> Options { get; }
}

class GameStepOptionVM
{
    public GameStepOptionVM(string text) => Text = text;

    public string Text { get; }
}
```

Эти классы по сути модельные, но я буду либерально использовать их как VM-классы, т. к. проект реально маленький, и отдельной модели покамест не заслуживает.

`GameStepVM` описывает одно состояние игры, `GameStepOptionVM` — возможные переходы из него.

Сама логика игры умещается в класс `GameVM`. Поскольку это класс содержит изменяемые данные, нам необходимо будет реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`, а для этого имеет смысл воспользоваться универсальной заготовкой:

```cs
public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value,
                          [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;

        field = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Ну и сам класс, описывающий логику игры. Тут всё просто: построили граф состояний, и выполняем стейт-машину: когда придёт команда перехода, подменяем текущий шаг согласно таблице переходов. Вот что у нас получается:

```cs
class GameVM : VM
{
    public GameVM(ImmutableDictionary<GameStepOptionVM, GameStepVM> transitions,
                  GameStepVM initialStep)
    {
        Transitions = transitions;
        currentStep = initialStep;
        MakeStepCommand = new RelayCommand<GameStepOptionVM>(MakeStep);
    }

    readonly ImmutableDictionary<GameStepOptionVM, GameStepVM> Transitions;

    GameStepVM currentStep;
    public GameStepVM CurrentStep
    {
        get => currentStep;
        private set => Set(ref currentStep, value);
    }

    public ICommand MakeStepCommand { get; }

    void MakeStep(GameStepOptionVM option)
    {
        CurrentStep = Transitions[option];
        // advance time, etc.
    }
}
```

Команду смены состояния я публикую как `ICommand`, а не публичный метод, имея в виду, что вызываться это будет из UI.

Построение графа состояний мы делегировали классу `Initializer`, который у меня создаёт всё вручную, а у вас, вероятно, должен быть читать данные из ресурсов (например, из файла):

```cs
static class Initializer
{
    public static (ImmutableDictionary<GameStepOptionVM, GameStepVM> transitions, GameStepVM initialStep) CreateGraph()
    {
        // load steps; this should be perhaps done from a file
        var steps = new List<GameStepVM>()
        {
            new GameStepVM("Понедельник, 8 утра. Невыспавшийся ты притащил своё тело на пару по Английскому в великий и могучий Гидрак",
                    new[]
                    {
                        new GameStepOptionVM("Ботать"),
                        new GameStepOptionVM("Спать на задней парте"),
                        new GameStepOptionVM("Зарубиться в 2048 на Xiaomi"),
                        new GameStepOptionVM("Сходить ешё за кофе"),
                        new GameStepOptionVM("Да пошло оно к ху@м! (отчислиться)"),
                    }),
            new GameStepVM("Вы отчислены",
                    new[]
                    {
                        new GameStepOptionVM("Наслаждаться жизнью, готовиться в армию")
                    })
        };
        var transitions = new Dictionary<GameStepOptionVM, GameStepVM>()
        {
            { steps[0].Options[0], steps[0] }, // in step 0, option 0 -> step 0
            { steps[0].Options[1], steps[1] }, // etc.
            { steps[0].Options[2], steps[1] },
            { steps[0].Options[3], steps[1] },
            { steps[0].Options[4], steps[1] },
            { steps[1].Options[0], null }
        };
        return (transitions.ToImmutableDictionary(), steps[0]);
    }
}
```

Остальную бизнес-логику типа подсчёта времени легко дописать самостоятельно в классе `GameVM`.

---

С логикой всё, переходим к UI.

Отображение одного шага удобно сделать в виде `UserControl`'а. Что нам понадобится на вход? `GameStep` и команда перехода. Отлично, пишем `UserControl` Нужные параметры положим в виде DependencyProperty.

```cs
public partial class GameStepPresentation : UserControl
{
    public GameStepPresentation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public object Step
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(StepProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StepProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StepProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Step", typeof(object), typeof(GameStepPresentation));

    public ICommand TransitionCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(TransitionCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TransitionCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TransitionCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "TransitionCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(GameStepPresentation));
}
```

Сам UI простой: сверху описание (я отдал под него много места в расчёте на то, что будет нужно ещё что-то добавлять), внизу кнопки с опциями (переходами). Чтобы разместить не известное заранее количество кнопок, используется, как обычно, `ItemsControl`.

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.GameStepPresentation"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Step, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
          d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:GameStepVM}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="0"/>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Options}" Grid.Row="1">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="local:GameStepOptionVM">
                    <Button Height="30" Content="{Binding Text}"
                            Command="{Binding TransitionCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Далее, главное окно. В нём лишь одна хитрость: когда текущий Step равен `null`, игра окончена, и мы выводим об этом радостное сообщение на весь экран.

```xml
<Window x:Class="testApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SOWpfFx01"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Type=local:GameVM, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
        Title="Test" Height="680" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <local:GameStepPresentation Step="{Binding CurrentStep}"
                                    TransitionCommand="{Binding MakeStepCommand}"/>

        <!-- game over message -->
        <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="Game over"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentStep}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Чтобы скрыть сообщение, когда игра не окончена, используется стандартный трюк со стилем и триггером.

Ну и класс `App`, который будет создавать VM и «подвязывать» `DataContext`:

```xml
<Application x:Class="TestApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
</Application>
```

(Обратите внимание, что я [убрал стандартный `StartupUri`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/10105)).

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        var (transitions, initialStep) = Initializer.CreateGraph();
        var w = new MainWindow() { DataContext = new GameVM(transitions, initialStep) };
        w.Show();
    }
}
```

---

Да, ещё вам понадобится стандартная реализация `RelayCommand`. Например, такая:

```cs
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> onExecute) { OnExecute = onExecute; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
    public void Execute(object parameter) => OnExecute((T)parameter);

    readonly Action<T> OnExecute;
}
```

Вот что получилось:

[image: простая анимашка, хотя дизайн ну такой себе]

Я не выставлял красоту наподобие шрифтов, маргинов и выравнивания, это остаётся тоже вам.

Comment: Команда разбросана по коду, метод+поле+свойство+конструктор - 4 части. А если таких команд пара десятков? Предлагаю собрать покучнее в поле+свойство `public ICommand MakeStepCommand => makeStepCommand ??= new RelayCommand<GameStepOptionVM>(option => { CurrentStep = Transitions[option]; });`. А так сделано добротно, мне только кажется, что с юзерконтролом слегка перегнул, можно было не пугать так автора (но я бы еще и в `ControlTemplate` разметку юзерконтролу засунул, чтобы `ReletiveSource TemplatedParent` юзать).

Comment: @aepot: С командой не скомпилируется вроде? По поводу отдельного поля, часто внутри класса нужен настоящий тип. Но в принципе поле в даннопм случае можно выкинуть.

Comment: Только не говорите, что у вас .NET Framework 4.x, а так скомпилится легко. Никто против поля ничего и не говорил. Я предлагал метод засунуть в лямбду, а инициализацию из конструктора унести в ленивую.

Comment: А, там ленивая инстанциация. Ну, мне больше нравится, когда в конструкторе явно устанавливается значение свойства, тогда у меня так честный readonly. Ну и заменять метод на лямбду нехорошо, т. к. это сейчас метод однострочный, а в него явно ещё придётся добавлять обработку текущего времени, номера хода и всё такое.

Comment: Если автор минуса будет любезен объяснить свой минус, я, вероятно, смогу улучшить свой ответ.

Comment: По командам, ну если хочется жосского ридонли с конструктором xD, то тогда всё ок.

Comment: @aepot: У меня в голове простая политика: либо жёсткое readonly, либо INPC. Позволяет ничего не забыть на уровне компилятора. То есть я понимаю, что lazy — тоже вариант, но сознательно избегаю его. Наверное, это небольшой догматизм, ну, в больших проектах такой догматизм может быть и полезен.